# Compute the first N digits of e

Tags: code-golf, math

### Challenge

Write a program to compute the the first N (<= 10^3) digits of [e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29).

Your program should take an integer **N** as input.

**Input:**

```
100
```

**Output:**

```
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178525166427
```

**Input:**

```
7
```

**Output:**

```
2.718282
```

**Input:**

```
1000
```

**Output:**

```
2.718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178525166427427466391932003059921817413596629043572900334295260595630738132328627943490763233829880753195251019011573834187930702154089149934884167509244761460668082264800168477411853742345442437107539077744992069551702761838606261331384583000752044933826560297606737113200709328709127443747047230696977209310141692836819025515108657463772111252389784425056953696770785449969967946864454905987931636889230098793127736178215424999229576351482208269895193668033182528869398496465105820939239829488793320362509443117301238197068416140397019837679320683282376464804295311802328782509819455815301756717361332069811250996181881593041690351598888519345807273866738589422879228499892086805825749279610484198444363463244968487560233624827041978623209002160990235304369941849146314093431738143640546253152096183690888707016768396424378140592714563549061303107208510383750510115747704171898610687396965521267154688957035035
```

**Shortest solution wins!**

Answer (score 9):

### Mathematica (12 bytes)

```
N[E,Input[]]
```

Comment: You can try it online: there is a `e-digits` command on yubnub.org e.g., http://yubnub.org/parser/parse?command=e-digits+1000 that uses wolframalpha http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=N[E%2C7]&asynchronous=false&equal=Submit

Comment: -1 because you do not implement the calculation by your self.

Comment: @FUZxxl:The author didn't asked for an implementation,only shortest ones is preferred.

Comment: @Quixotic The question does say "compute" not just output. Would you have argued the same thing if the question had said "calculate" instead of "compute"?

Answer (score 9):

### Python, 69

```
e=f=n=1;N=input()+2;exec"e+=10**N/f;f*=n;n+=1;"*N;print'2.'+`e`[1:-4]
```

Computes N+2 iterations of the standard power series for e.

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 67

```
import decimal as d
d.getcontext().prec=input()
print d._One.exp()
```

Comment: Save 3 chars? `from decimal import*` and remove both `d.`

Comment: @Timtech `import *` won't import `_One` due to the  leading underscore.

Comment: Okay, didn't know that, sorry/

Answer (score 6):

## J, 20...ish.

Computational, but... Very inefficient. With n defined (20):

```
(0 j.<:n)":+/%!i.x:n+9
```

As a monadic function (32):

```
ge =. 3 : '(0 j.<:y)":+/%!i.x:y+9'
```

As a tacit function (33, fixed):

```
(0 j.<:)":(+/)&:(%&!&i.&x:&(9&+))
```

Comment: This converges very fast (for 100 digits you need "just" 70 terms) so you can drop that `+9`.

Comment: For 1000 digits this: `(0 j.<:1000)":+/%!i.x:450` takes just a few seconds.

Comment: Would you care to explain your code?

Comment: @Eelvex: But I need extra terms up until N=30 or so. (Any hints on reducing that mess of composes, or is that about right?)

Comment: Ah, you're right, that's unfortunate. (That "mess" is shorter than anything else I could come up with - unless, off course, you use a fixed number for i. like: `(0 j.<:n)":+/%!i.999x`; then tacitly:`(+/%!i.999x)":~0 j.<:` )

Comment: @Eelvex: This brings up a point... This performs horribly for larger values of n because of the resulting denominator, which is (for example) `*/!i.999x` if it's not reduced. I wasn't even patient enough to let `+/%!i.999x` finish. Hints [here](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Extended%20Precision%20Functions), possibly...

Comment: @Jesse: Use 450x then. It's enough for every n<1000 and takes just a few seconds (~9s here).

Answer (score 3):

## 05AB1E, <strike>4</strike> <strike>3</strike> 2 bytes

<sub>[Crossed out 4 is still regular 4 ;(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77899/substitution-cipher/77913#77913)</sub>

Thanks to @Adnan for a byte.

```
žt
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

Explanation:

```
žt - Push input. Pop a, push e to a places (up to 10000).
```

**Update:**

Remove `I`, as `žt` takes input anyway if none is on the stack.

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf! The `ž` character is _1 byte_ in the **CP-1252** encoding, so this has a total score of 2 bytes instead of 3 :p.

Comment: @Adnan Thanks! Nice language, btw.

Comment: @GeorgeGibson Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 68

```
require 'bigdecimal/math';include BigMath;puts E(gets.to_i).to_s 'F'
```

Comment: it doesn't work on ruby1.8. It produces invalid results on ruby1.9

Comment: You're right, but it *should* work in Ruby 1.9. There seems to be something wrong with precision in the [E](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/index.html) function.

Comment: Looks fine here, it just adds some imprecise digits. Mayby like this? require'bigdecimal/math';puts BigMath::E(a=gets.to_i).to_s(?F)[0,a+1]

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript <strike>43</strike> 41

```
~10\?1:b 461,{)b*:b@+\}460*;*b/`);(;'2.'\
```

Edit: I might as well replace the 0 with the leftover 1 from initializing b, the resulting difference is far too small to make it to the output.

I left the old version as that is what I have documented below.

```
~10\?1:b;0 461,{)b*:b@+\}460*;*b/`);(;'2.'\
```

`~10\?` Take input and calculate 10^input, leave the result on the stack.
`1:b;` Store 1 in b.
`0 461,` Put 0 on the stack, put the array [0 1 ... 459 460] on the stack.
`{ }460*` Execute function 460 times.
`)b*:b` Take the last element of the array, multiply it by b, store result in b and leave the result on the stack.
`@+\` Switch the 0 (which is only a zero at the first iteration) to the top of the stack, add it to the leftover b value, and switch the result back again.
`;` Remove the rest of the array (only [0] is left).
The number that was initialized to 0 now hold the value e*460! and b hold 460!
`*` Multiply 10^input by e*460! (they are at this point the only 2 elements left on the stack).
`b/` Divide the result by b.
The stack now hold the value e*10^input which when converted to a string will hold all the decimals, but not the dot.
`` `);(;'2.'\ `` A bunch of string operations to fit in the dot.

e*460! is calculated as 1 + 460 + 460*459 + 460*459*458 etc.

Answer (score 1):

## [bc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), 17 chars

```
scale=read()
e(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
∆Ė
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiIbEliIsIiIsIiJd)

Built in solution.

Answer (score 0):

**J, 17**

```
(":&(x:^1)@*&0j1)
```

Example:

```
(":&(x:^1)@*&0j1) 50
2.71828182845891281655718620537435347047040502245993
```

Uses built in exponential verb - so, "compute" is on shaky grounds. Basically:

```
^1 - computes e**1
x: - does extended precision
0jy ": - formats the number to y digit
```

Comment: `*&0j1` is simply `j.`

Answer (score 0):

### Mathcad, [tbd] bytes

[image]

Uses a spigot algorithm - http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/11/2/229.full.pdf+html.

---

Byte count not given as Mathcad byte count equivalence is yet to be determined.  However, using a symbol equivalence it is roughly 121 bytes ... and not going to win any brevity prizes no matter how the equivalence is determined.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 7 bytes

```
N[E,#]&
```

My answer is a further golfing of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1577/75323) answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y/aVUc5Vu1/QFFmXkl0WrShQWwsF4ID5P0HAA)

For some reason, the output over at TIO looks funny but I tested it on my machine and the code works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

### [GTB](http://timtechsoftware.com/?page_id=1309), 14

```
eS?`AS;_,1,A+1
```

**Explanation**

`e` - Put `e` as the last calculated value

`S?` - Convert `e` to string `_`

`` `A `` - Input A

`S;_,1,A+1` Display the first `A` digits of `e`

Answer (score -1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Mbignum=bexp -p`, 12 bytes

```perl
$_=bexp 1,$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYptaJAwVBHJf7/f0Mjg3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9kzLT80pzwfL/dQsA)