# Cut-Off The Matrix

Tags: code-golf

#### Task

Given is a square matrix of any dimension and any integer `n`.

Output all possible matrices(without duplicates) by removing columns and rows from the input matrix such that the determinant of these new matrices is `n`.

#### Rules

Output should include original if determinant of original is `n`.

Output should be all the chopped off matrices.
In case no output matrix is possible, return 0 or None or anything similar.

The input matrix will be at least of size 2x2 and all elements will be integers.

If `n=1` empty matrix must also be in the output.

#### Test Cases

```
inputs:
[[1,0,5],
[1,0,5],
[1,2,4]],2

[[1, 3, 5],
[1, 3, 5],
[1, 45, 4]],0

[[1, 22, 5, 4],
[1, 3, 5, 5],
[1, 45, 4, 6],
[3, 4, 1, 4]],5

[[1, 22, 5, 4],
[1, -32, 51, 5],
[1, 45, 9, 0],
[3, 4, -1, -6]],-54

[[1, 22, 5, 4],
[1, -32, 51, 5],
[1, 45, 9, 0],
[3, 4, -1, -6]],1

outputs:
[[[2]], [[1, 0], [1, 2]]]

[[[1, 3], [1, 3]], [[1, 5], [1, 5]], [[3, 5], [3, 5]], [[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 5], [1, 45, 4]]]

[[[5]], [[5, 4], [5, 5]]]

[[[1, 22], [1, -32]], [[9, 0], [-1, -6]]]

[[], [[1]], [[1, 4], [1, 5]]]
```

**The shortest code wins.**

Comment: +1 for making me think about why the determinant of the empty matrix really should be 1.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>20</s> 16 bytes

```
ZŒPZœcLƊ€ẎQÆḊ⁼¥Ƈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q6KSAqKOTk32OdT1qWvNwV1/g4baHO7oeNe45tPRY@//Dy49Oerhzxv//0dGGOgrGOgqmsTpcaEwTUyCOjf1vAAA)

[Challenge finished](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47593014#47593014). Unfortunately, my brain wasn't in its best mood, so Dennis pushed it until I finally managed to get here (you can see how it went). ~1 hour.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>246</s> <s>238</s> <s>196</s> 192 bytes

*Credits: the function \$D\$ is derived from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147910/58563) by edc65.*

Takes input as `(integer)(matrix)`. Prints the results to the console.

```javascript
d=>g=m=>(F=(a,i)=>a.filter(_=>i--),m.map((_,i)=>m.map((_,j)=>g(F(m,i).map(r=>F(r,j))))),D=m=>m+m?m.reduce((n,[r],i)=>n+(i&1?-r:r)*D(F(m,i).map(r=>F(r,0))),0):1)(m)-d||g[m]||console.log(g[m]=m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZBda4MwFIbv/RWBwXqyJmL8KLQQe1P8BbsTKUGjWIyWaHflf3cmg9VtXXvT3L1vcp7nkJP4EH2u6/NA266QU8mngscVVzyGhIMgNeaxcMu6GaSGI49rSjFRrhJngKO9/Q6nOVSQgJpr22keJ6Dn3hxyMFC1VnvlallccgnQklRnFtKuoX5le6p3Gr8dbkA8g/DwjmFQmBbjWKUqG8e8a/uukW7TVWAarvC07Fbvsh9QLnqJXtgKOyX4GFIHoZQR5BEUZeRW8AkKMyfDjvMfzLcw7woLlvM/Qhg9pAWWFl1p/ryBHVsS/0AJ2nwVgQ3soSe0HhqFd0w0MA37LdvOX7SUUfN0c18XWR17pmz6BA)

### How?

#### Removing rows and columns

The helper function \$F\$ creates a copy of a given array \$a\$ with the \$i^\text{th}\$ item removed (0-indexed).

```javascript
F = (a, i) => a.filter(_ => i--)
```

#### Computing the determinant

The recursive function \$D\$ computes the determinant of a matrix \$m\$, using [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion).

```javascript
D = m =>                       // m = matrix
  m + m ?                      // if the matrix is not empty:
    m.reduce((n, [r], i) =>    //   for each value r at (0, i):
      n                        //     take the previous sum n
      + (i & 1 ? -r : r)       //     using the parity of i, either add or subtract r
      * D(                     //     multiplied by the result of a recursive call:
        F(m, i)                //       using m with the i-th row removed
        .map(r => F(r, 0))     //       and the first column removed
      ),                       //     end of recursive call
      0                        //     start with n = 0
    )                          //   end of reduce()
  :                            // else (the matrix is empty):
    1                          //   determinant = 1
```

*Example:*

$$m=\begin{bmatrix}\color{red}1&\color{red}2&\color{red}3\\\color{green}4&\color{green}5&\color{green}6\\\color{blue}7&\color{blue}8&\color{blue}9\end{bmatrix}$$

First iteration:

$$|m|=
\color{red}1\times\left|\begin{bmatrix}\color{green}5&\color{green}6\\\color{blue}8&\color{blue}9\end{bmatrix}\right|
-\color{green}4\times\left|\begin{bmatrix}\color{red}2&\color{red}3\\\color{blue}8&\color{blue}9\end{bmatrix}\right|
+\color{blue}7\times\left|\begin{bmatrix}\color{red}2&\color{red}3\\\color{green}5&\color{green}6\end{bmatrix}\right|$$

which eventually leads to:

$$1\times(5\times9-8\times6)-4\times(2\times9-8\times3)+7\times(2\times6-5\times3) = 0$$

#### Main function

We recursively remove rows and columns from the original matrix \$m\$ and invoke \$D\$ on all resulting matrices, printing those whose determinant is equal to the expected value \$d\$.

```javascript
d =>                           // d = expected determinant value
  g = m =>                     // g = recursive function taking the matrix m,
    (                          //     also used to store valid matrices
      m.map((_, i) =>          // for each i in [0 ... m.length - 1]:
        m.map((_, j) =>        //   for each j in [0 ... m.length - 1]:
          g(                   //     do a recursive call with:
            F(m, i)            //       the i-th row of m removed
            .map(r => F(r, j)) //       the j-th column of m removed
          )                    //     end of recursive call
        )                      //   end of inner map()
      ),                       // end of outer map()
      D                        // invoke D ...
    )(m)                       // ... on m
    - d                        // provided that the result is equal to d
    || g[m]                    // and provided that this matrix was not already printed,
    || console.log(g[m] = m)   // print m and store it in the underlying object of g
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 129 bytes

```r
f=function(m,n,o={},z=nrow(m)){for(i in r<-1:z)for(j in r)o=c(o,if(round(det(m))==n)list(m),if(z)f(m[-i,-j,drop=F],n));unique(o)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY/NTsMwDIDvPEW1ky05UpOmk2DkyhPsBhxGf6RMNIEsFbBpz16cQaFbJU7IkmXH/r4kYRha0/auitY76MiRN4cj7Y0L/g06xEPrA9jMuizcCnmzx9RvTz16U4En20LwvauhbmIijHH4bHepTjMmoLsXlsSW6uBfzN0jOcRV7@xr34DH41BtIizWzS5m@YNb4IqBTQz2HSQVHE8f/BazRlJ5jle/y/J8ueL1nEoasyKNF/yUVnO6OHFfWZcz/OzyYo4rxaT@NowOWnKbDtmmOX5s5dSm/7CJgis5Cq/5d0koeLC8UIpST6Xlv0glDp8)

Recursive function returning a list of submatrices. Outputs `NULL` for no solution. It is a bit unfortunate that the determinant value has to be explicitly rounded (otherwise some tests fail due to numerical imprecision), but at least we have a built-in for calculating it.

Comment: Here's a case where the growing object `o` seems like it must be explicitly initialized to `NULL` and the built-in abuse of `F` or `T` won't work.