# All possible permuations in lexicographical order

Tags: code-golf

Given a string of English alphabet characters, write the shortest code to print all possible permuations in lexicographical order without using any language based library.

```
def function('bca'):
    return all_permutation.
```

This should return :

```
abc, 
acb,
bac, 
bca, 
cab, 
cba
```

Comment: The `code-golf` and `fastest-code` tags are very often not compatible...

Comment: The previous question [Code-Golf: Permutations](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/code-golf-permutations) didn't impose the lexicographic order, but I think most answers provide it anyway and for those that don't it's a trivial change to call `sort`.

Comment: Its about lexicographical order

Answer (score 1):

## Python - <s>131</s> 129 chars

```
def g(a,z):
 if len(a)<1:print(z)
 else:
  for i in range(len(a)):g(a[:i]+a[i+1:],z+a[i])
def f(s):
 a=list(s)
 a.sort()
 g(a,'')
```

Only after coding it I noticed that you wrote both "print" and "return" in the question... my solution prints the permutations, I hope that's alright.

Comment: you can combine entire `f(s)` into `g(list(s).sort(),'')`

Comment: The sort function doesn't return the sorted list... but apparently there's a sorted function that does that, which is great to know.

Answer (score 1):

### Python - 83 bytes

```
p=lambda a,*s:sorted(sum([p(a[:i]+a[i+1:],a[i],*s)for i in range(len(a))],[]))or[s]
```

Sample usage:

```
>>> p=lambda a,*s:sorted(sum([p(a[:i]+a[i+1:],a[i],*s)for i in range(len(a))],[]))or[s]
>>> p('abc')
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'b', 'a')]
```

---

Without the `sorted` call, this narrowly beats out [ugoren's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5058) to the linked question at 75:

```
p=lambda a,*s:sum([p(a[:i]+a[i+1:],a[i],*s)for i in range(len(a))],[])or[s]
```