# All possible orders of items of unknown type

Tags: code-golf

This is code golf. Fewest bytes wins, only standard libraries, etc.

Write code, in any language, to output all possible same-length permutations of all items of an array / list / object in the input format and any order, grouped in whatever way you like. The items can be of ANY type, as allowed by the programming language.

Example input and output (inputting array, outputting array of arrays).
Inputs:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

and outputs:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 3, 2],
    [2, 1, 3],
    [2, 3, 1],
    [3, 1, 2],
    [3, 2, 1]
]
```

[Code-Golf: Permutations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/code-golf-permutations) reposts not allowed!

Comment: I don't see how the type of items changes anything. Permuting elements of an array doesn't depend on the type of items it contains

Comment: @Fatalize But... That's inactive now.

Comment: ...what? I don't understand.

Comment: Every answer to that can apply here

Comment: @muddyfish Yes, you're right. But it is an interesting codegolf.

Comment: then necro the old question. Thats OK (I think)

Comment: @Fatalize Probable duplicate. But that's inactive. Should this still be closed?

Comment: @muddyfish What's necroing? (Yes, I'm new here.)

Comment: answer anyway, even if its inactive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
.pQ
```

:D

[Live demo.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.pQ&input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D&debug=1)

Comment: +1 Yup! It works. And it's not a repost.

Comment: This might have to be closed. If it is, I recommend you move your answer to the question above.