# All permutations of range from \$1\$ to \$n\$

Tags: code-golf, permutations

Given a positive input \$n\$, output all permutations of either \$\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}\$ or \$\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\$.

### Examples

Outputting permutations of \$\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\$.

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `[(1)]` |
| `2` | `[(1, 2), (2, 1)]` |
| `4` | `[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 4, 3), (2, 3, 1, 4), (2, 3, 4, 1), (2, 4, 1, 3), (2, 4, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2, 4), (3, 1, 4, 2), (3, 2, 1, 4), (3, 2, 4, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2), (3, 4, 2, 1), (4, 1, 2, 3), (4, 1, 3, 2), (4, 2, 1, 3), (4, 2, 3, 1), (4, 3, 1, 2), (4, 3, 2, 1)]` |

Standard loopholes are forbidden. The shortest code wins.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for the output to be the permutations of either \$\{0, 1, ..., n-1\}\$ or \$\{1, 2, ..., n\}\$?

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5056/88546)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Œ!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMX///@bAAA)

Boring builtin answer

---

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
!Rœ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/18x6Ohk@////5sAAA)

Slightly less boring mostly-builtin answer

### How it works

```
!Rœ? - Main link. Takes n on the left
!    - Yield n!
 R   - Range; [1, 2, ..., n!]
  œ? - For each 1 ≤ i ≤ n!, get the ith permutation of [1, 2, ..., n]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 54 bytes

Outputs all permutations of \$\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}\$.

```python
lambda n:permutations(range(n))
from itertools import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3zXISc5NSEhXyrApSi3JLSxJLMvPzijWKEvPSUzXyNDW50orycxUyS1KLSvLzc4oVMnML8otKtKC6VdLyixTyFDLzFKINdRSMdBRMYq24FBQKijLzSjSitdKAJsRqQtQuWAChAQ)

Answer (score 2):

### Print out -- [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 58 bytes (@dingledooper)

```python
def f(n,*r):[f(n,*r,x)for x in{*range(n)}-{*r}]or print(r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI09Hq0jTKhrC0KnQTMsvUqhQyMyr1ipKzEtP1cjTrNUFsmtjgeIFRZl5JRpFmv/TNEw0/wMA)

### Return list -- [Python](https://www.python.org), 62 bytes

```
f=lambda n,*p:sum((f(n,*p,i)for i in{*range(n)}-{*p}),[])or[p]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY37dJscxJzk1ISFfJ0tAqsiktzNTTSNEBsnUzNtPwihUyFzLxqraLEvPRUjTzNWt1qrYJaTZ3oWM38ouiCWIgpqwuKMvNKgPpMNDUhIjDzAQ)

Ignoring the standard lib's itertools.permutations.

Comment: @solid.py but they conveniently take a set as input which saves them the `range` and the conversion to set.

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI09Hq0jTKhrC0KnQTMsvUqhQyMyr1ipKzEtP1cjTrNUFsmtjgeIFRZl5JRpFmv/TNEw0/wMA) by printing the results