# Is string X a subsequence of string Y?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

Given strings X and Y, determine whether X is a [subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Subsequence&oldid=594253998) of Y. The empty string is regarded as a subsequence of every string. (E.g., `''` and `'anna'` are subsequences of `'banana'`.)

#### Input

- X, a possibly-empty case-sensitive alphanumeric string
- Y, a possibly-empty case-sensitive alphanumeric string

#### Output

- True or False (or equivalents), correctly indicating whether X is a subsequence of Y.

#### I/O examples

```
X      Y        output

''     'z00'    True
'z00'  'z00'    True 
'z00'  '00z0'   False
'aa'   'anna'   True
'anna' 'banana' True
'Anna' 'banana' False
```

#### Criteria

- The shortest program wins, as determined by the number of bytes of source code.

#### Example programs

- Several programs that could be adapted are in this [related posting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6877249/1033647).

Comment: Why is 'anna' substr of 'banana'?

Comment: @kaoD - `anna` is a *subsequence* (but ***not*** a substring) of `banana`. String X is a subsequence of string Y just if X can be obtained from Y by deleting zero or more of the elements of Y; e.g., deleting the `b` and the second `a` from `banana` gives `anna`.

Comment: This has about a single solution in every scripting language offering regex that's both trivial to see and impossible to golf further.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 17 bytes (+1?), full program

```perl
s//.*/g;$_=<>=~$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX19PSz/dWiXe1sbOtk4l/v//xLy8RK6kxDwgLOb6l19QkpmfV/xftwAA)

Invoke with the `p` flag to the perl interpreter, as in `perl -pe 's//.*/g;$_=<>=~$_'`.  Per [the established scoring rules when this challenge was originally posted](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273/on-interactive-answers-and-other-special-conditions), this flag costs one extra byte.  Under [more recent rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends), AFAICT, it may be free.

Either way, the input strings should be supplied on separate newline-terminated lines on stdin.  Output (to stdout) will be `1` if the first input string is a substring of the second, or nothing at all if it's not.

Note that *both* input lines must have a newline at the end, or the program won't work correctly.  Alternatively, you can add the `l` command line flag to the invocation to make perl strip the newlines; depending on the scoring rules in effect, this may or may not cost one extra byte. Note that using this flag will also append a newline to the output.

### Original version (snippet, 18 bytes / chars)

```perl
$x=~s//.*/g,$y=~$x
```

Input is given in the variables `$x` and `$y`, result is the value of the expression (in scalar context).  Note that `$x` is modified in the process.
(Yes, I know using `$_` instead of `$x` would let me save four chars, but doing that in a snippet that feels a bit too cheesy for me.)

#### How does it work?

The first part, `$x=~s//.*/g`, inserts the string `.*` between each character in `$x`.  The second part, `$y=~$x`, treats `$x` as a regexp and matches `$y` against it.  In Perl regexps, `.*` matches zero or more arbitrary characters, while all alphanumeric characters conveniently match themselves.

Comment: According to out (new?) consensus, submissions must be program or function, not snippet. If your submission doesn't satisfy that, consider editing it.

Comment: @user202729: This challenge is a lot older than that consensus, so unless it's assumed to apply retroactively, the answers in this thread should probably be "grandfathered" in. That said, I did just add a version that complies with current rules, and may even be one byte / char shorter (note that byte-based counting is also newer than this challenge, AFAIK) depending on how you count command-line switches.

Answer (score 9):

#### Ruby, 32 characters

```
s=->x,y{y=~/#{[*x.chars]*".*"}/}
```

This solution returns `nil` if `x` isn't a subsequence of `y` and a number otherwise (i.e. ruby equivalents to `false` and `true`). Examples:

```
p s['','z00']        # => 0   (i.e. true)
p s['z00','z00']     # => 0   (i.e. true)
p s['z00','00z0']    # => nil (i.e. false)
p s['anna','banana'] # => 1   (i.e. true)
p s['Anna','banana'] # => nil (i.e. false)
```

Comment: i did basically the same thing, but it's too similar so i won't post it. i think it is acceptable to leave off the lambda, which would leave you with `y=~/#{[*x.chars]*".*"}/` (23 chars). cheers!

Comment: or even `y=~/#{x.split("")*".*"}/` (21 chars) :)

Comment: @padde The split one is actually 24 chars.

Comment: sorry, i guess i accidentally left off the `y=~` while fiddling with this in irb...

Comment: [My version](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5559/3121) is 2 char shorter.

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, <del>51</del> 37

```
h@(f:l)%(g:m)=f==g&&l%m||h%m;x%y=x<=y
```

Thanks to Hammar for the substantial improvement. It's now an infix function, but there seems to be no reason why it shouldn't.

Demonstration:

```
GHCi> :{
GHCi| zipWith (%) [""   , "z00", "z00" , "anna"  , "Anna"]
GHCi|             ["z00", "z00", "00z0", "banana", "banana"]
GHCi| :}
[True,True,False,True,False]
```

Comment: Since the empty list is smaller than any other list, you can simplify the base cases to `s x y=x<=y`. Also, you can save a few more by making it an operator and using an `@`-pattern instead of `(f:l)`. This cuts it down to 37 characters: `h@(f:l)%(g:m)=f==g&&l%m||h%m;x%y=x<=y`

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 45 bytes

```
lambda a,b:{1,l:=iter(b)}>{c in l for c in a}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY3BCoMwDIbvPkVurUOh3obgYO_hJd1aLHSpuLqh4pPsIoztnXybWd3JHJL_-0jI61t3vnI0vXVRflqv0-OcWrzJKwImMh-yxOaF8arhMh5PwwUMgQXtGlgjjv8jeFbGKsjyujHkueYH9UDLDdWt5_FS2940V4wlwHohWLT2PQjRB0IMgEQYIIwFJRKu4rwXKO_Otl7ZLmhynkXbwx8)

Builds on [@qwatry's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217976) used in [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180287): `iter` consumes elements as they are searched for, so `c in l` "uses up" the character if it is found.

Some trickery lets us combine the `all` and the iterator assignment:

- `{c in l for c in a}` is a set comprehension which effectively deduplicates its contents, so it's always one of `{}`, `{False}`, `{True}`, or `{False, True}`
- `1` and `0` are equivalent to `True` and `False`
- The `>` operator tests if `{True, iter(b)}` is a strict superset of the result, which is true only if that result is `{}` or `{True}`, i.e. all the `c in l` expressions were true
- By including `l:=iter(b)` in the set, we can sequence the evaluation order correctly with minimal parentheses by reusing the set's `{}` grouping
- It also lets us use `>` instead of `>=` because the iterator will never be present in the boolean set
- Otherwise, `>=` would be necessary because `{True}` is not a strict superset of `{True}`

Answer (score 6):

### Python (48 chars)

```
import re;s=lambda x,y:re.search('.*'.join(x),y)
```

Same approach as Howard's Ruby answer. Too bad about Python's need to import the regex package and its "verbose" `lambda`. :-)

Comment: I agree, lambda is verbose.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 42 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:''in[a:=a[a[:1]==c:]for c in b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcqxDoMgFAXQWb@CDUgcMF0aEoZ@B2W4WI0k9kkItqk/T8XR5d2ce1/85Xml2z2mMplnWfD2LzB0XnMeyEIbWFjdO2MG7aY1sYEFYt6V7xyWkfW6bY5vM36wiEBxy0LKtokpUBaTOCYpC@cd47tSvD3vFUrtVUAFiFBR46AH4Swel@IP)

**[Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 48 bytes**

```python
lambda a,b,j=0:all((j:=1+b.find(c,j))for c in a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XctBCsMgEAXQdTyFO2eoFEM3JeCi9@hmTCJR7ERC2tJc3sYss5nP@5/Jv3Wa@XbPS/H2WRK93ECStNPRmo5SAoidbS/u6gMP0OuI6OdF9jKwJCzfKaRRtp1o9h87fihB4PxeAVE0eQm8god9QixKaak2Y5Q47hnGbFVEFcRMFTV2OmI6isep@AM)

In Python 3.10+, we don't need parens around the walrus expression for [46 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XYxBDoIwEEXXcIru2molZWdIuuAMbt1MgYYmdSCkaOQqbkiM3onb2CIb3czP-z9vHu_-7tsO56dR59fozeG4ZA4uugYCQgurZAHOMVsonRmLNauE5fvcdAOpiEUCfLN2t9a6huRFmgRRNVcIFvajZ5ynST9Y9MywMPHNmJcTpYLQSUqarvcfpJwiAUQARIgQI6AGhLUof4vv7w8).

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes**

```python
lambda a,b:re.search('.*'.join(a),b)>0
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XctBCsMgEIXhdTyFu9EiYrsMpNB7dDO2Bi3JKNZSmstbzTKbeXw/TPoVH@lS5@leF1ztEzkqO2an3w7zwwvQJ9CvGEigVFZeDQtrirnw7OrXh8Xx88iG9jMFSp8iJBtSDlTELFqUsgIoDpsxwPZ7hDFbF2IHEmFHn0aLhHu4HcIf)

Copied from [this answer of Lynn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180248/20260). The `>0` can be omitted if just truthy/falsey output is OK.

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes**

```python
def f(a,b):l=iter(b);print all(c in l for c in a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcwxDsMgDAXQOZzCGyBloB1TZehRTAuKJctBiKpqLk8CmdLF3@9LdvqVZZV7re8QIRocvZ14phKy8faRMkkBZDYvIAGGuGboK9r6XYgD3CY1HFczSfoUY9VwPqlaj6A357Tq8x/ObU2IDSiCDS0OehTsxfNa7A)

A dazzling new method [introduced to me by qwatry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217976/20260). The idea is that turning `b` into the iterator `l` will consume values whenever they are read. So, checking `c in l` will consume values left to right until it finds one that equals `c` or it reaches the end.

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes**

```python
f=lambda a,b:b and f(a[a[:1]==b[0]:],b[1:])or''==a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcuxCoMwGATgWZ8i228gQ@wYyNDnCBnux4qC/Q2SUurLp4mjyx3fwaVfXnZ5lDL7DW@eoGDYsYJMah4QENwYvedgo4uGw@ii3g8i71G@y7q91Oj6rn78KumTB9136VglD/VsWOtCZBSd1lJ/5R3Wnk1AA0TQ0KqSIbiG5234Aw)

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes**

```python
lambda a,b:reduce(lambda s,c:s[c==s[:1]:],b,a)==''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcuxDoMgEMbxWZ6CDUgYsCMJQ5/DOhyIkcReiWBMfXkKppPLffn9k4vfvHzwUWbzKiu87QQUpNWbn3bn@b8k6XQanDFp0P2oR2klCGMYK8cSVk97Tbr6ZQLGPXNBurgFzHzmNQpRGJOUnUoxct07lDqbABoAERraVFpAuMLzFn4)

Comment: Great use of the walrus.

Answer (score 5):

### Python, 59 characters

```
def s(x,y):
 for c in y:
  if x:x=x[c==x[0]:]
 return x==""
```

I figured my answer would be better expressed in Python.

Edit: Added r.e.s.'s suggestions.

Comment: Surely given `x="a"` and `y="ab"` you would exit the loop with `y=="b"` and return `false`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yeah, I noticed when I was running the examples as tests after posting that I've mixed `x` and `y` up. In my functions `y` needs to be a subsequence of `x`. I think I'd better change them to avoid any confusion.

Comment: You can get this down to 59 chars: `def s(x,y):
 for c in y:
  if x:x=x[c==x[0]:]
 return x==""`. It doesn't display correctly in a comment, but I think you can see what I mean. (Also, one added space is enough to increase the indent level.)

Comment: @r.e.s. Thanks, Python's not a language I use much as you can probably tell. Nice golfing. (63 characters according to the Codegolf userscript - it must be counting the newlines).

Comment: The `if` statement can all go on one line, with no space after the colon, bringing the count down to 59.

Comment: @r.e.s. Like I said - my Python-fu is weak. :-)

Comment: you could probably save one more character on the third line if you follow this suggestion: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58/3527

Comment: You can use extending slicing to protect against x being `''` and save several chars by writing `x=x[c==x[0:1]:]`

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
⊆ᵈ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFSuVv2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU5VqQKy0xJziVKXaciU9BaWHuzprH26d8P9RV9vDrR3//0dHKynpKFUZGCjF6kSDaXSegUEVhJuYCOQl5uUlQnggho5SUmJeIlTEEVUkFgA)

As with [this answer,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180657/85334) `⊆` is a built-in predicate that declares a relationship between the input and output variables, and `ᵈ` is a meta-predicate that modifies it to declare that same relationship between the first and second elements of the input variable instead (and unify the output variable with the second element but as this is a decision problem that doesn't end up mattering here). `X⊆Y` is an assertion that X is a subsequence of Y, therefore so is `[X,Y]⊆ᵈ`.

This predicate (which of course outputs through success or failure which prints `true.` or `false.` when it's run as a program) takes input as a list of two strings. If input is a bit more flexible...

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 1 byte

```
⊆
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFSuVv2obcOjpuaHWzsedSxXKikqTVWqAbHSEnOKU5Vqy5X0FJQe7uqsfbh1wv9HXW3//0dHKynpKFUZGCjF6kSDaXSegUEVhJuYCOQl5uUlQnggho5SUmJeIlTEEVUkFgA)

Takes string X as the input variable and string Y as the output variable. Outputs through success or failure, as before. [If run as a full program,](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FX2///Sol5eYlK/5WSEvOAUAkA) X is supplied as the input and Y is supplied as the first command line argument.

Answer (score 4):

### GolfScript (22 chars)

```
X[0]+Y{1$(@={\}*;}/0=!
```

Assumes that input is taken as two predefined variables `X` and `Y`, although that is rather unusual in GolfScript. Leaves `1` for true or `0` for false on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

### C (52 chars)

```
s(char*x,char*y){return!*x||*y&&s(*x-*y?x:x+1,y+1);}
```

[Test cases](http://ideone.com/kMU8Y)

Comment: `s(char*x,char*y){x=!*x||*y&&s(x+(*x==*y),y+1);}`

Answer (score 4):

## Burlesque (6 chars)

6 chars in Burlesque:
    `R@\/~[`
(assuming x and y are on the stack. See [here](http://eso.mroman.ch/cgi/burlesque.cgi?q=%22anna%22%22banana%22R%40%5C%2F~%5B) in action.)

Answer (score 4):

## C, 23:

```
while(*y)*x-*y++?0:x++;
```

result in *x

http://ideone.com/BpITZ

Answer (score 3):

### PHP, 90 characters

```
<?function s($x,$y){while($a<strlen($y))if($y[$a++]==$x[0])$x=substr($x,1);return $x=="";}
```

Comment: You can remove the `if` statement and simplify to `$x=substr($x,$y[$a++]==$x[0])`: http://ideone.com/Ch9vK

Comment: Also here is a slightly shorter 82-character solution using recursion: http://ideone.com/IeBns

Answer (score 3):

## C #, <del>70</del> <del>113</del> <del>107</del> 90 characters

```
static bool S(string x,string y){return y.Any(c=>x==""||(x=x.Remove(0,c==x[0]?1:0))=="");}
```

Comment: Doesn't this search for a substring rather than a subsequence?

Comment: yes, I misread. Should be fixed now.

Comment: As fun as Linq is, I think you can save 10% by using recursion instead.

Comment: Here's my best attempt. Still longer.  `static bool S(string x,string y){if(x!=""&&y=="")return false;return x==""||S(y[0]==x[0]?x.Remove(0,1):x,y.Remove(0,1));}`

Comment: You can reduce the recursive one to `x==""||y!=""&&S(...)`, but it's still longer than the updated Linq version. Nice use of `Any`!

Answer (score 3):

#### Scala 106:

```
def m(a:String,b:String):Boolean=(a.size==0)||((b.size!=0)&&((a(0)==b(0)&&m(a.tail,b.tail))||m(a,b.tail)))
```

Answer (score 3):

### CoffeeScript <s>112</s> <s>100</s> <s>95</s> 89

My first attempt at code golf... hope I don't shame my family!

```
z=(x,y)->a=x.length;return 1if!a;b=y.indexOf x[0];return 0if!++b;z x[1..a],y[b..y.length]
```

**Edit**: turns out Coffeescript is more forgiving than I thought with whitespace.

**Thanks to r.e.s. and Peter Taylor for some tips for making it a bit sleeker**

Comment: A few more chars can be eliminated as follows (this won't display right in a comment, but I think you can see what I mean): `z=(x,y)->
 a=x.length
 return 1if a==0
 b=y.indexOf x[0]
 return 0if b<0
 z x[1..a],y[b+1..y.length]`. (In some browsers, e.g. Chrome, you can see comment code properly displayed by right-clicking, then Inspect Element.)

Comment: `a.length` is never going to be negative, so you can save one character more by replacing `if a==0` with `if a<1`. I don't know how CoffeeScript's tokenisation works, but if it lexes `if0` as two tokens you could save two more by reversing both conditions (i.e. `if1>a`).

Comment: Good points. `if1>a` isn't valid, but `if!a` is and is a character shorter! I also realised that I could shave an extra character converting `b+1` to `b` and incrementing it on the previous line, also making the same `if` trick possible since it was dealing with a 0/non-0 situation.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <strike>19 17</strike> 27

`LongestCommonSequence` returns the longest non-contiguous subsequence of two strings.  (Not to be confused with `LongestCommonSubsequence`, which returns the longest contiguous subsequence.

The following checks whether the longest contiguous subsequence is the first of the two strings. (So you must enter the shorter string followed by the larger string.)

```
LongestCommonSequence@##==#&
```

**Examples**

```
LongestCommonSequence@## == # &["", "z00"]
LongestCommonSequence@## == # &["z00", "z00"]
LongestCommonSequence@## == # &["anna", "banana"]
LongestCommonSequence@## == # &["Anna", "banana"]
```

True True True False

The critical test is the third one, because "anna" is contained non contiguously in  "banana".

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 41 Bytes

prints 1 for true and nothing for false

```
<?=!levenshtein($argv[1],$argv[2],0,1,1);
```

If only insertions from word 1  to word 2 done the count is zero for true cases

[levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#ZczBCoJAEAbgu09hW7AKE@x21ZIuPUE328MkUyvIKm55MHp2U9fEaE7D//H/cVLpyruVNWGmgzRlWwacA2@F4Mpfn@sneeDSIZrB729A/1eFaL98wsLOXcQe0RiccLk7xsCvaHDypR7/1A0rtBus7034Sg5dnOxXBTVkrH5QboJRUqnAPTsFAiTIMOoo0yW7GBa9uw8)

### PHP, 57 Bytes

prints 1 for true and 0 for false

Creates a Regex

```
<?=preg_match(_.chunk_split($argv[1],1,".*")._,$argv[2]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#Zc9NDoIwEAXgPacg1aRgKiluQYkbT@AOm2YkhRqxNAVcYDw78ifBOMv3zbxkwkhLbaWFEZBIJ47RFhGMCW4oxcxenU0tLDKmfTSD3U2P9q9S2nz5BHk53wJ0CErBhMveISb4CgomX@rxT8diBuUaTPZ0X9GhDaO9NiLjD6i6L7iXyFrdeanzW@UMW7HPiE@Qt0Gux8kY7ZgbtCKRBbooFLzbDw)

Comment: -2 bytes: leading `.*` is unnecessary. -2 bytes: don´t assign `$argv` to `$a`. +24 bytes: needs `array_map(preg_quote())` for special characters (use parentheses as delimiters to avoid second `preg_quote` parameter.)

Comment: @Titus the leading .* is necessary for the input of an empty string and for the input I must only handle  a possibly-empty case-sensitive alphanumeric string. You are right with the quote if there are special characters. Thank you for counting the assign. Copy and paste by an earlier solution and not think about it

Comment: `preg_match` will not complain about an empty regex as long as the delimiters are there. It will just match anything. But preg_quote is only +22 bytes, not +24: `array_map(preg_quote,str_split(...))`.

Comment: But then, input is guaranteed to be alphanumeric :) But you still don´t need the leading `.*`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 36 bytes

```hs
(a:b)%(c:d)=([a|a/=c]++b)%d
s%t=s<=t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYq9DsIgFIV3n@LmRhJINTI33sGncGgYbqlaIhIiTMRnF2nj0JzhO38zp@fN@1ol96MS0vaTIjnwh09kTde1btolkSmdKdcXuwAE8e1Chj0UF68uzyCFggERAA6ARWv8Y4kcAuM6XBZn2nHzaNC6rBw5NG2cqV979/xI9Whj/AE)

---

**37 bytes**

```hs
(.map concat.mapM(\c->["",[c]])).elem
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYtBCsMgEEX3PcUgLRhIghew0AN03UXiYiraSHUijSsPX6uhizCL9z7/z4Lb23hfrJwLHwNG0CtpTE3vfNbDdWKsn7RSXTcab0Lhl07aU0BHICF@HCU4Q3bx4dICtYT6AAA9sCwE@6NFJEK2F7dmqg4Piwoh8s4nUr2DqfLV1uNrK4OO8Qc)

I think `mapM` postdates this challenge. If we can assume the characters are printable, we can do

**36 bytes**

```hs
(.map(filter(>' ')).mapM(:" ")).elem
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYrBCsIwEETvfsWwKE1AJWchQj/AswftYS2JDSYhtDn1441p8VD28N7szMDTx3hfrH4WcQ6chHU@m1FcGzRSLp@buBCouvEmFHGQ2u4CuwiNNLqYscfs0t3lAbXEgwjAETQrRX8skWNkWot2sa4ON4sKpeaVL471NtaVb289v6dy6lP6AQ)

---

**37 bytes**

```hs
(null.).foldr(?)
c?(h:t)|c==h=t
c?s=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYqxCgIxEER7v2IJFgnokVpYDr/CQq9YozHBNRcusQl@uzF3WBxTvHnMOErPO3O1eKkyvJk71dmRb5Ps1cb00h2y@hhEh7lpwlRf5AMgxMmHDFsoPp58dmDhLAQA7EAUrcUfs1IIJJbhOLehHVePBq3LwiuFllUb6tdYpkeqexPjDw)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (no regex), 45 bytes

```js
y=>x=>(i=0,[...y].map(c=>c==x[i]&&i++),!x[i])
```

Should be called like

```
f(haystack)(needle)
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYw9T8MwEIb3/grXkWKbBNdda10QCwMDDLBFGY7UkQyuazkJSoL47aGJhEDqLfd@3D3v@IltHW3obttgjyaezv7DjHMD8wjFAAW3oPJSSjlW8oSB11DUAENpqzS1WSby7aLFrJtz5BMozR1Eg0dnveFCbMH3zmnxNaVpiNZ3XOgJ9pogPL48P8mAsTWclSxzMprgsDZ8l8ibXc6YyFjFhCYDYKkqPV7WvtIk9F3bRc4bPgo@iDv2GntzIIQd2AO69iIvn07o75nSnCxDJ6XoIhKy3G5Wn1/l5K9QalqbhKzIDUVcWRS9R/qPtPqc0Df0uDS/@f1VvoJ@AA "JavaScript (SpiderMonkey) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## C - <strike>74 71</strike> 64

This doesn't beat Peter Taylor's solution, but I think it's pretty fun <strike>(plus, this is a complete working program, not just a function)</strike>

```
main(int c,char**v){for(;*v[1]!=0;++v[1])v[2]+=*v[1]==*v[2];return*v[2];}
```

---

```
main(int c,char**v){for(;*v[1];++v[1])v[2]+=*v[1]==*v[2];return*v[2];}
```

---

```
main(c,v)char**v;{while(*v[1])v[2]+=*v[1]++==*v[2];return*v[2];}
```

And ungolfed:

```
main(int argc, char** argv){
   char * input = argv[1];
   char * test  = argv[2];

   // advance through the input string. Each time the current input
   // character is equal to the current test character, increment
   // the position in the test string.

   for(; *input!='\0'; ++input) test += *input == *test;

   // return the character that we got to in the test string.
   // if it is '\0' then we got to the end of the test string which
   // means that it is a subsequence, and the 0 (EXIT_SUCCESS) value is returned
   // otherwise something non-zero is returned, indicating failure.
   return *test;
}
```

To test it you can do something like:

```
./is_subsequence banana anna && echo "yes" || echo "nope"    
# yes
./is_subsequence banana foobar && echo "yes" || echo "nope"    
# nope
```

Comment: `!=0` in a condition is a bit verbose... Program vs function is something which the question needs to specify clearly, and here it doesn't, so the answers take different options.

Comment: Damn, that `!='\0'` is a bad (good?) habit from writing non-golf code, I've let that slip into my last two rounds of golf, I'll have to be more careful in the future. As to program vs. function, yes, you're absolutely right.

Comment: @GordonBailey sorry for the bump, but I made a few changes into a shorter version.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 28

```
f=->a,b{b.match a.tr'','.*'}
```

This will return `MatchData` instance if `a` is subsequence of `b` or `nil` otherwise.

**Old version that find substring instead of subsequence**

### Ruby 15

```
f=->a,b{!!b[a]}
```

Using `String#[](str)` method that returns `str` if `str` is a substring of `self` and `!!` to return `Boolean` if returned value can be usable as boolean (and don't need to be `true` or `false`) then it can be only 13 chars:

```
f=->a,b{b[a]}
```

It will return `nil` if `a` is not a substring of `b`.

Comment: Nice, but the question asks for a subsequence rather than a substring.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, <del>66</del> <del>62</del> <del>59</del> 58 chars

Kind of a fun solution, definitely a neat problem.

```
def f(n,h,r=0):
 for c in h:r+=n[r:r+1]==c
 return r==len(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

## SWI-Prolog, SICStus

The built-in predicate [sublist/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sicstus_lists%3asublist/2) of SICStus checks whether all the items in the first list also appear in the second list. This predicate is also available in SWI-Prolog via compatibility library, which can be loaded by the query `[library(dialect/sicstus/lists)].`.

Sample run:

```
25 ?- sublist("","z00").
true.

26 ?- sublist("z00","z00").
true .

27 ?- sublist("z00","00z0").
false.

28 ?- sublist("aa","anna").
true .

29 ?- sublist("anna","banana").
true .

30 ?- sublist("Anna","banana").
false.
```

The byte count can technically be 0, since all we are doing here is querying, much like how we run a program and supply input to it.

Answer (score 2):

## x86-16 machine code, <del>12</del> 10 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: 41ac f2ae e303 4a75 f8c3                 A.....Ju..
```

**Unassembled listing:**

```
41          INC  CX                 ; Loop counter is 1 greater than string length 
        SCAN_LOOP: 
AC          LODSB                   ; load next char of acronym into AL 
F2 AE       REPNZ SCASB             ; search until char AL is found 
E3 03       JCXZ DONE               ; stop if end of first string reached 
4A          DEC  DX                 ; decrement second string counter 
75 F8       JNZ  SCAN_LOOP          ; stop if end of second string reached 
        DONE: 
C3          RET                     ; return to caller
```

Callable function. Input: `Y` string pointer in `SI`, length in `CX`. `X` string pointer in `DI`, length in `DX`.  Output is `ZF` if `Truthy`.

**Example test program:**

This test program uses additional PC DOS API I/O routines to take multi-line input from `STDIN`.

[image]

Comment: x86-16 assembly is amazing! I thought this is going to take at least 20 bytes.

Comment: @2x-1 Yes it is! It's my goal to someday submit a valid answer to a question using only single-byte x86 instructions!

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 82 bytes

```
func[x y][parse/case y collect[foreach c x[keep reduce['to c 'skip]]keep[to end]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bckxDoMwDEDRnVNYWRibuVuv0NXy4DqOikBJlIAEXD6QpQKp438/q6tvdUidf0L1SxBcYSNMnIs@hIvCBhKnSWVGH7OyfEFgxVE1QVa3iGI/x9P6Mg6JqA08QYMjopryEGbwYAyY3VrT/aDVf7N2vyLzaRwCX60lmA8Hvvnr5vUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
ＦηＦ⁼ι∧θ§θ⁰≔Φθμθ¬θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYg7DoQwDAV7TuHSlkCip6IAaRvEFbzhFynrKB/Q3t4E5hXzNObgaDw71c1HwIPg9RBOdgltDb0sGIryR5b1/9yWCtCnZHfB0bq8xif/qIZAXTVHKxknnzEQdaoswtWXpUyby90) Link is to verbose version of code. Uses Charcoal's default Boolean output of `-` for true, nothing for false. Explanation:

```
Ｆη
```

Loop over the characters of `Y`.

```
Ｆ⁼ι∧θ§θ⁰
```

See if this character is the next character of `X`.

```
≔Φθμθ
```

If so then remove that character from `X`.

```
¬θ
```

Were all the characters of `X` consumed?

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
æQà
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LLAwwv@/09KzANCrsS8vEQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXC/8PLAg8v@K/zPzpaSUlHqcrAQClWRyEazMDgGhhUQfmJiUBuYl5eIpQLYukoJSXmJcKEHFGFYgE).

Or alternatively:

```
æså
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LLiw0v//09KzANCrsS8vEQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXC/8PLig8v/a/zPzpaSUlHqcrAQClWRyEazMDgGhhUQfmJiUBuYl5eIpQLYukoJSXmJcKEHFGFYgE).

With both programs the first input is \$Y\$ and the second input is \$X\$.

**Explanation:**

```python
æ    # Get the powerset of the (implicit) input-string `Y`
 Q   # Check for each if it's equal to the (implicit) input-String `X`
  à  # And check if any are truthy by taking the maximum
     # (after which this result is output implicitly)

æ    # Get the powerset of the (implicit) input-String `Y`
 s   # Swap to take the (implicit) input-String `X`
     # (could also be `I` or `²` to simply take input)
  å  # Check if this string is in the powerset-list of strings
     # (after which this result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Regex (PCRE2 <sub><sup>v10.35+</sup></sub>), 25 bytes

```
^((.)(?*.*
(\3?+.*\2)))*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZDPatwwEMbp1U-hzppYcrW2t7mEVYwpdBMCJSlubnEiFEfOOnhlI3svKXmJXnsJhD5EH6V9mo60LSmJQXjmm4_f_Pn-NKyHx99vng4LDEhoSU4gBZKQwepbafXQqVrTKE3iQsq16iZZ95uh7bStaMVEVaZjxEmEr0FR3mpnMJM200ilPDr5tJKScbJgiIR0CyJoekvDNs9E2OUN-kf65fzjySkT7CtpGxp2F-NkO20wYvPFZZ5DZYChedxeYwVlnvH5ggnvbpmu172zCILUhQgI6oQ-M_b2EJkhJ4IIW4Sb3K-2UVO9pqHld31rqAPwu7E38kbX_Y2mcAHJixPMkjiNOK6K0AQugTGcwXXf3apT4yS1tbgee5t_LlfH8vRMrsryrCxg5fQlgSUNNwWc261eEszgSHUjhoCkB5zc0yDsQDy8uDZl4sd2auYHP68oTRgt4iQOaLVfvEvi6j2OEge7-uPf369vAJy4D-6zDFwwI65x4HP-SifPhSy795UZ8fMFoJRngTJGwX8kn3MC18ooV_mnf3ile9ButD8)

Takes input as **X** followed by **Y**, delimited by a newline.

This abuses molecular lookahead `(?*`...`)` to save a byte. Instead of using a lazy quantifier `.*?` to advance only as far as necessary to find the next matching character, it greedily lets the regex engine do all the work by backtracking until it is able to match all of **X** in **Y** (or fail to, after trying all possibilities).

This beats [mbomb007's Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/75219/17216) by 1 byte, though not when ported to .NET (in that it is 29 bytes – see below).

## Regex (Perl / PCRE / Java), 26 bytes

```
^((.)(?=.*
(\3?+.*?\2)))*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY4xb8IwFIT3/IonY8l2mjpOqy6YkCLRDh3oUDagloEgUbkJJDCUKPz11E6KioQXv7vv@Xy7tDBPzbFM4e3jfSLh@wdwIaEy@UobwKG0Mh6MR9PRsPY2eUHxNhZyMJT2jlgF2411WLUrttkB0DxDsgZsIIbyuCwPdl0F91EQsXTvICRXvrCEQR@wkh7YIKAXZixzTwgirMJ7m4aNLWKHM5Rhj/uh66Wtv05X@TpVX2WeAZkRjvecLMgffK6wrmdiwd3XvFPRQkJXllK3dIYQFyFLyLQ4pn0A0iev2pR2JEzWtle37P6vlXqZjJVqPinljCYx9z06f0zuuJ/MHxhjvtc0CAXgDjoJgdzQA5fstTq48eEfCHFqSQ/aAh7Sus1COss0ukpqdQBoqTPtyMUf3fht0C8) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLBbtswDL37KzjGqKVMsZ3tFsczhs0tAgxJ4RS71J2gOErjwrED2dmGFvn2jPJQdEtv1Yl8pB75SK5Uuz3NLpcxGK3WMDJr8Dww06kn3/Q8Z5rst3twDcSAAYIPe6PvpdH7ShWaeYE/TKTcqqqTRbPbl5U2Oct5lGdB6wkqLmBDoLzXNqHudN21TMrL2bdUSi5gzIkSgwNGzuaXKTvNljdf0ywTeP0lS@En8uh/nEjaTtUd82yC/J5my9li7vHzPMxr@utsGsPcMg4jt4o31ERr47M5j/gTlBvmVrdtZypdk8VH47s47v9RcntYUYRgEYrRmEd9dsl1sW1sSgTEOo4cIBzYC8fFBVGGxOOhRyXcXdzPa6e6YstcIx6asmaWQDy0TS3XumjWmuEt@mdzHfjDwBM0PyL18Q45KQRb/e8CKtV2UhtD8vi7@DpLr@R8IUn4IkswtfgEcMLcXYI35qAnQB5eqqolk@YCR@q8Z0O3wujonO2Q8ej0gzGfsyT2hw7LPybvadP5B2pj6JzedkxOX3BUU80nM5mMxkf8ZOX7dGGR/q0LCA6tCVZlHdibew6dEAXYh49hiNYYgNXk9L54hcNLIAwf@8gAeukOKtVzoaprhf8w9b4AXKla2cgz/vkV3hP9AQ) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFvS@QwEMbf91PMzRabrLHteu82lnJw6yGIHtV31guxZm0lm5a0@0bxs6@THoeHFgIzzzz85k@HdjiclUM7QOyhAMwQUhi8eVLeDFY3hiVZuiyVarWdVNPvhs4aX7Oay7rKxkRAQm9LonoyweAm46aRKXV@cblRigtYcUJitkcZbXvP4q7IZWyLLflHdnP78@KKS/4K3ZbF9m6cvDWOIn6yui8KrB1yMo/7B6qQLHJxsuJydnfcNG0fLBKIupIRkA7sg3F0RMicOAkm1CLeFfNqOz01LYu9eO47xwJAPI@9U4@m6R8NwztMP51gkS6zRNCqBE3xHjmnGUL3v7eyepyU8Z7W49@K39Xml7q6Vpuquq5K3AR9Dbhm8a7EW783a6AMz7UdKUQivdHkMw1ji/Lt07UZl4c/jKWclUW6jFj9vTymf1Kf0hTL6HBAFBA@fMlzDMECQpdozsUXHT4Kef4yVxYwDxOh1jMLtXMa/yPNuQB80E6Hyj/9xxd9Br0D) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJNU9swEIbv@RWLYMjKpMLQGx43Q2fKqXQ6pTcMM4otJwJZNpYMgTS/PV05poVCdZH2XenZL93Ie/nhprjd6KqpWw83ZAtdiyiBl0rntXlXa9VcLYOn6WZG55Ab6RycS21hNUjOS0/bfa0LqMiBF77Vdg6ynbvLKw5@0dYPDr4sc9V4XdPDEcCZNgrK1KqH/ohM5HWhBPkZTz53ZalaVfxQslAtzPprr0V8fjmYJefJENdNfPKwCHxEl86oBFl81VYh5zup7YzhukQn1F0njUN2GEUR43z1@uqWgOjfBayI4P8QCHBIhBndu03cQTrO7DjsPllvtfV36b1qLbTpcKJqqyYEcDyhblzk0lqqVNum85BCKG7Q8OLReVUJbTmNx3rQaZzAUF9/Xyyk@6aWntKDFVBmeieN@fCsJn9DbfHGYgCkRyEeRdz2ylCwLcQSYSidGIBGGGXnfoH8Uwz7@2BEvpDtqceYp@mYjXk/xheoO0KF/9IYmasz3TqPLGOI05OMlvh1eZ2xKx7xjEE0geh/LhJ3RcSnbAJs7yize8eMJ0Okc@nzBbWpolCtqLYW3lHG/1ZbYiVKbQvkMAX2s@3UCQCDE2BnNDIyCLp@8woNqev1KHyJzTWi4DhNRTTC7OP0QETT7JhzHo02YeAbRhmGxZ7imIXDLoQ4o96evNHhryOOn3rPLvTJjJiUPYvRwCV7Qept6sNMWhk8z/rpG70H/QY) - Java

```
^                 # Anchor to start of string X
(
    (.)           # \2 = next character from X (starting at its start)
    (?=           # Atomic lookahead
        .*¶       # Skip to the beginning of string Y
        (         # \3 = concatenation of the following:
            \3?+  # previous value of \3, if set
            .*?   # Advance by as little as possible (minimum zero) to make the
                  # following match:
            \2    # Match the character we captured in \2
        )
    )
)*                # Iterate the above as many times as possible
¶                 # Assert that after doing the above, we've reached a newline,
                  # meaning the loop processed all of string X.
```

Taking the arguments in the opposite order takes **28 bytes**:

```
((.)(?=.*
(\3?+\2)).*)*
\3?$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBha9wwDIa/51doutDYmZvktm/nhTDYdRRGO9J@a4pxU1@TknOCkxuso7/9JnuMltZgkF6JR3o1ddPxSzV1E8QOSsAcIYPJmQflzDTo1rAkz9JKqU4Pi2rH/dQPxjWs4bKp8zkRkNDfkagejG@wi7HLzJQ6O/@xVYoLWHNCYn5AGe1Gx@K@LGQ8lDvqn9nV9bfzCy75H@h3LB5u5sUNxlLET9e3ZYmNRU7N8@GOKiSLQpyuuQzdPTdtN/oWCURdywhIB/bCODkhZEGcBBMaEe/LYG2vl7ZjsROPY2@ZBwjtnP5Nnn8ZNxv2OI9W3Zt2vDcMbzB7c5BVluaJIOM0IsNb5PQk@GX@nW7Q86KMc@SWfyh/1tvv6uJSbev6sq5w6/UN4IbF@wqv3cFsgDI808NMIRLpmYwEGsYDyuc3x2dcHhnLOKvKLI1Y87n62HziPEt5GlESH4@IAvzDp6JAH6zAz4lCLt7p8FIoiqdQWUFYJ0KtAwu1tRpfkUIuAO@01b7yX//6Tg@gvw) - PCRE2

## Regex (<sub><sup>Perl / PCRE / Java /</sup></sub> .NET), 29 bytes

```
^((.)(?=.*
((?>\3?).*?\2)))*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY4xb8IwFIT3/IonY8l2lDpOqy6YkCLRDh3oUDZILQNBonITSGAoUfjrwQ5FRcKL3933fL5tVprn9lBl8P75MZHw8wu4lFCbYqkN4FBaGQ/Go@lo2HjroqR4Ews5GEp7R6yGzdo6rN6Wm3wPaJ4j2QA2EEN1WFR7u66ChyiIWLZzEJIbX1jCoA9YSQ9sENArM5a5JwQRVuOdTcPGFrHDCaqwx/3Q9dLWX2XLYpWp76rIgcwIxztOUvIHX2qsm5lIufuaX1SUSriUpdQtnSDEZcgSMi0PWR@A9MmbNpUdCZON7XVZdv83Sr1Oxkq1X5RyRpOY@x6lyXD@lDDuJ/NHxpjvtS1CAbiDjkIgN/TAhXudDu58@AdCHDvSg66Dh7TuspDOc41ukjodAFroXDty9Ud3fhd0Bg) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVJNb5tAEL3zK6ZjFHYtDLi9GRNUtaSyVNkRjnoJ6WqN1zERXqwFp1Ui/3Z3lipK69yyp5n3Zt98rmS7Pc2ulgkYJdcwMmvwPDDTqSfe9Txnmu63e3ANJIAhQgB7o@6FUftalop5YTBMhdjKuhNls9tXtTIFK3hc5GHr@ZTchw2B4l7ZAN0p3bVMiKvZ90wI7sOYkySGB4ydzS9TdYotb75mee7j9Zc8g0fk8f84ibSd1B3zbID4keXL2WLu8fM4LDT9dTaNYW6VRLFbJxsqorX8bM5j/gzVhrn1bduZWmmy@Gh8lyT9PwpuDytiCPYjfzTmcR9dcVVuGxsSA6mOYwcIB/aqcXFBkhHpeOhRCneX9PPaya7cMtf4D02lmRXwH9pGi7Uqm7VieIvB2VwHwTD0fJofiQZ4h5w6BJv97wJq2XZCGUPt8Q/JdZ59E/OFoMYXeYqZxSeAE@buUrwxBzUB8vBK1i2ZNBc4UuW9Gro1xkfnbIeMx6efjAWcpUkwdBhLL4tPKadlFx@pkqFzet89OX3Okaa0z2YyGY2PeGknENCRxeq3KiE8tCZcVTq0Z/dCnRB9sA@fogitMQDbltP7/hscXokoeuqZAfTdOyhlr4VSa4n/KPW@D7iSWlrmBf/8Bu@F/gA) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFvS@QwEMbf91PMzRabLLHteu821nJw6yGIHtV31guxZm2lm5a0@0bxs6@THIeHFgIzzzz85k/HdjyclmM7QuygAMwQUhideVLOjL1uDEuydFkq1ep@Vs2wG7veuJrVXNZVNiUCEnpbEtWT8QY7GztPTKnzi8uNUlzAihMSsz3KaDs4FndFLuO@2JJ/Yje3Py@uuOSv0G1Z3N9Ns@uNpYgfr@6LAmuLnMzT/oEqJItcHK@4DO6Om6YdvEUCUVcyAtKBfTCOjgiZEyfBhFrEuyKsttNz07LYieehs8wDxPM0WPVomuHRMLzD9NMJFukySwStStAU75FzmsF3/3urXk@zMs7Revxb8bva/FJX12pTVddViRuvrwHXLN6VeOv2Zg2U4bnuJwqRSG80eaBh3KN8@3RtxuXhD2MpZ2WRLiPGyrP6e8npt9QnNMgyOhwQBfgPX/IcfbAA3ygKufiiw0chz19CZQFhngi1DizU1mr8jxRyAfigrfaVf/qPL3oAvQM) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJNU9swEIbv@RWLYIjkpsLQGx6ToTPNqXQ6pTcMM4otJwqy7EgyBNL89nTlmBYaqou070rPfmkhHsTHRXG/VVVTWw8LtLmqeZTAa6X1Sr@rWTmTq@Bp2qlWOeRaOAdXQhlY95LzwuP2UKsCKnTQa2@VmYGwM3dzy8DPbf3o4Msql41XNT4cAEyUllCmRj52R0p4XheSo5@w5HNbltLK4ocUhbQw7a69FenLy94sGUv6uG7kk8d54FPq0imWIIqvykjK2EFqWq2ZKqnjctkK7Sg5iaKIMLZ@e3VHoNS/C1gjwf8hIOAECVO8d5@4D@kwM8Ow@2Sz0zbfhffSGrBpf8JqqyYEcCzBblznwhisVJmm9ZBCKK7X6PWT87LiyjAcj/Gg0jiBvr7uPp8L902uPKYHa8DM1EEas/5Zjf4G2@K1oQGQnoZ4GHHXK43BdhCDhL50ZADVXEsz83PKLmI4PgbN87mwl57GLE2HZMi6Mb5CLREV/kujRS4nyjpPSUYoHZ9nuPivm7uM3LKIZQSiEUT/c6F4yCM2JiMgR6eZOTojLOkjXQmfz7FNFYayvNpZdIkZ/1ttSSteKlNQBmMgP20rzwEInAOZ4MjQQOhm7xXVqG42g/AltneUckbHKY8GmOlF9mnMeDTOzhhj0WAbZr4lmGRY5DmOSTgcQgg16OzRng5/HXH83HkOoctnQIToWARnLsgrUmdjK6bCiOB50S/39A70Gw) - Java
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDRS8MwEMbf@1cct0CSspaqby21k8EeBN982ybGebOVLKlp56Sjf/tMKzJh5iX5vu/yu@NqeyDXlKT1ibl86eiNvtZpauggZvz0JEQsRZHHYSBEcbu6KWQcFqtrKWUYnPhsCji3u7rS9IoyA9blSba1jtSmFExDZYBVpt638lhtvbFM1hF9cOQ/upPHg6taikrbtL3/fOURWudMR45qrTbEJ3HIMzhXQWSsn01XhgCZqLYgmIsfVLspqRFibs0nuXbh7C66b6wBXHrgGmX0bv0w@GxQSjjyR7enFHgPpBvyeqH8nfJeAvbZ/92Y7k@IUxgOdkmCw2MCAykY9fTCh3OQJN2YTGBsFaBSIwuVMQr/kEbt1/qijBqSX//uwh9B3w) - .NET**

The uses an atomic group `(?>\3?)` instead of a possessive quantifier `\3?+` to add .NET compatibility.

### Regex (.NET), 31 bytes

```
(?<=(.)*)
(.*(?<-1>\1))*(?(1)^)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBBT8MwDIXv@xWWFynJtFTttaUwNGkHJG7cxhBheLQoS0raMdSpv72kRWhII5f4vRd/tlK5I/m6IGN65vO1pzf62qSppaNY8F7cXOUikjM5EdEsCJVcPyZShlIk8kn2fDEHXLp9VRp6RZkBa/M42zlPelsIZqC0wEpbHRp5KnfBWMcbRR8c@Y9u5enoy4ZU4eqmC81JQBiTM6M8VUZviU@jGc/g/AqUdWE7U1oCZKLcgWA@utfNtqBaiKWzn@SblXd7dVc7C7gOwA1K9e7CMvhsUUo48Qd/oBR4B2RqCnqlw53yTgJ22f/TmOl6xDkMB9s4xqGYwkCajHp@4cM5iON2TKYwjpqg1iMLtbUa/5BGHb71RVs9JL/@7YU/gr4B)

As a matter of curiosity (even though it doesn't beat the group-building method), here is a version using .NET's Balancing Groups feature.

```
(?<=(.)*)      # In a lookbehind, push each character of string X onto the \1
               # stack, going from right to left. There is no need to use a "^"
               # anchor, because the lookbehind is atomic and will lock in its
               # first greedy full match.
¶              # Assert that the next character is a newline, meaning that the
               # above processed the entirity of string X.
(
    .*         # Skip however many characters as needed to match the following:
    (?<-1>\1)  # Pop a capture off the \1 stack and match it. This is iterated
               # from left to right.
)*             # Iterate the above as many times as possible.
(?(1)^)        # Assert that the \1 stack is now empty (by asserting that if it
               # isn't, then we're at the start of the string – which is
               # impossible because we have at the very least matched a newline).
```

## Regex (<sub><sup>Perl / PCRE / Java /</sup></sub> Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup> / Ruby <sub><sup>/ .NET</sup></sub>), 33 bytes

```
^((.)(?=.*
(?=(\4?))(\3.*?\2)))*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY4/b8IwEMX3fIqTsWQ7Sh2nfxZMSJFohw50KBuhloEgUbkJJDCUKHz11A5FRcKDffd@53dvm5XmqT1UGbx9vE8kfP8ALiXUplhqAziUto0H49F0NGy8dVFSvImFHAylfSNWw2ZtFVZvy02@B5TmSDaADcRQHRbV3o6r4C4KIpbtHITkSheWMOgDVtIDawT0woxl7gtBhNV4Z92wsUFscYIq7HE/dLm01VfZslhl6qsqciAzwvGOkzn5g8811s1MzLlbzc9dNJdwDkupGzpBiMuQJWRaHrI@AOmTV20qWxImG5vrPOz2N0q9TMZKtZ@UckaTmPuevWn6mDBG0wfuJ@k9Y8z32hahANxBRyGQK3rgFnhdH9zo8A@EOHakB10OD2ndeSGd5xpdOXV9AGihc@3IRR/d6J3RLw) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLfb9owEH7PX3E7osZGIQnbnghZNG1phTRBFaq9NJ1lgimpgoOcsE2t@NvZOVPVjb7VD9bdd5@/@@FbyXZ7ml0uEzBKrmFk1uB5YKZTT7zpeM403W/34BpIAEOEAPZG3Quj9rUsFfPCYJgKsZV1J8pmt69qZQpW8LjIw9bzKbkPGwLFvbIE3SndtUyIy9m3TAjuw5iTJIYHjJ3NL1N1ii1vvmZ57uP1lzyDn8jj/3ESaTupO@ZZgvie5cvZYu7xcx4Wmt46m8Ywt0qi2K2TDRXR2vhszmP@BNWGufVt25laabL4aHyXJP07IreHFUUI9iN/NOZxz664KreNpcRAquPYAcKBvWhcXJBkRDoeepTC3SX9vHayK7fMNf5DU2lmBfyHttFircpmrRjeYnA210EwDD2f5keiAd4hpw7BZv/7AbVsO6GMofb4u@Q6z67EfCGo8UWeYmbxCeCEubsUb8xBTYA8vJR1SybNBY5Uea@Gbo3x0Tn7Q8bj0w/GAs7SJBg6dLPiY8o5Kz7QhxfvqZqhc3rbTjl93pGm1E9mMhmNj/jJTiGgRYvVb1VCeGhNuKp0aFfvOXRC9MEefIwitMYAbGtO7/uvcHgJRNFjHxlAPwEHpey1UGot8R@l3vcBV1JLG3nGP7/Ce6E/) - PCRE1
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFdb5swFH3nV9zdoGJHLiHdnsIQmjY6RZqSilZ7KZ3lUlOoCCBDOqlTf3t27arqliIZ3XvO8bkfHurh8Dkd6gF8AwngAiGEweh7afTQqlKzYBHOUylr1U6y7HdD02pTsILHRb4YAwEBnYpAea@toJt0N41MyvP1j0xKLmDJyRIXe4y96rdpJs0ur75leS7w4muencEj8vh/glzGSXUTC6xC/szyy/V2E/BjHRYd3fWq3jC/SaLYb5OKuhgtv97wmP@BpmJ@ez1OptUdRfx0eZMk7h6Jx/0tMQSLSJwueezUDddl3VtJDOS6jD0gHNibx8kJWUbkE2BAJfxd4ha2U1NZM9@Ih77pmDUQD2PfyTtd9nea4TWGR4udhfNFIGiBZBriDXKaEGz1lxdo1ThJbQyNxz8kF3n2XW62kgbf5ilmFl8Brpi/S/HK7PUKKMNz1Y4U0l7gmTp3bui3GD8fvSHj8eEXYyFnaRLOPfqz4lPKOSs@0oMXZ9TM3DscEAXYD5@iCG0wA1vMc7l4h8MbEUVPjpmB68lDpZwXqq5T@I@TywXgreqUZV7xL@9wZ/QX) - PCRE2
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZJNU9swEIbv@RWLYMjKTYWhPeFxM3SmnEqnU3rDMKPYciKQZWPJBEjz29OVY1ooVAdb@6707Jeu5Z18f13cbHTV1K2Ha7KFrkWUwHOl89q8qbVqru6Dp@lmRueQG@kcnEltYTVIzktPv7taF1CRA899q@0cZDt3F5cc/KKtlw6@3Oeq8bqmiyOAU20UlKlVy36LTOR1oQT5GU8@d2WpWlX8ULJQLcz6Yy9FfLo5mCXnyRDXTXyyXAQ@oktnVIIsvmqrkPOd1HbGcF2iE@q2k8YhO4iiiHG@enl0S0D0bwJWRPB/CAQ4IMKMzt0k7l06zuw4/H2y3mrr79J71Vpo02FH1VZNCOB4Qt04z6W1VKm2TechhVDcoOH5g/OqEtpyGo/1oNM4gaG@/rxYSPdN3XtKD1ZAmemdNObDtZr8DbXFG4sBkB6GeBRx2ytDwbYQS4ShdGIAGmGUnfsF8k8x7O@DEflCticeY56mYzbm/RifoW4JFd5LY2SuTnXrPLKMIU6PM1ri18VVxi55xDMG0QSi/7lI3BURn7IJsL3DzO4dMZ4Mkc6kzxfUpopCtaLaWnhLGf9bbYmVKLUtkMMU2M@2U8cADI6BndLIyCDo@tUtNKSu16PwJDZXiILjNBXRiL6YfZxyjtkHEU2zI855NNqEuW8YJRoWe4xjFja7EMKNenvySoe/jjh@7D270Oc0YlL2LEZzl@wZqbepHTNpZfA86Sev9B70Gw) - Java
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9BbsMgEEX3nGI0WQAORaTpyhWyuukJurNTidSkcUSwBY7U@PKpIYpSKWUB/JmvN/OH87jv/frSHYc@jBDPUQT7bX/EIfaeBNAQEPHyyZjkrNKyIPPNmpeKc9asZVE1z5zzglxmV70qn1abV5i0Irs@gIPOJ6KMY9v5kgB0O5hKGELnR8av2lnPHAfjW3D1VcwQrWnjaQlOu1ol6j9mlVxIbzzrW40f4WRLAEzmnEMezfi1Z0FAAspD33mWoknXmzYyWtPl1RdPW0YXsqCCUuH4km7oHAysixbw3cxPCZh2vk9zPGVdzdEFpIOTUpg@C0h7kKzFQx3uDaWm3FlAnkDQmMxC473BP6SsBeDWeJM6t/rbQz2DfgE) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU5PT8IwFL/vUzwfh7ZjlIGeWJaFBD14wES5sbmUWLGkKbNjQTn41WdbQjTh0vT3/9lu891b@dkpK4Hs2r0hkYUcnuVWfjXcyCMs5qs5t1K8ZaDyNIPjh9ISdL6VhzYCUO@gbjzfdIc2A2mCb5J5Qa9HkyrPsTSYuYRep5yPplVwnaOOcgaCxEGA1i0/vjwteSNsKylZk6Hm27bb0PGAx@OEEDYkFWF8t1eG@loWco1V5uDTP2ChAFzZTs4AEGaAD0K3DuBl9OzVZ1jX98tFXfevlHJGi5zHkXtpeVcwRstbHhfllDEWR32PmPgpwFOaov8MwM9EASdXPPwJaXoKygDCLREKEbpQGCPwX1PACeBGGOGVCz@/4kPRLw) - Ruby**
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDNasMwEITvfoplI5BkYuP@nGxMUgI5FHrrLUmpmm5qF0VyZacpDn52V3YpKaQ6SJqZ1beLKnskVxekdc9cvnL0Rl@bNDV0FHPePwkRSzHL4zDwu1jfzqQU65s4nK2vpZRh0PP5FHBh91Wp6RVlBqzNk2xnHaltIZiG0gArTXVo5KnceWOVbCL64Mh/dCtPR1c2FBW2bjr/@MojtM6ZjhxVWm2JT@KQZ3CugshYP58uDQEyUe5AMBc/qGZbUC3EwppPcs3S2X10X1sDuPLADcro3fph8NmglHDij@5AKfAOSNfk9VL5M@WdBOyy/7sx3fWIUxgWtkmCw2UCAykY9fTCh3OQJO2YTGBsFaBSIwuVMQr/kEbtv/VFGTUkv/7dhT@CvgE) - .NET

Copies the capture back and forth between `\3` and `\4` to avoid use of nested backreferences, adding Python and Ruby support (and as the lookahead is atomic, it's also another way of adding .NET support).

### \$\large\textit{Anonymous functions}\$

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/), <s>52</s> <s>51</s> 50 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to MarcMush*
*-1 byte [thanks to MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77608/all-together-now/251237#comment575552_251237)*

```
x->y->count(r"^((.)(?*.*
(\3?+.*\2)))*
",x*'
'y)>0
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBojTbpaUlaboWN40qdO0qde2S80vzSjSKlOI0NPQ0Ney19LS4NGKM7bX1tGKMNDU1tbiUdCq01LnUKzXtDKA6bxUUZeaV5ORppGkoKSkAgaaGUpWBAYipqamgrBBSVJrKhaQGLIdFjQI2RQYGVSBVYEVuiTnFKCYlJiqBbUvMy0tUwmEbWA6oJikxLxHEwqbGEYsasGUQHy5YAKEB)

Yep, Julia string literals can contain an unescaped raw newline!

Beats [Simeon Schaub's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190523/17216) by 2 bytes when both are converted to the same type of declaration, e.g. [currying, as used here](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvu/QteuUtdOo8LWVkmppia6wrYi2sgqNS8lViEtv0gh2bZSITMNSAGFDWNjrcHKNP8XFGXmleTkaaRpKCkpAIGmhlKVgQGIqanJhSQJFiQkaWBQBZJFlUxMVAIbm5iXl4gpCRIESiYl5iWCWCiSjuiS/wE).

Of course, both could also be 2 bytes shorter [with operator overloading](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700qzQnM3HBgqWlJWm6FjcNKmIqbZPzS_NKNIqU4jQ09DQ17LX0tLg0YozttfW0Yow0NTW1uJR0KrTUudQrNe0MoPoOFRRl5pXk5GkoKSkAQYxSlYEBiKWpoKwQUlSaygWXB0tgyCtgKDAwqAKpAClwS8wpRjIhMVEJZENiXl6iEjYbwBIxSkmJeUCohCnviCEPtgDiE1hIAAA).

Comment: @MarcMush Thanks. BTW, I can't help but feel that you disapprove of my presenting the curried function as the answer, rather than the operator-overloading one. My logic is this: there's only one operator available for this type of overload (and even if there were more than one, it'd still be very limited number). A function is supposed to be usable by any program, even a large one. If the presented golfed function can be the only one used by any given program, its being a function is a sham – it's really just a full program masquerading as a function.

Comment: It's commonly accepted (I'm too lazy to find on meta but I'm pretty sure it is) and you can use `$` than is unused by default

Comment: And it returns a function, without changing the original function [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/303BViEntYQrUSvJNlE7iSs1L@W/Q3FGfrmCm4aFjrkmF4RjoWX@HwA "Julia 1.0 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics`, 19 bytes

```factor
[ all-subsets in? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc@xCsIwGATgPU9xzW7JrKA4iYtLcRKHP6HBQJuW5newpc8eQ2ul4o33ccNZMtx08VqcL6ctauJHbppaO0@pdiYglBzQdiXzq@2cZ1AITep3QgwCKQOkhOyVkhjxSQZebII1J8MvKtUvmsEuRpSIvKfV8GtTLTV5mn1lx3@zYhTxBqqqTXjq6ZHzB9yjnd/sa2qRxzc)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 2 bytes

```
iS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNlczcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRABXte7S0pI0XYtFmcEQxs3purVcXLmJmXkKtgop-VwKCgVFCioKmcEKSol5eYlKCkpJiXlAqIQsAxStMjBAEQLxMUUTQQaAzcFUa2BQharYEWKfE8Q-iPMWLIDQAA)

So this is a builtin. There are actually a couple of builtins.  There's also `fiS` which is the same function but the arguments flipped, there `iSW eq` which how `iS` is defined internally.  There's `fe<ss` which gets all subsequences of `y` and checks if `x` is among them. There's `ap eq<lSW` which tests if the longest common subsequence is equal to the second element.

But these are no fun.  Let's have a true no builtins solution

## Regex based, 17 bytes

```
pP<rXx<ic".*"<m p
```

Also

```
pP<rXx<ic".*"<!<p
```

This works like all the other regex answers here.  It adds `.*` between items and then matches a regex.

## Parser based, 15 bytes

```
pP<mF(aK h'<χ)
```

This works similarly to the regex answer.  It replace every character in the string with a parser that matches anything ending in that character.  It then sequences all the parsers and checks if there is any partial matches.

It's cheaper than the regex which is a little surprising.

## Reflections

The regex answer is the one with the most room for improvement.

- There should be functions that build and apply regexes all in one.  It's silly to have to build and then apply the regex separately.  This would save 3 bytes on the regex solution
- Hard to imagine a situation in which `<!<` is going to be useful.  Here we can see it's not saving anything.  Maybe this should be shortened, the docs should have some info about when it is useful.
- There should be more versions of `ic` and `is`.  Some that add copies to the outside, and a versions that are mapped with pure like the regex answer.

With the above changes the regex answer could look like

```
pPX<icp".*"
```

The only other suggestion I have is that *maybe* `aK h'` should get a synonym.  It's basically "ends with", which seems like a concept that might come up again.

Answer (score 1):

### CoffeeScript 73

Here's an alternative CoffeeScript answer, using regexes instead of recursion:

```
z=(x,y)->a='.*';a+=c+'.*'for c in x;b=eval('/'+a+'/');(y.replace b,'')<y
```

If the haystack matches a very greedy regex constructed from the needle, it will be replaced with an empty string. If the haystack is shorter than it started, the needle was a subsequence.

Returns false when `x` and `y` are both empty strings. Think we need a philosopher to tell us if an empty string is a subsequence of itself!

(Posted as a separate answer from my previous because it feels different enough to justify it).

Answer (score 1):

#### PowerShell, 38

```
$args[1]-clike($args[0]-replace'','*')
```

Of course, any such regex- or pattern-matching-based solution has severe performance problems with longer strings. But since shortness is the criterion ...

Answer (score 1):

A sort of anti-solution generating all subsequences of Y:

## Python 93

```
l=len(y)
print x in[''.join(c for i,c in zip(bin(n)[2:].rjust(l,'0'),y)if i=='1')for n in range(2**l)]
```

Answer (score 1):

### APL (31)

String handling is a bit lacking in APL.

```
{(⊂'')∊N←⍵↓⍨¨1,⍨=/⊃¨⍵:~×⍴⊃N⋄∇N}
```

usage:

```
      {(⊂'')∊N←⍵↓⍨¨1,⍨=/⊃¨⍵:~×⍴⊃N⋄∇N} 'anna' 'banana'
1
      {(⊂'')∊N←⍵↓⍨¨1,⍨=/⊃¨⍵:~×⍴⊃N⋄∇N} 'Anna' 'banana'
0
      {(⊂'')∊N←⍵↓⍨¨1,⍨=/⊃¨⍵:~×⍴⊃N⋄∇N} '' 'banana'
1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 132

Similar to Daniero's. Not the easiest solution, but it was fun to try. I'm new to Python, so I'm sure I could make it shorter if I knew a little bit more.

```
def f(i):
    s=x;j=0
    while j<len(s):t=~i%2;s=[s[:j]+s[j+1:],s][t];j+=t;i>>=1
    return s==y
print True in map(f,range(1,2**len(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## **Python - 72**

```
def f(a,b):
 c=len(a)
 for i in b:a=a.replace(i,"",1)
 print len(a+b)==c
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](http://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 26 bytes (not competing)

The language is newer than the challenge. Byte count assumes ISO 8859-1 encoding. Input is taken on two lines with Y first.

```
+`^(.)(.*¶)(?(\1).|)
$2
¶$
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=K2BeKC4pKC4qwrYpKD8oXDEpLnwpCiQyCsK2JA&input=YmFuYW5hCmFubmE)

Answer (score 1):

## Python (<strike>75</strike> 52)

```
s=lambda a,b:a==''or b>''and s(a[a[0]==b[0]:],b[1:])
```

Simple recursive solution. First time golfing, so any tips on whittling this down are much appreciated :)

Tested with the following:

```
assert s('anna', 'banana') == True
assert s('oo0', 'oFopp0') == True
assert s 'this', 'this is a string') == True
assert s('that', 'this hat is large') == True
assert s('cba', 'abcdefg') == False
```

Thanks to @lirtosiast for some clever boolean tricks.

Comment: You can get this down to 52 characters: `s=lambda a,b:a==''or b>''and s(a[a[0]==b[0]:],b[1:])`

Comment: Thanks, that's clever, using the boolean as the 0/1 index into the splice :)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>163</s> <s>162</s> <s>38</s> 35 bytes

```java
a->b->b.matches(a.replace("",".*"))
```

-124 bytes by converting to Java 8, and pasting [my answer from the duplicated challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190420/52210).

NOTE: Doesn't work if the input contains special regex-characters, but this would invalidate a lot of existing answers as well.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZBBS8MwGIbv/RUfOTW2Cz07LejB2047Dg9v2lRT07Qs6WCT/faadgGlIgiBvDzvl@QhLU7YtPXHVBk4Rzto@5kQOQ@vK2pDK0avjWhGW3ndW/ESw8PeH7V9y/8189z3RsGWJTX0OGFTyrBEB1@9K5dCHNVgUKmUsZyJO8b5tE2CxTBKEyyizKnXNXVBML1de3gl8FmWyCvnl8OXomB8@4PN4E9cFJcVBwKGtVjhmeRMwmJdPf2ursn3Dy7Sy@RNmpDHIKP7/uy86kQ/ejGEwhubImMEWxPLZMbuw9YIDIM5p@AxSB5fuk5f)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->b->         // Method with two String parameters and boolean return-type
  b.matches(   //  Check if the second input matches the regex:
   a           //   The first input,
    .replace("",".*"))
               //   where every character is surrounded with ".*"
```

*For example:*

```java
a="anna"
b="banana"
```

Will do the check:

```java
"banana".matches("^.*a.*n.*n.*a.*$")
```

Comment: You're mishandling special regexp characters like "." though

Comment: @StefanReich You're right, but the same applies to almost any other existing answer, though. But I've added a note to mention this in the answer (and golfed it by 3 bytes at the same time).

Comment: Come on... you're saying there is a bug in THIS? >> à øV << (the Japt program, whatever that is)

Comment: @StefanReich The golfing languages like Jelly, Japt, 05AB1E, etc. are probably fine, since most of them just use the powerset and check if the second input is in it. I was referring to the answers using regex like mine, like the accepted Perl answer; the Python answer of Eric; the Ruby answer; etc. All answers that use regex are similar as mine (add a ".*" after each characters, and check if it matches the second input) are most likely invalid if the inputs contain special regex characters.

Comment: I was just messing around :)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>75</s> <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```php
for(;$p=@strpos(_.$argv[2],$c=$argv[1][$i++],$p+1););echo""==$c;
```

takes input from command line arguments; prints `1` for true, empty string for false. Run with `-r`.

**explanation:**

- [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) returns `false` if needle `$c` is not in the haystack `$argv[2]` (after position `$p`),
  causing the loop to break.
- `strpos` also returns `false` for an empty needle, breaking the loop at the end of `$argv[1]`.
- If `$argv[1]` is a subsequence of `$argv[2]`, `$c` will be empty when the loop breaks.
- `strpos` needs `@` to suppress `Empty needle` warning.

Comment: `+$p` instead of `$p+1` after that ther is no need for the underscore

Comment: @JörgHülsermann `+1` is needed to advance in the haystack string; and the underscore avoids `$p=-1` initialization. But ... I can avoid `false!==`.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, 27

```
print(Y.range(of:X) != nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Prompts for Y then for X.

```apl
×≢(∊'.*'∘,¨⍞)⎕S⍬⊢⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P/h6Y86F2k86uhS19NSf9QxQ@fQike98zQf9U0NftS75lHXIiAPpPK/AhgUcFUZGHBxIXNAGMY3MKhCFUjMy0vkSkyE85MS8xJBIiBhNDFHoBgA)

`⍞` prompt (for Y)

`⊢` yield that (separates `⍬` from it)

`(`…`)⎕S⍬` search for occurrences of the following, yielding one empty list for each match:

`⍞` prompt (for X)

`'.*'∘,¨` prepend `.*` to each character

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

`≢` tally the number of matches

`×` sign of that

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), chars 46, bytes 92

```
{(⊂,⍺)∊(⊂''),↑¨,/¨{⍵⊂w}¨{⍵⊤⍨k⍴2}¨⍳¯1+2*k←≢w←⍵}
```

test:

```
  h←{(⊂,⍺)∊(⊂''),↑¨,/¨{⍵⊂w}¨{⍵⊤⍨k⍴2}¨⍳¯1+2*k←≢w←⍵}
  '' h 'z00'
1
  'z00' h 'z00'
1
  'z00' h '00z0'
0
  'aa' h 'anna'
1
  'anna' h 'banana'
1
  'Anna' h 'banana'
0
```

comment:

```
{(⊂,⍺)∊(⊂''),↑¨,/¨{⍵⊂w}¨{⍵⊤⍨k⍴2}¨⍳¯1+2*k←≢w←⍵}
 ⍳¯1+2*k←≢w←⍵    this assign to w the argument and k argument lenght, it return 1..(2^k)-1 range
 {⍵⊤⍨k⍴2}¨      for each element of 1..(2^k)-1 convert in base 2 with lenght k (as the arg lenght)
 {⍵⊂w}¨         use the binary array above calculation for all partition argument
 ,/¨            concatenate each element of partition
 ↑¨             get the firs element of each element because they are all enclosed
 (⊂''),         add to the array the element (⊂'')
 (⊂,⍺)∊         see if (⊂,⍺) is one element of the array, and return 1 true o 0 false
```

How all you can see the comments are +- superfluous all is easy...

I have to say not understand why the last instruction is not "(,⍺)∊" in the place of "(⊂,⍺)∊"
because for example in code

```
  q←{↑¨,/¨{⍵⊂w}¨{⍵⊤⍨k⍴2}¨⍳¯1+2*k←≢w←⍵}
  o q '123'
┌7──────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌1─┐ ┌1─┐ ┌2──┐ ┌1─┐ ┌2──┐ ┌2──┐ ┌3───┐│
││ 3│ │ 2│ │ 23│ │ 1│ │ 13│ │ 12│ │ 123││
│└──┘ └──┘ └───┘ └──┘ └───┘ └───┘ └────┘2
└∊──────────────────────────────────────┘
  o (,'3')
┌1─┐
│ 3│
└──┘
```

all you see array of 1 element (,'3') is the element  of the set of instruction q '123', but

```
  o (,'3')∊q '123'
┌1─┐
│ 0│
└~─┘
```

return one array of unclosed 0 instead of number 1... for workaround that one has to write:

```
  o (⊂,'3')∊q '123'
1
~
```

that is the right result even if the element seems different because :

```
  o (⊂,'3')
┌────┐
│┌1─┐│
││ 3││
│└──┘2
└∊───┘
```

It is sure i make some error because i am not so smart... where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 32 bytes

Repost of a port of [Kevin's Java solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190420/58974) to a duplicate challenge, modified in case my choices for I/O weren't standards at the time this challenge was posted.

```
x=>y=>!!y.match([...x].join`.*`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHRboJAEHxuv2LlpVAtfgEkyK1Aet4S7og1lERisdVYMGIb/Xp7aNpq6z3c5nIzs5OZZfFZNLPNYr19qOqX8jB3DjvH3Ttup7O334vt7M3MbNve5fayXlRT@35qHWZ11dSr0l7Vr2Z2C5kRIucEY0o4M3oGp4QZee9Gn34ftpuPssX4xBAC4kPwBAP9ikQAfuhxjiJAqXnMEwHHI/OMJzV8QE8wpATihGKSyC55rfI3a16smvKKJc6vWPqLYfwX8yMkcAwTSh4hJh75CAxjL1EjFEpzBBHj/5ePPCk9P0wlKiUhElJFKlV4J4GGoNAPBXEKJlpglCpFohU48zWggf5q75OdC9NxgjJiev1RK0RIRaR0JFJ56hhHdJFgrktcm2bW9Ircctyma0AXjG6hp6Pn3Cwss7GsU7vPlW73Cw) (will update with this challenge's test cases when I get back to a computer)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>34</s> 28 bytes

*-6 bytes thanks to nwellnhof*

```perl6
{$!=S:g/<(/.*/;&{?/<{$!}>/}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYu/CsIwGMT3PMUnSJM4NHFxsH/ExRfQTTp8YiJCTSVBpA159hhTBzk47n7cPZXtN/ExQqGhiX65aI7bm6iZKFeiKvxO1ImFVoQQHY6gGaWc0UlKyiuiBwv93SjXtuV7sFcHngDMu/IsO5583XESYjoAZAM42ZcCkouU0xcdsHeKIKaIxuBvQ3K@oEmawf4P5M8H)

Anonymous code block that takes input curried, like `f(X)(Y)`. This does the familiar join by `.*` and evaluate as a regex as other answers, but takes a couple of shortcuts.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                          }  # Anonymous code block
 $!=            # Assign to $!
    S:g/<(/.*/  # Inserting .* between every character
              ;&{         }   # And return an anonymous code block
                 ?/      /    # That returns if the input matches
                   <{$!}>     # The $! regex
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 53 bytes

```julia
f(x,y)=(x==""||[x=x[2:end] for c=y if c==x[1]];x=="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P02jQqdS01ajwtZWSammJrrCtiLayCo1LyVWIS2/SCHZtlIhMw1IAYUNY2Otwco0/xcUZeaV5ORppGkoKekoKFUZGChpanIhiYJE8EkYGFShyyQmgiQS8/IS0SVAQkCppMS8RAxJR3TJ/wA)

Comment: Ties with a [pure regex solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/250848/17216).

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ŒPi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIDM/4eXK/3/r1ScmJOqkJ@nUJyXmpidWlSspKOgVJKfklipBJTLAwpBBBJTlAA)

Outputs `0` for false and a non-negative integer for true

### How it works

```
ŒPi - Main link. Takes X on the left and Y on the right
ŒP  - Powerset of X
  i - Index of y, or 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
€Ṗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HTmoc7p/3//z8pMQ8I/yfm5SUCAA)

Having a single byte builtin for powerset is useful.

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 40 bytes (10 instrs)

C strings.

```
00000000: 8302 0000 8303 0100 dc04 0203 30FF 0203  ............0...
00000010: 73FF FF01 2200 00FF 2301 0101 5b04 fff9  s..."...#...[...
00000020: 7300 0201 f801 0000                      s.......
```

## Disassembly

```
subseq  LDBU $2,$0,0        // loop: av = *a
        LDBU $3,$1,0        // bv = *v
        MOR  $4,$2,$3       // t0 = av && bv (MOR is faster than MUL)
        CMP  $255,$2,$3     // t1 = av <=> bv
        ZSZ  $255,$255,1    // t1 = !t1
        ADDU $0,$0,$255     // a += t1
        ADDU $1,$1,1        // b += 1
        PBNZ $4,subseq      // iflikely(t0) goto loop
        ZSZ  $0,$2,1        // a = !t0
        POP  1,0            // return a
```

Obvious algorithm, with only one branch!

For `wchar_t`, replace `LDBU` with `LDWU` (and similarly for `codepoint_t`);
additionally, replace `ADDU $0,$0,$255` with `2ADDU $0,$255,$0` (`4ADDU` for codepoints), and `ADDU $1,$1,1` with `ADDU $1,$1,2` or `ADDU $1,$1,4`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
ṗc
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4bmXYyIsIiIsIid6MDAnLCAnJ1xuJ3owMCcsICd6MDAnXG4nMDB6MCcsICd6MDAnXG4nYW5uYScsICdhYSdcbidiYW5hbmEnLCAnYW5uYSdcbidiYW5hbmEnLCAnQW5uYSciXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>32</s> 18 bytes

```
~#*{(=/*'x;1)_'x}/
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pT1qrWsNXXUq+wNtSMV6+o1efiKrGqVomurCuySlOosE7Iz7bWSEhLzMyxrrCutC7SjK3lKonWUFJSAAJrpSoDAxBLM9YQLArm4hI1MKgCCWvGGoBFExOVQCYk5uUlKiHUgrnWSkmJeUCoBBN1RBM1AADpVzCb)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `G`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ʠ=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0krtS7IKlpSVpuhaLTy2wXVKclFwM5S9YnZSYB4RciXl5iRAhAA)

Port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
ʠ=  # Implicit input
ʠ   # Powerset of the first input string
 =  # Vectorised equality check with the second input string
    # Check if any are true, and implicitly output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 2 bytes

```
S=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FouCbZcUJyUXQ7kLbvoqVRkYKCkoKXFBGSCSS8nAoArBSczLSwRyEhOB7KTEvEQIDySIxHcE8SGmAgA)

```
S       Check if any subset of the first string
 =      is equal to the second string
```

Answer (score 0):

### C, 120

```
main(i,c){char x[99],y[99];c=0;gets(y),gets(x);for(i=0;y[i]!='\0';)c+=y[i++]==x[c]?1:0;puts(x[c]=='\0'?"True":"False");}
```

Comment: You can save at least 15 chars by moving `c=0` to the loop initialiser and eliminating every instance of `==` in favour of "non-zero is truthy" conditions.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 104 chars

```
function _(x,y){f=true;for(c in x){if(y.indexOf(x[c])>-1)y=y.replace(x[c],"");else{f=!f;break}}return f}
```

Ungolfed

```
function _(x,y){
f=true;
    for(c in x)
    {
        if(y.indexOf(x[c])>-1)
           y=y.replace(x[c],"");
        else {
            f=!f;
            break;
        }
    }
    return f;
}
```

Comment: This appears to test whether x is a *substring* of y, but it's supposed to test whether x is a *subsequence* of y. E.g., 'anna' is a subsequence of 'banana', but `'banana'.indexOf('anna')>-1` evaluates to false.

Comment: @r.e.s. : My bad dint read the question properly. Thanks

Comment: @r.e.s. posted a altogether new answer

Comment: What does the new answer do for `_("ab", "ba")`?

Comment: returns true. demo http://jsfiddle.net/yvAdT/

Answer (score 0):

## J (20 chars)

```
(<x)e.(#:i.2^#y)<@#y
```

The input is given in the variables `x` and `y`. It makes a list of all subsequences of `y`, so don't use it for very big strings.

Answer (score 0):

## Python (72)

```
import itertools as I;any(tuple(X)==Z for Z in I.permutations(Y,len(X)))
```

Comment: No, that use of permutations ignores the required order of the elements; e.g., X='z00' and Y='00z0' should output False (whereas your program outputs True).

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes

Takes input `n` (needle) and `h` (haystack) in currying syntax `(n)(h)`.

```js
n=>h=>!!RegExp(n.split``.join`.*`).exec(h)
```

#### Test

```js
let f =

n=>h=>!!RegExp(n.split``.join`.*`).exec(h)

console.log(f(''    )('z00'   )); // true
console.log(f('z00' )('z00'   )); // true 
console.log(f('z00' )('00z0'  )); // false
console.log(f('aa'  )('anna'  )); // true
console.log(f('anna')('banana')); // true
console.log(f('Anna')('banana')); // false
```

Comment: What if `n` contains regex special characters?

Comment: @Titus Well, I assumed `n` is in `[A-Za-z0-9]` since the challenge mentions that both input strings are _alphanumeric_.

Comment: woops missed that. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
}hQye
```

Explanation

```
}hQye
 hQ       The first input...
}         ... is an element of...
   y      ... the power set...
    eQ    ... of the second input.
```

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 76 bytes

```
o=1
do while x>''
  parse var x a+1 x
  parse var y(a)b+1 y
  o=o&a=b
  end
return o
```

Note that x and y are consumed by this routine. Readability is impaired by skipping a lot of whitespace and parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
x,y=map(list,input())
while x:y.remove(x.pop())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5BCsIwEEXX5hRDN0mhSHHhotCFoBfwAjK2owbsJIxR216@JqUiuJnP@/P/MH4IN8ebqXEt1VrrqS@GukNv7vYRCsv@GUyeq/fN3gn6algLde5Fpl975@Nmih2lLk7gBJZBkK9ktnmlVkGGOFfUU2PS9TyCF8sBsr1tgV0AofAUBhJxkqkYbcgHOMxiHQM@gKpf7TjHqYXDUlgWpL6JLL5TgB7LUqt5/kNZjokQEyAzJkgS8YyMs7H7Mz4)

Takes two quote-delimited strings via STDIN as input.

Output is by [presence or absence of an error](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/73368), which is allowed per meta consensus.

Explanation:

```python
             # get arguments from STDIN
             input()
    # convert each argument to a list
    map(list,.......)
# split arguments into two variables
x,y=..................

# while x still has elements
while x:
                 # remove the final element of x and return its value
                 x.pop()
        # remove the first matching item in y
        # this will error if there is no matching element
        y.remove(.......)

# if the loop is exited without error, all elements in x were in y
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it checks that the removed letters are in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

Repost from a duplicate challenge.

Takes input in reverse order (`Y`, then `X`).

```
à øV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4CD4Vg&input=IkhFTExPIFdPUkxEIgoiTE9SRCI)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
}hQye
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/vzYjsDL1/3@lxLy8RCUdBaWkxDwgVAIA)

---

```
Pyth   | Explanation
-------+------------------------------------------
}hQye  | Full code
}hQyeQ | "       " with implicit variables
-------+------------------------------------------
}      | return whether arg0 is an element of arg1
 hQ    |  first element of input
   y   |  powerset of
    eQ |   last element of input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), <strike>85</strike> <strike>68</strike> 66 bytes

```lua
_,b=...for c in (...):gmatch"."do b=b:gsub(c,"",1)end print(b=="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcfBCoAgDADQXxk7KYjQVdi3xKZlQmmYfv@Sd3r3ZNXdCXnvz9YhQqlgVmzID494ocfUQEhC/qaY6BDdZo@a4O2lDiNEiFZVheuizPwD)

#### Explanation

`...` is the variable argument operator, it returns all remaining arguments to the current function (the top-level block in this case). We can force it to return just one variable by encasing it in parentheses.

`gmatch()` is a pattern-matching function which returns an iterator function, we use it to loop over every character in the input string.

`gsub()` is a substitution function, we use it to clear matched characters from the subset contender. The extra parameter is the number of substitutions to make, 1 in this case.

Comment: This is only checking if the second string contains a subset of the characters in the first string, not if it's a subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-o glob_subst`, 14 bytes

```sh
>:$1>${2///*}*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@F@cWqKgm6@QnpOfFF9cmlRc8t/OSsXQTqXaSF9fX6tW6////0mJeUD4PzEvLxEA)

Explanation:

- `>:$1`: copy stdin to a file named `:` and the first argument. The colon ensures that we don't try to create a file with an empty name in the case of an empty string as input. Since we don't take any input from stdin, this just creates an empty file.
- `>${2///*}*`: try to copy stdin (again) to a file that matches the pattern resulting from the expansion of `${2///*}*` If no such file exists, an error will occur. The `-o glob_subst` ensures that the expanded value is treated as a pattern. Otherwise, it will be treated as a literal string. Alternatively, this option can be removed and `${~2///*}*` used instead for +1 byte.

  - `${2}`: take the second argument
  - `///*`: replace every empty string with an asterisk; this results in `abc` -> `*a*b*c`
  - append another asterisk. Asterisks simply mean "match any sequence

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
ṗƛṅ;$c
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B9%97%C6%9B%E1%B9%85%3B%24c&inputs=anna%0Aaa&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## brev, 78 bytes

```
(define(s(x . xs)y)(aif(memq x y)(s xs(cdr it))#f))(define(s'()y)#t)
```

68 to define `s`, but you've got to call it as `(as-list s)` to handle string input.

```
(define (s (x . xs) y)
  (aif (memq x y) (s xs (cdr it)) #f))

(define (s '() y) #t)

(map (fn (apply (as-list s) x))
     '((""     "z00")
       ("z00"  "z00")
       ("z00"  "00z0")
       ("aa"   "anna")
       ("anna" "banana")
       ("Anna" "banana")))
```

Bonus! Regex version 50 bytes:

```
(fn(with(strse x"."(conc(m 0)".*"))(strse? y it)))
```