# All together now

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Given a list of digits 1 through 9, output whether each digit is grouped together as a single contiguous block. In other words, no two of the same digit are separated by different digits. It's OK if a digit doesn't appear at all. Fewest bytes wins.

**Input:** A non-empty list of digits 1 through 9. This can be as a decimal number, string, list, or similar sequence.

**Output:** A consistent [Truthy](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) value if all the digits are grouped in contiguous blocks, and a consistent [Falsey](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2190/interpretation-of-truthy-falsey) value if they are not.

True cases:

```
3
51
44999911
123456789
222222222222222222222
```

False cases:

```
818
8884443334
4545
554553
1234567891
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=77608,OVERRIDE_USER=20260;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/77608/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Would a list of singleton strings be an acceptable input format?

Comment: Yes, singletons are fine.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what the most efficient algorithm for this problem would be?  Or is there a more general problem that this falls under that I can look up?

Comment: @amt528 You can do it in linear time by iterating over each digit and checking that there's no runs of it past the first.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how it's implemented?

Answer (score 19):

## Python 3, <s>38</s> <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
lambda s:s==sorted(s,key=s.index)
```

This expects a list of digits or singleton strings as argument. Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/lPtREK).

*Thanks to @xsot for golfing off 4 bytes!*

*Thanks to @immibis for golfing off 1 byte!*

Comment: If you are allowed to accept a list of strings instead, you can shorten this to `lambda s:s==sorted(s,key=\`s\`.find)`

Comment: Ah, I tried taking a list, but I didn't think of using backticks... I'll ask the OP.

Comment: Am I missing something - why can't you just use `s.find`?

Comment: @immibis `s` has to be a list of singleton strings (or I'd have to cast `s` to list for the comparison), and `list.find` is not defined...

Comment: @Dennis `s.index` then? Seems to work for me.

Comment: @immibis Yes, that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

### JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

```
s=>!/(.)(?!\1).*\1/.test(s)
```

Uses negative lookahead to look for two non-contiguous digits. If at least two such digits exist, then they can be chosen so that the first digit precedes a different digit.

Comment: Or, just use a regex XD. That works too.

Comment: *ahem* Retina *ahem*

Answer (score 14):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

Code:

```
Ô¹ÙQ
```

Explanation:

```
Ô     # Push connected uniquified input. E.g. 111223345565 would give 1234565.
 ¹    # Push input again.
  Ù   # Uniquify the input. E.g. 111223345565 would give 123456.
   Q  # Check if equal, which yields 1 or 0.
```

Uses **CP-1252** encoding.

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w5TCucOZUQ&input=NDQ5OTk5MTE)

Comment: You...just beat jelly...I never thought this was possible...

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ĠIFPỊ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xKBJRlDhu4o&input=&args=NDQ5OTk5MTE)

#### How it works

```
ĠIFPỊ  Main link. Input: n (list of digits or integer)

Ġ      Group the indices of n by their corresponding values, in ascending order.
       For 8884443334, this yields [[7, 8, 9], [4, 5, 6, 10], [1, 2, 3]].
 I     Increments; compute the all differences of consecutive numbers.
       For 8884443334, this yields [[1, 1], [1, 1, 4], [1, 1]].
  F    Flatten the resulting 2D list of increments.
   P   Product; multiply all increments.
    Ị  Insignificant; check if the product's absolute value is 1 or smaller.
```

Comment: Five bytes you say? What kind of encoding is that?

Comment: Jelly has its own [code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), which encodes each of the 256 characters it understands as a single byte.

Answer (score 9):

## Pyth, <s>6</s> 5 bytes

*1 bytes thanks to FryAmTheEggman*

```
SIxLQ
```

Inspired by the Python solution [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77624/20080).

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=SIxL&input=%22888444333%22&debug=0)

**Explanation:**

```
SIxLQ
  xLQ   Map each element in the input to its index in the input. Input is implicit.
SI      Check whether this list is sorted.
```

Comment: `SIxLQ` seems to work.

Comment: This is genius.

Comment: The second `Q` doesn't seem to get parsed properly, it swaps argument order or something so you get all `0`s and it always gives true. [Here's](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=SIxL&input=%22121%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%223%22%0A%2251%22%0A%2244999911%22%0A%22123456789%22%0A%22222222222222222222222%22%0Aasdf%0A%22818%22%0A%228884443334%22%0A%224545%22%0A%22554553%22%0A%221234567891%22&debug=0) a test suite.

Answer (score 8):

## R, <s>66</s> <s>48</s> <s>46</s> <s>43</s> 38 bytes

```r
function(s)!any(duplicated(rle(s)$v))
```

This is a function that accepts the input as a vector of digits and returns a boolean. To call it, assign it to a variable.

Not the shortest but I thought it was a fun approach. We run length encode the input and extract the values. If the list of values contains duplicates then return `FALSE`, otherwise return `TRUE`.

[Verify all test cases online](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=R8cXhmZ0&version=5)

Saved 20 bytes thanks to MickyT, 3 thanks to Albert Masclans, and 5 thanks to mnel!

Comment: [26](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY_BSgMxEIbveYq4lSYDK5huVtOue_XUo-Cll7RNNBDSmtl6qPgkXqrgS_gCPkPfxtku4sWBCSTzf9-Qt_d8-PDt567zF-ZrIRFsjLKzy-hkpkY4f4abCQyB4ze2lw3ftz7QrMBuHVIBDfObLOc8JI677TY7xHubU0gPKLOz63lIDuUeAF4Y58GTdGU7KRZJQIOtaobXtHq0pAE-HpNniR1dSlUqOGvFSADvmeBdRCe9dFFSALcxdJQqCpKX4i7v3IxzUYpbS7EZFwC9vCfn0LyyVdwQvYdm-M7h-DTiPUQJdMhYxWrFtJ5SKcXUpNL11bWZssl_xdiIn_b80kYZZozRWldVpZmudc1qOurqT6WGzT8) by switching to latest R version and using `table`.

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
t!=tXSP=
```

The output is an array containing only ones for truthy, or an array containing at least one zero for falsey.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dCE9dFhTUD0&input=Jzg4NDQ0MzMzJw)

#### Explanation

Consider the input `22331`, which satisfies the condition. Testing if each character equals each other gives the 2D array

```
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

The final result should be truthy if *the rows of that array (with rows considered as atomic) are in decreasing lexicographical order*. For comparison, input `22321` gives the array

```
1 1 0 1 0
1 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 1
```

in which the rows are not in order.

```
t!   % Take string input. Duplicate and tranpose
=    % Test for equality, element-wise with broadcast: gives a 2D array
     % that contains 0 or 1, for all pairs of characters in the input
t    % Duplicate
XS   % Sort rows (as atomic) in increasing order
P    % Flip vertically to obtain decreasing order
=    % Test for equality, element-wise
```

Answer (score 5):

### Java, <strike>161</strike> 156 bytes

[Because Java...](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5829/16043)

Shamelessly <strike>stealing</strike> borrowing the regex from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77634/16043) because I started out trying to do this with arrays and math manipulation, but it got hideously complex, and regex is as good a tool as any for this problem.

```
import java.util.regex.*;public class a{public static void main(String[] a){System.out.println(!Pattern.compile("(.)(?!\\1).*\\1").matcher(a[0]).find());}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(!Pattern.compile("(.)(?!\\1).*\\1").matcher(args[0]).find());
    }
```

Laid out like a sensible Java person:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.)(?!\\1).*\\1");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(args[0]);
        System.out.println(!m.find());
    }
}
```

Comment: `like a sensible Java person` That would be, not using Java ever.

Comment: Other solutions are just providing a function, would make it a lot shorter. Something like `s->s.match("(.)(?!\\1).*\\1")`

Comment: But then we couldn't revel in the verboseness of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 17 bytes

```
M`(.)(?!\1).+\1
0
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApNYCguKSg_IVwxKS4rXDEKTWAwCilHYA&input=Mwo1MQo0NDk5OTkxMQoxMjM0NTY3ODkKMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyCjgxOAo4ODg0NDQzMzM0CjQ1NDUKNTU0NTUzCjEyMzQ1Njc4OTEKMTIxMjM0MzQzNDQ1NDU0NTY3Njc4OTg5) (Slightly modified to run all test cases at once.)

The first regex matches digits which *are* separated by other digits, so we get a `0` for valid inputs and anywhere between `1` and `9` for invalid inputs (due to the greediness of the the `.+`, we can't get more than `n-1` matches for `n` different digits).

To invert the truthiness of the result, we count the number of `0`s, which is `1` for valid inputs and `0` for invalid ones.

Comment: I made a shorter one, but it's close enough to yours that it should be a comment instead. Use AntiGrep instead of Match, then remove the last line: [```A`(.)(?!\1).+\1```](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=QWAoLikoPyFcMSkuK1wx&input=Mwo1MQo0NDk5OTkxMQoxMjM0NTY3ODkKMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyCjgxOAo4ODg0NDQzMzM0CjQ1NDUKNTU0NTUzCjEyMzQ1Njc4OTE) for 15 bytes. Also works for multiple inputs. Truthy is the input, falsy is nothing. One does not simply out-golf Martin at his own language. :)

Comment: @mbomb007 I think I actually considered that, but unfortunately, the challenge asks for a *consistent* truthy (and falsy) value, so printing the input as truthy isn't allowed.

Answer (score 5):

## J, 8 bytes

```
-:]/:i.~
```

Test it with [J.js](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=(%20-%3A%5D%2F%3Ai.~%20)%204%204%209%209%209%209%201%201).

#### How it works

```
-:]/:i.~  Monadic verb. Argument: y (list of digits)

     i.~  Find the index in y of each d in y.
  ]/:     Sort y by the indices.
-:        Match; compare the reordering with the original y.
```

Comment: `:]` `:i` `:-1`

Comment: Not sure if joke or golfing suggestion...

Answer (score 5):

## Regex (Perl / PCRE / Java / Boost / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup> / Ruby), 17 bytes

```
^(?!(.)+\1*+.+\1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1NT8JAEIbv8ytGuqFdQcrSXS1dSkOCHj1xJG4qKUmTteAWDqapf71OMagH5zCfz/vOsXBWdW8fyJzGxh52uUUWahrTxXq1WS1b2B9cwMp0qhdLTVXwBss9bXhzdGV1wsG2GugWmcUU6/NrfSLcjO/EWPDivT9i9mc/pQvHBJnRgGSEAQmHwx/CEiF4Vfief30Q9Ej6iSFzYckzf@PORYLoJ/5Tbmtqfa5bMvummdXYGvP4vDamewmym2DCR1txO5pQ5l3nYa/HXV4XNUAESoCUcwohQMwiqe4f4jnM/gsADy8vr@pYxBDHsZQyiiIJUkkFipKKfq3EFw) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBRS8MwEMff8yluWbGJ1m2xqdbF0henCKJSfbMaaslsIdtK0j2Jn31eJyKIBzkul//97i5d0@0u8q7pIHCQAZ1SmEDnzLt2prNVbVg4nRzmWjeV7XW9WXWtNa5kJVdlMfVhBCGeJSb1uxkE696se8@0vrq5XWjNIxAckXS6bakiy41jQZvNVGCzJRZ49vh0eXPHFf@AdskC@@x7Z80aI34sXrKMlmvKUey3b/iC6WgWHQuu9uqWm7rZDBIFSBWKAOaB/TIODhA5exll4TjEFsEq2@@2qvq6YYGLUKJggHzvbCvfa@McTslH2UOxuNZ393pRFPdFThdDfg50zoJVTp/c1swBb/Sqsh5DiqRPHGBPo4Gl6vPPrzGudq8sH7EJPyrF4dEEPd/txjCwoK688YTEJBFEynM0IYg4iWVyepaek5P/jJAx7Nv/VKciJWmaSinjOJZEJjIhCbok/kWJLw) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJbb9owFIDf/SsOQSo2dC4pYaONsqqbqIS0omlUe1m3ySQOmDoOi53ChPjt7ATCtm74wfG5feeWhXgWrxbJ005ly7xwsECZq5y3Q/hbUzqlT@oKOZPryrIsp1rFEGthLdwLZWBTq6wTDj/PuUogQwOduEKZGYhiZr98ZeDmRb6yMFzHculUjoEE4E5pCWlk5Gr/pB6P80RytHssfFemqSxk8kmKRBYw3bu9VNJjZC2mjIV1XnvuwtW84lNqoym2IJIPykjKWCMypdZMpdRy@aMU2lLvot1ue4xtXroeCJS6k4ANEtxvAgIukDBFv6fQdqLWo2lVXxduD7rtR@GcLAwUUf3CbrNllcCeHzXvbyfD76PxZDiejB5Gn4csxDFNYmEMjkCZZekggqrrWkcnP62TGVeG4d6MAxV1Q6gb3/vzubBjuXZYN2wAS1aNqMvqsBztS5yX04ZWgMiv8mHGwxA1JjtADBLqmSADqOZampmbU/a2C2dnoHk8F8Wto12cTqvZYvv9VudeuHiOxWfIKnh2kKhGzr81pDTjqTIJZXAD3kNRymsAD67Bu8MJo4A/xfa/qAq13W5JtcHdN3rToJx1Hv12h@PNdtVadk2oaBALKy0hPdL3SRBc4fF94l/2gv7rN4MrcnnqENKEffpj9MAfkMFgEARBr9cLSNAP@qSPV7/3B@X/Ag) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBbtswDL3rK1gHaKTEyarY7lw7aYEe9gFDDy3SzHAVxTbm2IIkI2uK/PoySU7WdhgPhEg@8pFPTIhJwdhxUDWs7tYc5i9tq/QXyQv@a1oKcYtYmUvIxHIFC/ju3e92P1@C7un19fGhvN6V@PgD313gKRk/09F4ajw5kn9Bng8jscjEmKbonakyRJLn21tUNRqEND7jUrYSs7ZRGhzxaMuVygtO3pReJwkzAJjP4ZS1T5fnzbpOQXLdyQZoenAjt3nVYAJvCIyJpWGreYMFmdDV4iqFzmCCWaahtZFtKMzDgd1Mg6@awhREp1Pod3LqJImTx9Bh4X9KJUnFcsVJes6qba5ZCbsy1/3kTSsBW669JXU8Bdd11XDcH1g1fk9phuwX9Ly@tWoDeE/A1Kw0ePjcDEn6qeoal1cruLyE8/tiMRwMyV@Y08JqvcEfN88UzyUr@wm@W9g3BxK4A@9BdjwB8CAB71teKxN4H4g3O1lp3ndOWWZkw@R0w1RVe24j6ttbW3uV6zs4f/ovI/rhOABLA1Y@hVCAIorC8MYYpYjOgjC6/hrfoNn/DKEBuL3O3TGNURzHYRgGQRCiMAojFBkXBe@j6G@2qfNCHSe10yFzMvwB) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BbsIwDEDv/gqTHtoOVjUk2UKmaLd9wW4FpIqGUSlLq6STBj/fJUyICz7YsuX37PE8nQbH5v57HPyE4RxW3nyZX/Co0RNC5n3xviiqcrmlT8sq5nKO04aqZ7p7w4uu4Th4tNi7BFdh6nqnALE/4kXh6Hs3FeV/b40rbImt69A2Edc637pcodW2qZPvwVq9W@g8y28m4zpNPv2PUYgkLV@frYJp/eFU@BVG0NhgkHy0sSgk6fadtWX6mc4ZJgke2mACAANBgfNNDEqBrhkXL69yA@tHAZDhVX6jJZUgpeScM8Y4cMEFiJgEu6voHw) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU1LT4NAGLzvrxiWpA@bblhYdFuyIU2qRw@mtxYJ6lpJVkIWSO3Fv44LtfHiHCaZbx6f7V7OvYXCkz7qr5pV@oTtZrdhVhdvCUoVJDh9lEbDqKNuGwKU7yi94V53bZNAV2OOJ4Nh9kueKUUPFU1cw@wDxpZhNqYuVc8w/Vm35xSTiYsHmaem/tR5QG3LqoWB@oZFCrqznV4DFGvQh8I0TtDr0m/2IvP8/nGb5/3zLPVmbL448JsFczzvex/DCl6LRjeERCTmRIiVA@eEh5GIb@/kioT/gRAf49trW3JJpJRCiCiKBBGxiEnsKI7@pvgP) - Ruby

```
^             # Anchor to start of string
(?!           # Assert that the following can't match:
    (.)+      # Skip any number of characters (minimum zero), then capture
              # the next character in \1
    \1*+      # Skip all subsequent occurrences of \1, and lock in that match
              # using a possessive quantifier.
    .+        # Skip at least one character, or as many as necessary to make the
              # following match:
    \1        # Match the character captured in \1
)
```

### Regex (Perl / PCRE / Java / Boost / Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup> / Ruby), 11 bytes

```
(.)\1*+.+\1
```

Returns a match for false, and a non-match for true.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY09b8IwEIb3@xUnYuG4UIKx3ZqYgJBox06MkawUBSmSG6gDQxWlfz01RbQdesN9Pu97x9I71b99IPEGW3fYFQ5JYsKYLTbr7XrZwf7gY1JlU7NYmlA5a7Hahw1rj76qTzjI64HpkDjMsDm/NqeA2/E9H3NWvl@OuPqzn4YLwxSJNYDBCOMgHA5/CBcIzuqSRvT2IL4g2ScmxCcVW9HnwjVlijSlW38ODVJmumB2pYkz2Fn79LKxto8nLOd3o8ko530f4YXHXdGUDYAAxUHKeQjOgc@EVA@Peg6z/wIgwu@3N7XmGrTWUkohhASppAIVkhK/VvwL) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBRS8MwEMff8ynOrNjE1W2xqVZj2YtTBHFS92Yl1JKthWwrSfck@@zzOhFBPEi4/PO/X@7S1u3hdtrWLQQOMqBjCiNonVlpZ1pbVoaF49HZVOu6tJ2utuu2scYVrOCqyMc@jCDEtURRr0xv2HRm03mm9f3j00xrHoHgiKTjXUMVWW4dC5psogKbLbHAs9fF3eMzV/wTmiUL7JvvnDUbzPi5eM8yWmwoR7PffeANytEkOhdcHd0NN1W97S0KkCoUAdSB/TJOTxE5eT/JwkGITwTr7DjbuuyqmgUuQouCHvI9sy19p41z2CU/yV7y2YN@nutZns/zKZ31@g3QGxasp/S@tN70J7pwO0yAImmPDRxpNLBU7f/8GuPqwEa8EGfD0bAQh8MA@lqoSm88ITFJBJHyGkMIIi5imVxepdfk4r8gZADHFn6qU5GSNE2llHEcSyITmZAEtyT@RYkv) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJbb9owFIDf/StOQSo2dC5pwpYuyqZuohLSiqZR7WVMk0kccOs4NHYKE@K3sxMI27phKbF9Lt@5@UE8i1cP6eNO5cuidPCAd64K3o3gb0nllD4pK@VcrmvNsppplUCihbVwJ5SBTSOyTjjcnguVQo4KOnGlMnMQ5dx@@87ALcpiZWG4TuTSqQIdCcCt0hKy2MjV/khbPClSyVHfYtGHKstkKdMvUqSyhNne7KWQHj2ba8ZY1MS1Fy5aLWo@pTaeYQki/aSMpIydxabSmqmMWi6fKqEtbV12u90WY5uXpgcCpe4kYIME95uAgEskzNDuMbK9uDM1nXp30fYg234WzsnSQBk3J6w2X9YB7MVR8vFmMvwxGk@G48nofvR1yCJs0yQRxmALlFlWDmKoq25kdPLTOplzZRjOzThQcT@CpvC9PV8IO5Zrh3nDBjBldRb3WeNWoH6J/XLa0BoQe3U8jHhoosZgB4hBQtMTZADVXEszdwvK3vXh/Bw0TxaivHG0j93ptDtsP9963QmXLDD5HFklzw83qpHzbw4ZzXmmTEoZvIfWLXZVvoUW4HdfVngEfBTb/7xq1Ha7JfUEd5Szqdft8d7U29UD2bWh9oVEWGkJ8cnAI0FwjcvziHflB4PXb8JrcnVqEdKGfRJH79ALSRiGQRD4vh@QYBAMyAB/A/8PyvsF) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFtb9owEP7uX3EDqdgQWE2SLk2gk/ZhP2Dqh02AotSYJFpwLNsRKxV/fcx2YG2nnZTT@V6e5@4Jk3JaMnYe1oI13ZbD4qlttfmoeMl/zSopHxCrCgW5XG1gCd8GXw6Hn09h9@P5@ftjdXeo8BnPyJqOJ7PJmp7Jv@VBAGO5zOWEZuiVo7YUihf7B1QLA1JZn3OlWoVZK7QBTznec62LkpMXbbZpymwDLBZwybrQ57nYNhkobjolgGYnD7kvaoEJvCCwJleWreECSzKlm@VtBp3tCee5gda93EBpA9/sMW1/LUpbkJ3JoN/J65KmXhhLh2XwLpWmNSs0J9k1q/eFYRUcqsL0yLtWAXZcR0fqeUpumlpw3B9Yi6CntCDHJb2u76zeAT4SsDUnDR6txYhk76p@cHW7gZsbuMYflqPhiPxt81o4rXf47ea55oViVY8Q@IUDeyCBzzD4WjSapzAA@z2qzoYweEO8O6ja8H5yxnIrGyaXG2a6PnL3ooG7tXVX@bmT95f/ZUU/nYfgoMHJpxEKUUxRFN1boxTReRjFd5@SezT/nyE0BL/jdTqhCUqSJIqiMAwjFMVRjGLr4vAViv5mu6Yo9XnaeB1yL8Mf) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BboMwEETv@xVbcwCaFLGx3TpUvvYLeiM5oOA0SK5BNpWa/Dy1U0W5ZA8rrWbe7Ezn@TQ6vgzf0@hnDOew9ubL/IJHjZ4xthRVuaPnVbXa0RLvlpoX2r/jRddwHD1aHFzCqjD3g2sAcTjipcHJD24uyv/bGlfYEjvXo20jrnW@c3mDVtu2TnkPbPX@SedZfksyrtfso7PBNMiS@VqzCqbzh1Ph1xhBE1Vkn/4nepCl33fWlqkzLRkmHQ9dMAGAgyQQYhuHCGjDhXx9U1vYPBqADK8NbrQiBUopIQTnXICQQoKMS/J7FP0B) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU1NS8NAEL3vr3hJoFVLl2x2V7eGpRSqRw/SWxNC1LUG1hA2CbUX/3rcpBYvPphhZt7HuP7lNDhoPJuD@WpobY7YbnYb6kz5lqLScYrjR2UNrD6YriVA9Y4qGO9N37UpTD3pWDoSdr9kudZhVoepd9h9TOkyySfV2RpYaj6b7rTGbOblcR7oeTT3HNC4qu5gob/hsEb4WNrW3COEr53r/YjwkvSrPa9F8fC0LYrhil5n7GZBFxkbhgijB69la1pCOJGMCLHyYIywhAt5e6dWJPkPhESYnl/ciimilBJCcM4FEVJIIn2T/C@K/QA) - Ruby

This beats the regex in the previous [Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77657/17216), [Perl answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77684/17216), and [Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77634/17216) by 2 bytes.

```
(.)   # \1 = a character anywhere in the string
\1*+  # Skip all subsequent occurrences of \1, and lock in that match using a
      # possessive quantifier.
.+    # Skip at least one character, or as many as necessary to make the
      # following match:
\1    # Match the character captured in \1
```

### Regex (ECMAScript <sub><sup>(or better)</sup></sub> / Python / .NET), 13 bytes

```
(.)(?!\1).+\1
```

Returns a match for false, and a non-match for true.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU3LbsIwELz7KxxFwrsUAiY2NUQup/YD2t5KD1Ew1K1JItv0QdVvTwMS6qVzGO1odmZey/cyVN62cRxauzF@39Rv5qvzujYf9N7sbj9bgKO@mQw7yBBWyZpjdrXm3XByxCw2D9HbegeYBWcrA/PRWOCIMsuw2DYerJ4W4LQ35cbZ2gBiouuDc4XVHL8JpXYLFtu@IwIWvXZ0MKDuafqcaJayk2gPMUQPLtuXsXoBjyt2V7pglpQt2aM/9Adl5@zlE4ufLqUni1ZlMIGQnEhOhFj04JzwWS7k/FotyOw/EJLS88IlrbgiSikhRJ7ngggpJJE9yfyviv8C) - ECMAScript**
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3PT8IwFMfv7694soauERmlrZaVQUjQoyeOS5pJRrKkDuzgYJb5r89Og3rwHd7Pz/f7TqV3qn99R@INtu64LxySxIQxW243u82qg8PRx6TKZma5MqFy1mJ1CBvWnnxVn3GU1yPTIXGYYXN5ac4Bt5M7PuGsfBuOuP6zn4ULwxSJNYDBCOMgHI9/CBcIzuqSRvT6IB6Q7AMT4pOKrelT4ZoyRZrSnb@EBikzXTD7pokz2Fn7@Ly1to@nLF7f5JxNb3Pe9xEOCtwXTdkACFAcpFyE4Bz4XEh1/6AXMP8vACL8enxVa65Bay2lFEJIkEoqUCEp8WvFPwE) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBRS8MwEMff8yluWbGJ1m2xqVZj6YtTBHFS92Yl1JLZQraVpHsSP/u8TkQQDxIu//zvl7t0Tbe/zrumg8BBBnRKYQKdM@/amc5WtWHhdHKca91Uttf1dt211riSlVyVxdSHEYS4VijqdzMYNr3Z9J5pfXv/MNeaRyA4Iul011JFVlvHgjabqcBmKyzw7Hl5c//IFf@AdsUC@@J7Z80GM34qXrOMlhvK0ex3b3iDcjSLTgVXB3fLTd1sB4sCpApFAHVgv4yjI0TOXkdZOA7xiWCdHWZbV33dsMBFaFEwQL5ntpXvtXEOu@Sj7KmY3@nHhZ4XxaLI6XzQr4BesWCd09vKejOc6NLtMAGKpE9s4ECjgaXq88@vMa72bMJZPioFn5yUYr8fw1ANdeWNJyQmiSBSXmIIQcRZLJPzi/SSnP0XhIzh0MRPdSpSkqaplDKOY0lkIhOS4JbEvyjxBQ) - PCRE
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJbb9owFIDf/StOQSo27VxSwpYuyqpuohLSiqal2suYJpM4YOo4LHYKE@K3sxMI27phKbF9Lt@5eSGexatF@rRT@bIoHSzwzlXBuyH8Lamc0idlpZzJda1ZVlOtEki0sBYehDKwaUTWCYfbc6FSyFFBY1cqMwNRzuzXbwzcvCxWFobrRC6dKtCRANwrLSGLjFztj7TFkyKVHPUtFr6vskyWMv0sRSpLmO7NXgrp0bO5ZoyFTVx76cLVvOZTaqMpliDSj8pIythZZCqtmcqo5fJHJbSlratut9tibPPS9ECg1J0EbJDgfhMQcIWEKdo9hfYi6kxMp95duD3Itp@Ec7I0UEbNCavNl3UAe3mUfLiLh99H43g4jkePoy9DFmKb4kQYgy1QZlk5iKCuupHR@Kd1MufKMJybcaCiXghN4Xt7Phd2LNcO84YNYMrqLOqxxq1A/RL75bShNSDy6ngY8dBEjcEOEIOEpifIAKq5lmbm5pS968H5OWiezEV552gPu9Npd9h@vvV6EC6ZY/I5skqeH25UI@ffHDKa80yZlDK4hdY9dlW@hRbg91hWeAR8FNv/vGrUdrsl9QR3lDN6ezbxGL@YeLt6JLs21N6QCCstIX0y8Ijv3@DyPOJd9/3B6zfBDbk@tQhpwz6No3fgBSQIAt/3@/2@T/yBPyAD/A36f1DeLw) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVFtb9owEP7uX3EFqdhtYDVJujSBVtqH/YCpH1YBilJjEmvBsexErFT89THbgb5MOymn8708z90TptS4ZOw4FJLV3ZrD7LlpTPtF85L/nlRK3SNWFRpytVjBHH4Mvu12v57D7unl5edjdbur8BFPCH64WFIyuV7SI/m3YRDAlZrn6ppm6J1FWBLNi@09ErIFpa3PudaNxqyRpgVPerXlxhQlJ6@mXacpsw0wm8Ep60Kf53JdZ6B522kJNDt4yG0hJCbwisCaWli2mkusyJiu5jcZdLYnnOYtNO7lBkob@GaPafuFLG1BdW0G/U5emTT10lg6rIJPqTQVrDCcZOes2RYtq2BXFW2PvGk0YMe1d6Sep@RtLSTH/YFCBj2lBdnP6Xl9Z2IDeE/A1pw0eLSUI5J9qvrBxc0KLi/hHF/MR8MReWvzWjitN/jj5rnhhWZVjxD4hQN7IIEHGHwvasNTGID9HnVnQxh8IN7stGh5PzlhuZUNk9MNEyP23L1o4G5t3FV@7uD96X9Z0Q/HIThocPIZhEIUUxRFd9YoRXQaRvHt1@QOTf9nCA3B73ieTmiCkiSJoigMwwhFcRSj2Lo4fIeif9imLkpzHNdeh9zL8Bc) - Boost
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BboMwDIbvfgo3HACtQ7hJupQp2m1PsBv0gEqqImUBJezQvjxLNlW91AdLtv/v/z1fl8vk@Dp@z5NfMFzD1hvwqNEzxtaiKouPTUdl9dLRGjctNa90fMebruE8ebQ4ukRVYRlG1wDieMZbg7Mf3VKU/7M1rrAl9m5A20Zc67xzeYNW27ZOfk9k9XGj8yy/Oxk3aPbZ22AaZEnsTRVM70@Xwm8xUiaekH35nyhAloIfoC3Tw7RmmO546oMJABwkgRCHWERAOy7k/k0dYPesADL8i7/TihQopYQQnHMBQgoJMjbJH1b0Cw) - Python**
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BbsIwDIbvfgqTHtpqrMIk2UKnaLc9wW4th4qGUSlLq6STBi/fJUyICz5Ysv1/v//pPJ9Gx5fhexr9jOEc1t58mV/wqNEzxpaiKov3VUtl9dTSEjcN1c@0f8OL3sBx9GhxcAmswtwPrgbE4YiXGic/uLko/2drXGFL7FyPtom41nnr8hqtts0m@T2QbfYrnWf5zcm4XrOPzgZTI0via9AqmM4fToVfYwRNvCL79D9Rgyz9vrO2TJlpyTDd8dAFEwA4SAIhdrGIgLZcyJdXtYPtowLI8JrgRitSoJQSQnDOBQgpJMjYJL9b0R8) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU1NS8NAEL3vr3hJoB9Il2x3V7eGJRSqRw/SWxNC1LUG1hA2CbUX/3rcpBYvPphhZt7HuP7lPDhoPJuj@WpobU7Ybfdb6kz5lqDScYLTR2UNrD6ariVA9Y4qGO9N37UJTD3pWDIS9rBiudZhVoeJd9hDTOlqnU@qizWw1Hw23TnFbOblcR7oeTT3HNC4qu5gob/hkCJ8LG1r7hHC1971fkR4TfrVXtaieHjaFcWwoMtFGmRsSW8yNgwRRhdey9a0hHAiGRFi48EYYWsu5O2d2pD1fyAkwvT@6lZMEaWUEIJzLoiQQhLpm@R/UewH) - Ruby
**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5NT4QwEIbv/RUVmrRVIXZptQvZuImJN2/eXA@EHaSxAmnZYJbw27G7idHDzmE@Ms/7zvTdCM43YO1C3ObNwQd8v@d5CyPb0oWlnD1e7QRPb3Ziodvb6Kn76o2FfcQLctzcFXXnoKwaRiw2LSam7Q8Dn0zNyJFPozMDJE3nhznAojA1DmBStvuk7YZTa80n0Pia8v8wDtvwgDUt4Iiws8qlL@VQNeCDinM80efSesjpjCHUML@6A@SYzhxHc3HZi9h5ifEJxFXpwSOUISWQlOsQQiCxyqS6f9BrtLoUCMX4fPVXrYVGWmspZZZlEkklFVIhqezPSvwA) - .NET**

### \$\large\textit{Anonymous functions}\$

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 21 bytes

```
->s{/(.)\1*+.+\1/!~s}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxRT4MwFIXf76@4FLOpCx2lrXYjdW/@gr0BMdssSlIJoRAzjP51LOjii@fhJueec762P57HUo/Rg/tYX9ObnN2u6Cpn6@DLfY6DjlN8f62sQatfTOcAsSpxCKZ/03cuRVM/pzholk6BzSJWaE3ymqR@YbOY0igpfltXT7qu7A8isNS8Nd15h4uFn8VFoJfh0meITVvVHZaZLXCHZN/2ZotIcIvk8WCdN2TmwaVpZzuGOFXxdHDGAXCQDITYeDEGLOFC3t2rDST/CSDEmX1ZK6ZAKSWE4JwLEFJIkP5I/odi3w)

## JavaScript (ES6), 27 bytes

```
s=>!/(.)(?!\1).+\1/.test(s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY2xTsMwFEV3f4WbSI0twK1rB9xEbjckdjbCECWOFGQ5wc@Boeq3B6cSgqG9w9Mdzrnvo/6qofH9GB7c0Jq50zPow2pDGCXHVcUpu6v4hgUDgQCdS9Db0pvPqfeGZN7Ure2dyShrYg/mxQXju7ox5NS7cQrF6IfGADAIbe/OlA2OZBfj3urDCWEMeL3G/6hhCuzb9yGuVy6jJQbNy8jZhbNv2/eVztLsptQRS4/Jq59MgXFSJM@1hVgTumxcNSwtz3RO8eLgpgYDCAmUcyTlPoZzxHdC5o9Pao9214JQii9vfm3FFVJKSSmFEBLJXOYojycXf1P8Bw)

Included for completeness; already done in [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77622/17216).

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 29 bytes

```
!($args-match'(.)(?!\1).+\1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BbsMgEEX3c4qJjQqochQCtCRR1F1P0F2ThWXh2hK1U3BkKZbP7mJLUTbtLJgB/ntzaXvrQ2Wdm0h5HKYVI7n/Ctl33hUVZWvO3lYnwdfPJ0H5NB7I7bg5lK23eVEx4rBukNTN5drxARDrkpEbH3pfdzar2tCNMS@WD4zpzP5gkmDWeiTuc3Ne7mnCcWZHtC7YZUR8GDBr2sb2rm4sJoTNoidSRj5S9MNf7R6R3ln6nse@jw88mZXwn4k4GKcUZx6LPNgAIEELUGoXSwgQW6n0y6vZwfavAkhx2XWnjTBgjFFKSSkVKK006Hho@VCJXw)

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/) v0.7+, 30 bytes

```
s->!occursin(r"(.)\1*+.+\1",s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bU5LTsMwEN3PKaaJ1NqUVri2wW2UsuME7CiLkNrFyHLATja9ChKqkHoN7tHb4DSq2DCLNxq933we3zpnq8O3KY9da2bqJ87Wo6auuxCtJyEjc7phV9P5dMOy60gH0elrX5rKRV2gaQI6tB6DrrbOeh0JBcSda14qh_vCmgTvwfrWeUIL7bcF7ss2dDqpEum037WvxNH1DY7H6J7Y86ic5JPEIp59xCQW7zF7TKYVYoYrzB769rT7rpQJF62jkM7hy8PpI8fehHUVdQTgIBkIsUzDGLAFF_L2Ti1h8d8A5HhuubgVU6CUEkJwzgUIKSTIBJL_RbGh-Rc) / [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU3LTsMwELzvV2wTqbUpVLi2qdso5cYXcGs5mNQpRisH2cklPx@cShUX5jCr1by@B/J2N7X1lJ6Oi65phph8YLFgG34WD@vN@iyKx8SnsW4tJVdh20Uk9AGjsxfywSXGAfFK3aclHCvfZvqJPvQUGK9cuFQ41n0cXHZlkVy49l@M@PEZl0ukk/hY1KtylVXEW461WcVXLN5z6IBY4AGLt3k933krd8LdSxzyO5U4m7GxySUACVqAUvsMIUBspdIvO7OH7X8AKPHWfk8bYcAYo5SSUipQWmnQmbT8qxK/)

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/) v1.3+, 28 bytes

```
s->count(r"(.)\1*+.+\1",s)<1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVDNTsMwDL77KUwrbQljE1kSyFY6bjzBboxD2ZJRZKXQtJe-ChKakPYWvMjehnRj4oIPtqzvz_LH_rWlsth9uXzfNm5svsN4sa5a37A6YRO-EpejyWglkqvA78SJcvjscldQsBm6qkbC0mNtiw2V3gbGAXFL1XNB2GWli-2tLn1DnvHM-k2GXd7UrY2sCJL12-aFEV9c42CA9CieLvJhOowo4lHHXETxHpNlFM0RE5xj8tCnx9lnRU84c4lDXE9X7g7vKfYiXBfBBgAJWoBSs1hCgJhKpW9uzQym_xVAiseUs9oIA8YYpZSUUoHSSoOOTcs_q9___AA)

*-2 bytes compared to v0.7+, thanks to MarcMush*

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 32 bytes

```
\(s)!grepl('(.)\\1*+.+\\1',s,,1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY6xTgMxDIZ3P4XbSk1Mj4r0cpD2dCtTRySWW442KZFOaYmvSxFPwlKQeAXepW9DjoJY8GDL1vf_v1_f4vHdVR_7zl2aE9aSabCJdtdKIadU1-piMp2kITLOMkU_3CdXVyUeKudbK4fcrX0YUgluG-USfUDe73bRMt83MfiwYRlts176YFkeiOgZEL1LUaumk6IOgkquVHm-htVjk2wIx-Pk88BdWjKVsgeVGAnCXuOdbdlKl7BM3MW9XSCKTNw26bpAQdR79eCSyhdYtdsEH6g8f388PY2wFyWCLQPkUCjQep5KKVCzXBfXN2YOs_8KYITfOb9qowwYY7TWeZ5r0IUuoEityP-s1Dn5Cw)

Beaten by [Alex A.'s non-regex answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77633/17216) [by 2 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY_BSgMxEIbv8xRpV5oMrGC6WU277FUQeix46WXdTTSwpDXZFaz4JF6q4GsIPkbfxtku4sU5BDL5v28mb-_h8GHLz76z5_prIyJOKv8smn7XurrqTCNCa6h79oQ4ho7fsbwo2L60jl6msWucn2IBdhvEijnPYr_bBRPjbRW88_dRBFM1K-dNFHtEfAHGnCUl6QXfeI5FLGUxdn39UJEG2WxGnrvY0SWVqcRJyROObGCcNW00wgpaR6-3N74jAFO-Dr1ZMsZTfl1RYMk44qAdmBUWr1C3W-L2WIwfORwfEzZAlIgmAmSQS1BqQSUlyHmm8ssrvYD5fwWQsNOcX1pLDVprpVSWZQpUrnLI6cizP5UcJ_8A), or [by 6 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY_BSgMxEIbv8xSxK00GVjDdrKZd9yoIPRa89JK2iQaWbM1sPVR8Ei9V8CW8-Rh9G7NdxIsDCUzyf98kb-_x8OHqz13nLvTXUhCaphGdWTVWxLQIz5_xZoJD4PhN9WXF9rXz6W5E3caHEVbg2ijmzAdGu-02WqJ7E4MPDySiNZu5D5bEHhFfgDHvknRtOsGXgWNFtayG07B-NEmDbDxOnhV1qcllLvGs5hlH1jPe2YascCI9Ry_au9AlAHO-iDs7Y4zn_NakwIxxxF7bM3OsXmHdtInbYzV85HB8ylgPpQRZAiiglKDUNJWUICeFKq-u9RQm_xVAxk5zfmktNWitlVJFUShQpSqhTFtZ_KnkMPkH) with pajonk's improvement.

## Java, 33 bytes

```
s->!s.matches("(.)+\\1*+.+\\1.*")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BT@MwEIXv/hWvqQR2AashzhIIKWIPnBYu5QZ78AancXGdKHaAatXf3nVT0ErAHDwaz7zvvaV8kSfLp@etXrVN57EMM@@9Nrzqbel1Y/kkx5flJCelkc7hVmqLvwRo@z9Gl3Be@tBeGv2EVdjRue@0XTz8huwWjg2nwM07@3K/Pf7ZNEZJO0OFYutOZiPHV9KXtXI0opwdPT7GkyO@a3wSsW0eIPNSWqs6aNv2HgWsev34o/O182rFtWUhuvXQxTTHa62NAh3ueS3dnXrzlIVE0BXVo2LK3mVN2LchljeW7gBFnA@h91lhgtkeYgPhl7ZquKpADTfKLnxN2WyKgwMYXtayu/Z0ykbF4fiQDZgA@uRDKy7b1qypYbhCdN/16gKIcIHoRhoXhig4fFEZlpPNZrMdY6dAKZ1yhCQkjYkQ56HimMSniUh/nGXn5PS7ImSMweJDncUZybJMCJEkiSAiFSlJw5Mm/1HxPw)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 39 bytes

```
fn($s)=>!preg_match('/(.)\1*+.+\1/',$s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9Pb4IwGIfv/RS1Emkn/qkUBbvOy9yyiy7M2zQESRGyqqTF0@JnZ8Vl8bL38Kb59enzvq2KqnlcVEUFnVw0@Qk7hoinTqXlITmmdVZgd4SHZEsf@sP@lo5czwINL09lYmSNUZVpOdyn2VetbUtUeSxr5EHEJhGLprNJFCDCQX7W2CnFmDtK5AdZG/yxeX5bEU6@YZljR32aWitppysyoDsh0PaEiIXNZW9vbOyNvQEl/EaXRGbFuUU4tFbKAbQ5xHdHr2eV411HuF3XjmhxePuSSk2dSK3tPqQj3uPla7JaJ8s4XscLtGzzOURz7LQ7kQXa6IucQ5ugl1QZe7Sfuf7qkKMQvzZd2DIwS400APggoICxyBalgE58FkxnYQQm/xUAXXjT/r0OaQjCMGSM@b7PAAtYAALbAv@uoj8)

### \$\large\textit{Full programs}\$

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 17 bytes <sub><sup>(18 bytes including flag)</sup></sub>

```
$_=!/(.)\1*+.+\1/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzBTsMwEETv/orFsdKEtmlc2@DWCtz4Ao6RIlMcGil1rNg50Kq/TjCVEBfmMLurnXnOjL2YJ29AFCUtFZw@SVv56e1CmsoNTs1x3m2yIq/p/bJY1nQzK9JcFfiggwFyVuScpm7sbMC1xfGqqILDcTg5FVm6Io3q2qw39iMciYY0hUj3YcyIXpUrmluzSBb55UbISLt@io/8Gb@Ok9kD4D1@0b2PK86vtwwQrWCy76YF0swJ/AThoL3xCDEkKOJ8F0UpolvGxcOj3KHtf0IogRv7ty2pRFJKzjljjCMuuEAimmB/KPo1uNAN1s9r9w0)

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 17 bytes

```
M`(.)(?!\1).+\1
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcshDoAwEERRP7dAkJSQNCw7C1uFRHEDBAgEBkG4f6nD8MR3/z6e89pzHeYtL1uITZiqVZrYroIuZ4UJyFSIQHqlDaMn9H/g4nB3kqpK0GiwEtNvlRc)

Included for completeness; already done in [Martin Ender's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77661/17216).

## [Retina 1.0](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 17 bytes

```
C`(.)(?!\1).+\1
0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8N85QUNPU8NeMcZQU087xpDL4P9/Yy5TQy4TE0sgMDTkMjQyNjE1M7ew5DLCBrgsDC24LCwsTExMjI2NTbhMTE1MuUyBhKkxQqshAA)

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <sub><sup><s>19</s></sup></sub> 18 bytes

```
`(.)(?!\1).+\1`NIa
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/QUNPU8NeMcZQU087xjDBzzPx////JiaWQGBoCAA)

Thanks to DLosc.

Comment: [Alex A.'s answer does work correctly but takes vector of digits/characters as input](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY-xTsMwEIb3ewo3RbVPChJuHHAbZWXqiMTSJW0csBS5xZcgUcSTsBQkXoOVZ-jbcCFCLNxgyef_--78-haP70350XfNuf1cK8JJFZ5U3e9bv606V6vYOu6ePSKOodMXlReFOJSN55eEutqHBAtodlGthA-C-v0-OqLbKgYf7khFV9UrHxypAyI-gxC-YSXrlVwHiQWVuhi7YXtfsQbFbMaeDXV8SXWqcVLKqUQxML5xLTnVKNcqDhBv2nEqSVieypvYu6UQMpXXFceWQiIO8oFcYfEC23bH9AGL8TvH08NUDBAnyBFABrkGYxZcWoOeZya_vLILmP9XAFPxM-eXttqCtdYYk2WZAZObHHI-8uxPpcfJ3w), but can be [26](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77608/all-together-now/77633#comment559725_77633)

Comment: @pajonk Thanks, edited. It also works with `utf8ToInt()` instead of `el(strsplit(,""))`.

Comment: 13 bytes in Python `re` flavor with match = falsey / no match = truthy: `(.)(?!\1).+\1` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/QUNPU8NeMcZQU087xjBBwc9TIfH///8mJpZAYGgIAA "Pip – Try It Online"))

Comment: (Note: the Pip program can be 18 bytes because the space isn't necessary.)

Comment: Julia, 28 bytes: [`s->count(r"(.)\1*+.+\1",s)<1`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVDNTsMwDL77KUwrbQljE1kSyFY6bjzBboxD2ZJRZKXQtJe-ChKakPYWvMjehnRj4oIPtqzvz_LH_rWlsth9uXzfNm5svsN4sa5a37A6YRO-EpejyWglkqvA78SJcvjscldQsBm6qkbC0mNtiw2V3gbGAXFL1XNB2GWli-2tLn1DnvHM-k2GXd7UrY2sCJL12-aFEV9c42CA9CieLvJhOowo4lHHXETxHpNlFM0RE5xj8tCnx9lnRU84c4lDXE9X7g7vKfYiXBfBBgAJWoBSs1hCgJhKpW9uzQym_xVAiseUs9oIA8YYpZSUUoHSSoOOTcs_q9___AA)

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
{IeMrz8
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7BIeMrz8&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=3%0A51%0A44999911%0A123456789%0A222222222222222222222%0A818%0A8884443334%0A4545%0A554553%0A1234567891&debug=0).

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 23 bytes

Anonymous function. Accepts a string. Regex strat.

```
->n{/(.)(?!\1).*\1/!~n}
```

**Regex breakdown**

```
/(.)(?!\1).*\1/
 (.)            # Match a character and save it to group 1
    (?!\1)      # Negative lookahead, match if next character isn't
                #  the same character from group 1
          .*    # Any number of matches
            \1  # The same sequence as group 1
```

`!~` means if there are no matches of the regex within the string, return `true`, and otherwise return `false`.

Answer (score 4):

## MATL, <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
u"G@=fd2<vA
```

Thanks to *Luis Mendo* for saving two bytes!

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dSJHQD1mZDI8dkE&input=JzEyMzQ1Njc4OTEn)

**Explanation**

```
        % Grab the input implicitly
u       % Find the unique characters
"       % For each of the unique characters
    G   % Grab the input again
    @=  % Determine which chars equal the current char
    f   % Find the locations of these characters
    d   % Compute the difference between the locations
    2<  % Find all index differences < 2 (indicating consecutive chars)
    v   % Vertically concatenate all stack contents
    A   % Ensure that they are all true
        % Implicit end of the for loop
```

Comment: You can take the input with quotes (allowed by default) and remove `j`. Also, I think you can move `vA` within the loop and remove `]`

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks! I had messed around with putting `Y&` inside but that didn't work because `fd2<` can be empty. Moving `vA` inside works great though! Also I really wish we had a stable `unique` that didn't take up tons of bytes.

Comment: Now stable unique takes a little less, using a number instead of the predefined string. I may add a shorter version in the future, though. Or just make `u` stable by default (you could always include `S` afterwards, two bytes). What do you think?

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 26 bytes

```
0<##&@@Sort[#&@@@Split@#]&
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
f l=(==)=<<scanl1 min$(<$>l).(==)<$>l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYs7DsMgEET7PcUWFKZBWu@SYMnkLsiyZRQgUbCV4xM7TZq8YjQfzRrqfU6ptQWT77zXfhzrFEoizLGoblS3pM05nK7lEAt6jGWbX2HaUOFeUixzRYM5PLu6Pt5m0Uf6to3BEogMB0RAPYu9XN0A/T/AkQPnnIgws4BYsWAPsfy70gc)

Uses the same approach as [Luis Mendo's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77665/20260): creates a vector for each entry which indices equal it, and checks that the result is sorted in decreasing order.

`(<$>l).(==)<$>l` is shorter version of `[map(==a)l|a<-l]`. The function `(<$>l).(==)` that takes `a` to `map(==a)l` is mapped onto `l`.

`scanl1 min` takes the cumulative smallest elements of `l`, which equals the original only if `l` is reverse-sorted. `(==)=<<` checks if the list is indeed invariant under this operation.

A recursive strategy also gave **37 bytes**:

```hs
f(h:t)=t==[]||f t>(elem h t&&h/=t!!0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYtBCsIwEEX3c4opSEk31TQTTYV4EXERJCHFJIodcdO7x@LGjW/x4X140c03n1KtQcQjd5atPV@WJSCfhE8@Y0Ru27i13DS7rmY3FbQ4FfZPd2Xc4KukqfgZe8zuIeZ4f/ehW@37VgVaAtG4IiXIQZHeH8wIwz/ASAPGGCJSShGQJg16Ha1@qfwA)

This checks each suffix to see if its first element doesn't appear in the remainder, excusing cases where the first two elements are equal as part of a contiguous block.

Other approaches:

**42 bytes**

```hs
f l=and[all(/=a)t|a:b:t<-scanr(:)[]l,a/=b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYtBDoIwEEX3c4pZuIBEIaVTLcSehLAYECJxqIbWuPHulbhx41v85P3kXTncRpGUJhTH/tKySFY6zuObm76J50MY2K9Zk7ed7Ll0fZcWnj06nH0cVx4i7vDpZfZjwAIXfmThen8VU77Z900ajAKiekMpUJUmczzZGqp/gFUWrLVEpLUmIEMGzDZG/1L1AQ)

**43 bytes**

```hs
import Data.List
((==)<*>nub).map nub.group
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYu9DsIwEIP3e4obGFqGSGkukEoNEyMvEVBKI5ofNal4/BCxsPANlm3Zi8kvu661Op/iVvBqimE3lwvMuuu07qfjJez3nnmTsBn23OKeqjcuoEYXit3Mo@AB97C6YDMybMsuL/HN5r6lb1sFSA5EY4Nz4IMgeTqrEYZ/gOIKlFJEJIQgIEkSZBMpflf@AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
i@ÞƑ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxDcJAEATrQdpk//bs/cwBTVAAgS03QAXENEAzltzW8SIhYbKVZme77/ujal2O9/mq6/G83KoCppGEbUkRIUh9QEKpBFsop9kdOWYG2j9@GkF6/G1@K31uGR8)

Semi-based on several of [DLosc's 5-byters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251235/85334).

```
   Ƒ    The input is not changed by
  Þ     sorting its elements by
i@      their first indices in the input.
```

Kind of like cutting the `F` out of `` ¹ƙ`F⁼ ``, but also kind of like cutting the `` `ṢƑ `` out of `` iⱮ`ṢƑ. ``

Comment: @thejonymyster Should be clearer now

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
)ġf⁼
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#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)

Takes input as a list of singleton strings. Happens to be a different algorithm to the existing vyxal answer.

### Explained

```
)ġf⁼­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
)ġ    # ‎⁡Group by the identity function, by order of first appearance. 
  f   # ‎⁢Flatten the list
   ⁼  # ‎⁣Does that equal the input?
```

Comment: what is the diamond emoji for? 

Comment: It means it was created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire/)

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <strike>56</strike> 55 bytes

```
a=lambda s:~(s[0]in s.lstrip(s[0]))&a(s[1:])if s else 1
```

Comment: Fails in Python 3.4.1 (`int not subscriptable`)

Comment: Saved an extra byte with `~`(which literally is equivalent to`1-`): `a=lambda s:~(s[0]in s.lstrip(s[0]))&a(s[1:])if s else 1`

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 44 bytes

```
import Data.List 
((==)<*>nub).map head.group
```

Usage example: `((==)<*>nub).map head.group $ "44999911"` -> `True`.

A non-pointfree version:

```
f x = q == nub q                -- True if q equals q with duplicates removed
  where
  q = map head $ group x        -- group identical digits and take the first
                                -- e.g. "44999911" -> ["44","9999","11"] -> "491"
                                -- e.g  "3443311" -> ["3","44","33","11"] -> "3431"
```

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 119 bytes

```
bool m(String s){for(int i=0;i<9;i++){if(new Regex(i.ToString()+"+").Matches(s).Count>1){return false;}}return true;}
```

---

### Ungolfed

```
bool m(String s) {
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if(new Regex(i.ToString() + "+").Matches(s).Count > 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Instead of deleting a post and making a new post with the fixed version, you could also edit your old post and then undelete it. (No need to do that now that there's two posts already anyway, but just so you know in the future.)

Comment: My bad. When I first intended to participate in this Code Golf I misread the objective and didn't had much time to do another solution ( and knowing myself, I wouldn't try to correct the previous posted solution ). But then I was told I had some more time free and attempted to post the "correct solution". Didn't even thought in doing what you said. Next time I'll have that in mind!

Comment: No problem at all, I hope you'll have a good time in the community. :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
≡ᵍc?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/3DXzupHbRseNTU/6liuVFJUmqqnpPeoY4VSWmJOMZBd@3BXZ@3DrRP@P@pc@HBrb7L9///RxjoWhhY6poY6FhYWJiYmxsbGJjomJpZAYGioY2JqYqpjaGRsYmpmbmGpYwrkmhrrGGEDCGWGOgaGhhZAAywsDMHGWJobmRrHAgA)

*-1 thanks to DLosc*

Takes input as a list of digits through the input variable, and succeeds or fails as output.

```
≡ᵍ      The input with identical elements grouped in order of first appearance
  c     with the groups concatenated
   ?    is the input.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
vḟÞṠ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiduG4n8Oe4bmgIiwiIiwiXCIzXCJcblwiNTFcIlxuXCI0NDk5OTkxMVwiXG5cIjEyMzQ1Njc4OVwiXG5cIjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMlwiXG5cIjgxOFwiXG5cIjg4ODQ0NDMzMzRcIlxuXCI0NTQ1XCJcblwiNTU0NTUzXCJcblwiMTIzNDU2Nzg5MVwiIl0=)

```
vḟ  # Index of B in A, vectorized (B will be each individual character in the
    # string / item in the list, and A will be the string/list itself)
ÞṠ  # Is the result sorted?
```

Answers that use this method, in chronological order:

- [Dennis – Python, 33 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77624/17216)
- [isaacg – Pyth, 5 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77635/17216)
- [Dennis - Julia, 30 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77640/17216)
- [Dennis - J, 8 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77705/17216)
- [DLosc – BQN, 5 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251233/17216)
- [DLosc – Jelly, 5 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251235/17216)
- [Unrelated String – Jelly, 4 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251241/17216)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
₌ÞǓU=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oKMw57Hk1U9IiwiIiwiXCIzXCJcblwiNTFcIlxuXCI0NDk5OTkxMVwiXG5cIjEyMzQ1Njc4OVwiXG5cIjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMlwiXG5cIjgxOFwiXG5cIjg4ODQ0NDMzMzRcIlxuXCI0NTQ1XCJcblwiNTU0NTUzXCJcblwiMTIzNDU2Nzg5MVwiIl0=)

```
₌     # Parallel Apply - apply the following two elements to the input and keep
      # both results on the stack.
  ÞǓ  # Connected Uniquify - Remove occurences of adjacent duplicates.
  U   # Uniquify - Remove all duplicates.
=     # Are the two results equal?
```

Turned out to be a port of [Adnan's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77651/17216).

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @ovs

```
~/,/'='^:\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rT19FXt1WPs4rh4kpz0FEyVuJKUzI1BJEmJpZAYAhmGxoZm5iamVtYgjhG2IASly5QysLQAqTCwsLCxMTE2NjYBGyQqYkp2FggbWqMYpyhEgDXShno)

`^:` test for spaces - always returns 0s, as the input consists only of digits. The `:` here means monadic.

`^:\` repeat until convergence. This will return a pair of the original argument and a list of 0s of the same length as the argument.

`='` group each. To "group" a list means to make a dictionary that maps each distinct element of the list to the positions where it occurs.

`,/'` raze each, i.e. ignore the keys and concatenate the values. For the list of all 0s this will result in 0,1,...,length-1. For the other list, it will depend on the presence of non-continuous blocks - if there aren't any, the result will be 0,1,...,length-1 too.

`~/` do they match?

Comment: I think the ``#:'\`` can be ``^:\``

Comment: @ovs well spotted, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 40 bytes

```
\[A|S]:-S=[];(S=[A|_];\+member(A,S)),\S.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYzBDoIwEETvfMUeMCmxkNRutWI81A/wwlGIQa1KUgqhGC/@O7bcTJzDvNnd7PRDZ7pH6t7NNJUn9SmqPC32p2pHvKvPudqVy1a3Fz0QRYskoWWRTQu4dwM8a3szjX3AqN0I19ppl0fxEfIUrKFgX@HrfO1u2pEjVQmFtu5N40bSm5cjKUq/UhQOHu@hGbWxJOTykE0xz6IoFiw44taLzZmtOIr1Rm7DsPqncJBMzpASETnnONcIFHOpp@A/ZSz7Ag)

-3 thanks to Jo King

Similar to xnor's second Haskell answer.

This won't work on TIO because it is too old of a version, and it's longer, but I think it's more interesting:

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 57 bytes

```
\A:-clumped(A,B),maplist([X-_,X]>>!,B,C),list_to_set(A,C).
```

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 35 bytes

```
s->issorted(s,by=x->findfirst(s,x))
```

For whatever reason, `sort` does not take a string, but `issorted` does...

Comment: ...Are strings not immutable arrays in Julia like Python? That would make me really sad.

Comment: Yes, strings are immutable. That's probably why `issorted` works, but `sort` doesn't.

Comment: There isn't a sorting method defined for strings, but it wouldn't work if they were processed in the same way as one-dimensional arrays because those are sorted by performing an in-place sort of a copy, and as you said, strings are immutable. It's not a problem for checking for sorted order though because it's implemented as a simple loop over an iterable, which is fine for strings. Just some trivia. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AlexA. So *very* much like Python in fact; the difference is that Python's builtin `sorted` turns its iterable argument into a mutable list first -- that's why `sorted(string)` returns a list of strings

Answer (score 2):

### Lua, <s>107</s> <s>94</s> 85 Bytes

**13 bytes saved thanks to @LeakyNun**

At least, it beats Java :D. Lua sucks at manipulating strings, but I think it is good enough :).

It takes its input as a command-line argument, <s>and outputs `1` for truthy cases and `false` for falsy ones.</s> Now outputs using its exit code. Exit code 0 for truthy, and 1 for falsy

```lua
o=os.exit;(...):gsub("(.)(.+)%1",function(a,b)if 0<#b:gsub(a,"")then o(1)end end)o(0)
```

#### Ungolfed

Be care, there's two magic-variables called `...`, the first one contains the argument of the program, the second one is local to the anonymous function and contains its parameters

```lua
o=os.exit;               -- ; mandatory, else it would exit instantly
(...):gsub("(.)(.+)%1",  -- iterate over each group of the form x.*x and apply an anonymous
  function(a,b)          -- function that takes the captured group as parameters
  if 0<#b:gsub(a,"")     -- if the captured group (.+) contain other character than
  then                   -- the one captured by (.)
    o(1)                 -- exit with falsy
  end
end)
o(0)                     -- exit with truthy, reached only when the string is okay
```

Comment: If it is permitted, you can replace `os.exit()` with `i=#0`...

Answer (score 2):

## Factor, 22 bytes

```
[ dup natural-sort = ]
```

Does what it says on the tin. As an anonymouse function, you should `call` this, or make it a `: word ;`.

Comment: it scares me when a cat brings a *mouse* into the game

Comment: @downrep_nation :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 18 bytes

```
Gather@#==Split@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d8dJFTkoGxrG1yQk1nioKz2X0HfQaG62rhWR6HaVMcQRJnomOhYQqEhRMhQx0jHGChsqmOmY65joWMJEjTSIRLW6nApgEC1BdA8C5BWCx0QNAFDYzA0gdhsCrIE4hYwEwiNsToA6K7a2P8A)

`Gather` gathers a list into sublists of identical elements, and `Split` splits a list into sublists of consecutive identical elements. They give the same result if and only if each value appears in only one contiguous block.

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>9</s> 5 bytes

```
≡⟜∧⊐˜
```

Anonymous tacit function. Takes a string or a list of integers. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAg4omh4p+c4oin4oqQy5wKCkYg4p+oNCw0LDksOSw5LDksMSwx4p+pCg==)

#### Explanation

Inspired by [Dennis's J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77705/16766), though the details are a bit different.

Given two lists, `⊐` works as follows: for each element of its right argument, it finds the first index of that value in its left argument.

We're using `⊐˜`, which passes the same list as both left and right arguments. The result is a list, for each digit, of the index of that digit's first occurrence.

If the digits are grouped together, these indices will occur in ascending order. However, if some copies of digit A are separated by digit B, B's (larger) index will come between the copies of A's (smaller) index.

```
≡⟜∧⊐˜
    ⊐˜  First index of each digit in the argument list
≡⟜      The result is identical to
   ∧     The result, sorted ascending
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
iⱮ`ṢƑ
```

Takes a list of integers. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/z0cZ1CQ93Ljo28f///9EmOiY6llBoqGMYCwA)

#### Explanation

Port of [my BQN solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/251233/16766).

```
iⱮ`ṢƑ
i      First index of right argument in left argument
 Ɱ     mapped over right argument
  `    using the single argument as both left and right arguments
    Ƒ  The result is equal to
   Ṣ   itself sorted
```

---

Here's some other 5-byte solutions (see also [Dennis's 5-byte solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77617/16766)):

```
ĠṢFṢƑ
Ġ      Group indices by their value in the list
 Ṣ     Sort list of lists of indices
  F    Flatten
    Ƒ  The result is equal to
   Ṣ   itself sorted
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Igoc7F7kB8bGJ////jzbRMdGxhEJDHcNYAA)

```
ĠṢF⁼J
Ġ      Group indices by their value in the list
 Ṣ     Sort list of lists of indices
  F    Flatten
   ⁼   The result is equal to
    J  Range from 1 up to len of original argument
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Igoc7F7k9atzj9f///2gTHRMdSyg01DGMBQA)

```
¹ƙ`F⁼
¹ƙ`    Sort into buckets of identical items, ordered by first occurrence
   F   Flatten
    ⁼  The result is equal to the original list
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QzmMzE9weNe75//9/tImOiY4lFBqCYCwA)

Comment: [An incredibly sad variation of the last one](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/h8IZjM90eNe7573K4XTPy/39jHQtDCx1TQx0LCwsTExNjY2MTHRMTSyAwNNQxMTUx1TE0MjYxNTO3sNQxBXJNjXWMsAGEMkMdQ0MLoH4LC0OwKZbmRqbGAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 28 bytes

```arturo
$=>[=squeeze<=sort squeeze&]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?ZTFvmA)

```
$=>[          ; a function where input is assigned to &
    squeeze&  ; squeeze the input; e.g. [1 1 2 1 1 1 3 3] -> [1 2 1 3]
    sort      ; sort
    <=        ; duplicate
    squeeze   ; squeeze
    =         ; are they equal?
]             ; end function
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ñdḞ⁼
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMyVCMWQlRTElQjglOUUlRTIlODElQkMmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD00JTJDNCUyQzklMkM5JTJDOSUyQzklMkMxJTJDMSZmbGFncz0=)

Input as a digit list.

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
çµUUạ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMyVBNyVDMiVCNVVVJUUxJUJBJUExJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9NDQ5OTk5MTEmZmxhZ3M9)

Input as an integer.

##### Explanation

```python
ñdḞ⁼  # Implicit input
ñd    # Group identical items together
  Ḟ   # Flatten the list
   ⁼  # Equals the input?
```

```python
çµUUạ  # Implicit input
ç      # Pair apply on the input:
 µU    #  Connected uniquify
   U   #  Uniquify
    ạ  # Are they the same?
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
≍⊝.⊜⊢.
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_3_1__ZiDihpAg4omN4oqdLuKKnOKKoi4KCmYgWzNdCmYgWzUgMV0KZiBbNCA0IDkgOSA5IDkgMSAxXQpmIFsxIDIgMyA0IDUgNiA3IDggOV0KZiBbMiAyIDIgMiAyIDIgMiAyIDIgMiAyIDIgMiAyIDIgMiAyIDIgMiAyIDJdCmYgWzggMSA4XQpmIFs4IDggOCA0IDQgNCAzIDMgMyA0XQpmIFs0IDUgNCA1XQpmIFs1IDUgNCA1IDUgM10KZiBbMSAyIDMgNCA1IDYgNyA4IDkgMV0K)

```
≍⊝.⊜⊢.
   ⊜⊢.  # get the first digit in each like contiguous group
  .     # duplicate
 ⊝      # deduplicate
≍       # do they match?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 22 bytes

```
&i[s=[ppl=]pl~[!u;]p]1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18tM7rYNrqgIMc2tiCnLlqx1Dq2INbw/39DI2MTUzNzC0tDAA)

This one isn't that all short, but as far as I can tell it works differently from the other programs posted.  It deletes all "grouped" digits, then searches the remaining digits for the digit it just deleted.  If if finds another one, `0` is printed and the code exits.  If the stack is exhausted, the default `1` output is printed.

```
&i                     - read all the digits as codepoints
  [                 ]  - loop until the stack is empty
   s                   - save current digit
    =                  - is the next digit the same?
     [    ]            - yes, then loop deleting that digit
      p                - delete previous test results
       p               - delete digit we just checked
        l              - load the current digit
         =             - does the next one match?
           p           - delete loop/iterator var
            l          - load the current digit again
             ~         - is there another of those digits?
              [    ]   - yes, then time to exit...
               !ul;    - push "0", print and exit
                    p  - print test result variable
                     1 - push "1" for truthy result
                       - stack prints on exit
```

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```
Prompt A
sum(not(∆List(ʟA
SortA(ʟA
Ans=sum(not(∆List(ʟA
```

Takes input as a list ot integers.

-2 bytes thanks to [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush).

Comment: -2 bytes with `not(` instead of `0≠`

Comment: @MarcMush I believe `not(` is equivalent to `0=`. `0≠` is equivalent to `not(not(`.

Comment: The number will not be the same but you compare both of them so it works out in the end

Comment: If you change it at both lines

Answer (score 2):

## GNU [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-E`,  <s>32</s>  28 bytes

Thank you, Jiří, for golfing off four bytes!

In the first line, remove all duplicate characters to avoid false positives, then check whether there is still a character twice. Output `F` for Falsy or `T` for Truthy:

```
s/(.)\1*/\1/g
/(.).+\1/cF
cT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYsxDoJQEET7OQli4GfZWV0OICegpENCbMDky/Vdv5WNr5i8KV5e7s26HRE5Ve1pkjpNklZ8T3suOg@YxwiFCci@IALplHa5eo/uH3BxuDtJVSVoNFgZ018q7/35euxbjub2AQ)

Even without `-E`, it would only be 32 bytes, by far better than the current `sed` solution.

Comment: Nice! You can have it even in 28B by removing trailing space on the second line and the `//!`.

Comment: @Jiří Thank you. I wasn't really aware of how `c` works.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>71</s> 69 bytes

```
h=y=>y.match(/(.)\1*/g);x=>h((u=h(x)).sort().join``).length==u.length
```

Or, equivalently:

```
x=>((u=x.match(r=/(.)\1*/g)).sort().join``).match(r).length==u.length
x=>(h=y=>y.match(/(.)\1*/g))((u=h(x)).sort().join``).length==u.length
```

Golfing in progress.

### Verify test cases

```js
var truthy = `3
51
44999911
123456789
222222222222222222222`.split `
`;
var falsey = `818
8884443334
4545
554553
1234567891`.split `
`;

var Q = x => ((u = x.match(r = /(.)\1*/g)).sort().join ``).match(r).length == u.length;
truthy.concat(falsey).forEach(e => {
  t = document.createTextNode(`${e} => ${Q(e)}`);
  o.appendChild(t);
  o.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Consolas, monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id=o></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 20 bytes

19, plus 1 for `-pe` instead of `-e`.

```
$_=!/(.)(?!\1).+\1/
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <s>74</s> <s>73</s> 71 bytes

Shaved <s>one</s> three byte thanks to @xsot!

```
a[99],c,m;main(d){for(;~c;m|=c^d&&a[d=c]++)c=getchar();putchar(48+!m);}
```

Comment: `a[99]` I love Perl's autovivification! Oh, wait...

Comment: I think this works: `a[99],c,m;main(d){for(;~c;m|=a[d=c]+=c!=d)c=getchar();putchar(48+1/m);} `

Comment: @xsot - Thank you for shaving one byte by replacing `!--m` with `1/m`. About `a[d=c]+=c!=d`, I tried it with gcc and it didn't work on my computer because of order of evaluation. We must find a compiler that will play along.

Comment: Oh, I just tested it on ideone and it worked fine. How about this: `a[99],c,m;main(d){for(;~c;m|=c^d&&a[d=c]++)c=getchar();putchar(48+!m);}`

Comment: -2 bytes using `read(2)` and outputting `49 - m`: `a[99],c,m;main(d){for(;read(0,&c,1);m|=c^d&&a[d=c]++);putchar(49-m);}`, also possible is `return m` to save an extra 5 bytes

Answer (score 1):

### C# 111 bytes

```
bool f(string s){for(int i=0;i<s.Length-1;i++)if(s[i]!=s[i+1]&&s.LastIndexOf(s[i])!=i)return 1==2;return true;}
```

*old strategy* **131 bytes**

```
bool s(string i){var f=Regex.Matches(i,@"([0-9])\1{0,}").Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Value[0]);return f.Distinct().SequenceEqual(f);}
```

first golf i think i did ok in

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 53 bytes

The dumb, simple version.

```
(λ(s)(let([s(string->list s)])(eq?(sort s char<?)s)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (lame-all-together s)
  (let ([s (string->list s)])
    (eq? (sort s char<?) s)))
```

## Racket, 86 bytes

Here's the version implementing [@xnor's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77608/all-together-now/77777#comment189915_77608) about more efficient ways to do this.

```
(λ(s)(let([s(string->list(regexp-replace#px"(.)\\1+"s"\\1"))])(eq?(sort s char<?)s)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (all-together s)
    (let ([s (string->list (regexp-replace #px"(.)\\1+" s "\\1"))])
      (eq? (sort s char<?) s )))
```

Okay, this may actually just shift the weight of computation from the `sort` function to `regexp-replace`, but it was an interesting solution. Basically, it removes runs of duplicate characters *first* ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/bH3jP7/1)), then tests if the remaining length-1 runs are in sorted fashion.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 54 bytes

```
:a
/^1/{s/1*//;/1/cF
}
y/123456789/912345678/
/./ba
cT
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bYwxCsJQEET7OYpghs3uxv3aewFTB2LUC0QLEU9i80E8VG5jIEYbXzFM897j2R8POb8u59Myhmrdgo3w1lMW5IbCbos7rpRSzatVJKb5Eiy4b9HVk_2J5GGncIFZGhHBV0X5D4QEIsLMVNVgbg4fx_WnytR-Aw)

Comment: Clever idea, but no match for [back references](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266985/72726)!

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 83 bytes

```
A=[1...l.length][l=i]
L=join(A.min-1,A)
f(l)=[0^{max(L[2...]-L-1)}fori=l[1...]].min
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/powssqzeok)

[Try It Online! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kxmu8qbehi)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

```ruby
->s{(s*'').squeeze==s.uniq*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYvLDoIwEEX38xUTSERNJCmdalmUHzEufBQhwQoMjVHCt9fu3HgWd3Fuzugv71CbsKt4XvM2yzY5D97ajzWGc@/aIbolvJq2s@jQ4N1OvMqvzfPRA2LvJ8Yknd2CpsJ0ro8ufueRT0sC1t2CBCWAqIwIAaKQpPYHXULxD9BCg9aaiKSUBKRIgYqj5C8VXw)

Longer than using regex, but uses a builtin that doesn't need to exist.

`squeeze` is connected-uniquify. It's on strings, but not lists, and `uniq` is on lists, and not strings...

Answer (score 0):

### Convex, 17 bytes

```
9´\f{\s'++\ð½¬}ª!
```

[Try it online!](http://convex.tryitonline.net/#code=OcK0XGZ7XHMnKytcw7DCvcKsfcKqIQ&input=&args=IjQ0OTk5OTExIg)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 9 bytes

```
ò¦ mÌ
eUâ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8qYgbcwKZVXi&input=Ijg4ODQ0NDMzMzQi)

---

### Explanation

```
          :Implicit input of string U             :e.g., "8884443334"
ò¦        :Split on inequality                    :["888","444","333","4"]
   mÌ     :Map and return the last digit of each  :["8","4","3","4"]
\n        :Assign to U
  Uâ      :Remove duplicates                      :["8","4","3"]
e         :Test for equality with U               :false
          :Implicit output of result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

```apl
(⍋≡⍳∘≢)∘⌽∘∊2⊥∘.=⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbBI1Hvd2POhc@6t38qGPGo85FmiCqZy@I7OgyetS1FMjSs33UuwKoXEHdWJ0LSJoagikTE0sgMIRwDI2MTUzNzC0swTwjbECdCyRlYWgBVmJhYWFiYmJsbGwCMczUxBRiOJBhaoxqpqE6AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL, 158 bytes

```
select decode(count(*),count(unique y),1,0)from(select regexp_substr(x,'(.)\1*',1,level,'',1)y from t connect by regexp_substr(x,'(.)\1*',1,level)is not null)
```

It works with an assumption that input data is stored in a table t(x), e.g.

```
with t(x) as (select '44999911' from dual)
```

Answer (score 0):

## brev, 86 bytes

```
(fn(with(call-table)((as-list(c every(fn(or(eq?(it'l)x)(it x(not(it(it'l x))))))))x)))
```

or 79 if it doesn't have to reset its memory between each call, i.e. doesn't have to be idempotent:

```
(with(call-table)(as-list(c every(fn(or(eq?(it'l)x)(it x(not(it(it'l x)))))))))
```

Comment: People are submitting solutions that take lists of integers. That'd shave 9 bytes off of mine (the `(as-list …)`).

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 58 bytes

A port of [@JamesENL's Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/77657/110802) in Scala.

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVJNa9wwEIUe_SsmZiFS2Rgcy62z4C35oFBockjbU5LDxB7vqnhlI8nJlpBf0ktySC-lP6j9NZXtXUNZV2CP9N6b0dMw33-YDEuMfl75B6q6R638mz-vfslVXWkLHRc0VpbBCm22lGoRXNKC1p5X3X6lzMI5SgUPHkBOBazcgaFemBkca43frj5Z7VJu-Ay-KGkh7ZQAd1iCJWNP0ZBx6EdpLOsYAOZH_hSsbohPBygOdzEhjtwKR5jwMBLxm7fJ0S51OLZ2ZUmYOLDA0vyDJokQIooiMUKKWMQjcOzgOBohBpPhQHYc97owtCcoKk2YLeEBMncGJlXd2CnQunb9p5xDOt8UbduqyTRl2-klmovqkmpCJzpdokan1qZP55sMNIa0ZdukdKg6BeN_dhb6O_cnXda-8ynLltzKYDLsbhsLi8rCpC_mb6-o3QTYUrHRenVrIN9oH7328_p3_Mf-jPUjlc5PqqokVO758NLY4iD5PVunc9hTdA_diDKfBZy927u-Dnnw2v19HhRS5e-lNvaDYmseSHNGDqK8r_D82Menpz7-BQ)

```scala
x=> !new Regex("(.)(?!\\1).*\\1").findFirstIn(x).isDefined
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVJLS8QwEAaP_RWzZcFU1kJtqt2FVUQRBL34OO16iG1aI920JFMfLPtLvOxFL978Of4a08cWZBtI2nyPyTAzH186Yhnzv2f2vsxfmZL2w_qzxGQ__N35EYsiVwi1xC1RZO6CYfQkZOre8JS_WVb--MwjhGsmJCwtgJgnsDAXwlSqJ3CqFHuf3aIylgdnAvdSIExrJcALy6BgiFxJg0n-CnVQYhPXISeD-dxz3D1z2o7V6ZFrPGOaa-O4EhpJzQAQ27dHgKrkzqiDAm8bo3RsltfDeAc-DQ6PwvE2ddC3tmWhFxowYZn-h4YhpdT3fdpD0oAGPXBg4MDvIbokvY6subZEXXncJFecRU-whMjcgQhZlDgC_laYfvHYgelxG7Qqq-K6zKrODNqGuImQ8YVQGi9l43Vcoc-5gXncGpnWXCHZeKdd8BFo-85k0jy9O6z9uyZdkVXkRgbD7u-xREhzhGETzHbaJwozOJhJ0huvqBKIW-3KqvaqGd12gtft9w8)

```scala
import scala.util.matching.Regex

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val pattern = new Regex("(.)(?!\\1).*\\1")

    val testCases = List(
      ("3", true),
      ("51", true),
      ("44999911", true),
      ("123456789", true),
      ("222222222222222222222", true),
      ("818", false),
      ("8884443334", false),
      ("4545", false),
      ("554553", false),
      ("1234567891", false)
    )

    testCases.foreach { case (input, expected) =>
      val result = !pattern.findFirstIn(input).isDefined
      assert(result == expected, s"Test case '$input' failed, expected $expected but got $result")
      println(s"Test case '$input' passed")
    }
  }
}
```