# Crack the bank account's password!

Tags: code-golf

## Introduction

In order to prevent keyloggers from stealing a user's password, a certain bank account system has implemented the following security measure: only certain digits are prompted to be entered each time.

For example, say your target's password is `89097`, the system may prompt them to enter the 2nd, 4th and 5th digit:

`997`

Or it might prompt them to enter the 1st, 3rd and 5th digit:

`807`

All you know is that your target entered the digits in order, *but you don't know which position they belong to in the actual password*. All you know is there are two 9s, which must come before 7; and that 8 comes before 0, and 0 before 7. Therefore, there are six possible passwords:

```
80997
89097
89907
98097
98907
99807
```

The keylogger in your target's computer has been collecting password inputs for months now, so let's hack in!

## Challenge

Given a list of three-digit inputs, output all the possible passwords that are valid for all inputs. In order to reduce computational complexity and to keep the amount of possible results low, the password is guaranteed to be numerical and have a fixed size of 5. The digits in every input are in order: if it's 123, the target typed 1 first, then 2, then 3.

## Input/Output examples

```
|----------------------|--------------------------------------------|
|         Input        |                   Output                   |
|----------------------|--------------------------------------------|
| [320, 723, 730]      | [37230, 72320, 73203, 73230]               |
| [374, 842]           | [37842, 38742, 83742]                      |
| [010, 103, 301]      | [30103]                                    |
| [123, 124, 125, 235] | [12345, 12354, 12435]                      |
| [239, 944]           | [23944]                                    |
| [111, 120]           | [11201, 11120, 11210, 12011, 12110, 12101] |
| [456, 789]           | []                                         |
| [756, 586]           | [07586, 17586, 27586, 37586, 47586, 57586, 57856, 58756, 67586, 70586, 71586, 72586, 73586, 74586, 75086, 75186, 75286, 75386, 75486, 75586, 75686, 75786, 75806, 75816, 75826, 75836, 75846, 75856, 75860, 75861, 75862, 75863, 75864, 75865, 75866, 75867, 75868, 75869, 75876, 75886, 75896, 75986, 76586, 77586, 78586, 79586, 87586, 97586] |
| [123]                | [00123, 01023, 01123, 01203, 01213, 01223, 01230, 01231, 01232, 01233, 01234, 01235, 01236, 01237, 01238, 01239, 01243, 01253, 01263, 01273, 01283, 01293, 01323, 01423, 01523, 01623, 01723, 01823, 01923, 02123, 03123, 04123, 05123, 06123, 07123, 08123, 09123, 10023, 10123, 10203, 10213, 10223, 10230, 10231, 10232, 10233, 10234, 10235, 10236, 10237, 10238, 10239, 10243, 10253, 10263, 10273, 10283, 10293, 10323, 10423, 10523, 10623, 10723, 10823, 10923, 11023, 11123, 11203, 11213, 11223, 11230, 11231, 11232, 11233, 11234, 11235, 11236, 11237, 11238, 11239, 11243, 11253, 11263, 11273, 11283, 11293, 11323, 11423, 11523, 11623, 11723, 11823, 11923, 12003, 12013, 12023, 12030, 12031, 12032, 12033, 12034, 12035, 12036, 12037, 12038, 12039, 12043, 12053, 12063, 12073, 12083, 12093, 12103, 12113, 12123, 12130, 12131, 12132, 12133, 12134, 12135, 12136, 12137, 12138, 12139, 12143, 12153, 12163, 12173, 12183, 12193, 12203, 12213, 12223, 12230, 12231, 12232, 12233, 12234, 12235, 12236, 12237, 12238, 12239, 12243, 12253, 12263, 12273, 12283, 12293, 12300, 12301, 12302, 12303, 12304, 12305, 12306, 12307, 12308, 12309, 12310, 12311, 12312, 12313, 12314, 12315, 12316, 12317, 12318, 12319, 12320, 12321, 12322, 12323, 12324, 12325, 12326, 12327, 12328, 12329, 12330, 12331, 12332, 12333, 12334, 12335, 12336, 12337, 12338, 12339, 12340, 12341, 12342, 12343, 12344, 12345, 12346, 12347, 12348, 12349, 12350, 12351, 12352, 12353, 12354, 12355, 12356, 12357, 12358, 12359, 12360, 12361, 12362, 12363, 12364, 12365, 12366, 12367, 12368, 12369, 12370, 12371, 12372, 12373, 12374, 12375, 12376, 12377, 12378, 12379, 12380, 12381, 12382, 12383, 12384, 12385, 12386, 12387, 12388, 12389, 12390, 12391, 12392, 12393, 12394, 12395, 12396, 12397, 12398, 12399, 12403, 12413, 12423, 12430, 12431, 12432, 12433, 12434, 12435, 12436, 12437, 12438, 12439, 12443, 12453, 12463, 12473, 12483, 12493, 12503, 12513, 12523, 12530, 12531, 12532, 12533, 12534, 12535, 12536, 12537, 12538, 12539, 12543, 12553, 12563, 12573, 12583, 12593, 12603, 12613, 12623, 12630, 12631, 12632, 12633, 12634, 12635, 12636, 12637, 12638, 12639, 12643, 12653, 12663, 12673, 12683, 12693, 12703, 12713, 12723, 12730, 12731, 12732, 12733, 12734, 12735, 12736, 12737, 12738, 12739, 12743, 12753, 12763, 12773, 12783, 12793, 12803, 12813, 12823, 12830, 12831, 12832, 12833, 12834, 12835, 12836, 12837, 12838, 12839, 12843, 12853, 12863, 12873, 12883, 12893, 12903, 12913, 12923, 12930, 12931, 12932, 12933, 12934, 12935, 12936, 12937, 12938, 12939, 12943, 12953, 12963, 12973, 12983, 12993, 13023, 13123, 13203, 13213, 13223, 13230, 13231, 13232, 13233, 13234, 13235, 13236, 13237, 13238, 13239, 13243, 13253, 13263, 13273, 13283, 13293, 13323, 13423, 13523, 13623, 13723, 13823, 13923, 14023, 14123, 14203, 14213, 14223, 14230, 14231, 14232, 14233, 14234, 14235, 14236, 14237, 14238, 14239, 14243, 14253, 14263, 14273, 14283, 14293, 14323, 14423, 14523, 14623, 14723, 14823, 14923, 15023, 15123, 15203, 15213, 15223, 15230, 15231, 15232, 15233, 15234, 15235, 15236, 15237, 15238, 15239, 15243, 15253, 15263, 15273, 15283, 15293, 15323, 15423, 15523, 15623, 15723, 15823, 15923, 16023, 16123, 16203, 16213, 16223, 16230, 16231, 16232, 16233, 16234, 16235, 16236, 16237, 16238, 16239, 16243, 16253, 16263, 16273, 16283, 16293, 16323, 16423, 16523, 16623, 16723, 16823, 16923, 17023, 17123, 17203, 17213, 17223, 17230, 17231, 17232, 17233, 17234, 17235, 17236, 17237, 17238, 17239, 17243, 17253, 17263, 17273, 17283, 17293, 17323, 17423, 17523, 17623, 17723, 17823, 17923, 18023, 18123, 18203, 18213, 18223, 18230, 18231, 18232, 18233, 18234, 18235, 18236, 18237, 18238, 18239, 18243, 18253, 18263, 18273, 18283, 18293, 18323, 18423, 18523, 18623, 18723, 18823, 18923, 19023, 19123, 19203, 19213, 19223, 19230, 19231, 19232, 19233, 19234, 19235, 19236, 19237, 19238, 19239, 19243, 19253, 19263, 19273, 19283, 19293, 19323, 19423, 19523, 19623, 19723, 19823, 19923, 20123, 21023, 21123, 21203, 21213, 21223, 21230, 21231, 21232, 21233, 21234, 21235, 21236, 21237, 21238, 21239, 21243, 21253, 21263, 21273, 21283, 21293, 21323, 21423, 21523, 21623, 21723, 21823, 21923, 22123, 23123, 24123, 25123, 26123, 27123, 28123, 29123, 30123, 31023, 31123, 31203, 31213, 31223, 31230, 31231, 31232, 31233, 31234, 31235, 31236, 31237, 31238, 31239, 31243, 31253, 31263, 31273, 31283, 31293, 31323, 31423, 31523, 31623, 31723, 31823, 31923, 32123, 33123, 34123, 35123, 36123, 37123, 38123, 39123, 40123, 41023, 41123, 41203, 41213, 41223, 41230, 41231, 41232, 41233, 41234, 41235, 41236, 41237, 41238, 41239, 41243, 41253, 41263, 41273, 41283, 41293, 41323, 41423, 41523, 41623, 41723, 41823, 41923, 42123, 43123, 44123, 45123, 46123, 47123, 48123, 49123, 50123, 51023, 51123, 51203, 51213, 51223, 51230, 51231, 51232, 51233, 51234, 51235, 51236, 51237, 51238, 51239, 51243, 51253, 51263, 51273, 51283, 51293, 51323, 51423, 51523, 51623, 51723, 51823, 51923, 52123, 53123, 54123, 55123, 56123, 57123, 58123, 59123, 60123, 61023, 61123, 61203, 61213, 61223, 61230, 61231, 61232, 61233, 61234, 61235, 61236, 61237, 61238, 61239, 61243, 61253, 61263, 61273, 61283, 61293, 61323, 61423, 61523, 61623, 61723, 61823, 61923, 62123, 63123, 64123, 65123, 66123, 67123, 68123, 69123, 70123, 71023, 71123, 71203, 71213, 71223, 71230, 71231, 71232, 71233, 71234, 71235, 71236, 71237, 71238, 71239, 71243, 71253, 71263, 71273, 71283, 71293, 71323, 71423, 71523, 71623, 71723, 71823, 71923, 72123, 73123, 74123, 75123, 76123, 77123, 78123, 79123, 80123, 81023, 81123, 81203, 81213, 81223, 81230, 81231, 81232, 81233, 81234, 81235, 81236, 81237, 81238, 81239, 81243, 81253, 81263, 81273, 81283, 81293, 81323, 81423, 81523, 81623, 81723, 81823, 81923, 82123, 83123, 84123, 85123, 86123, 87123, 88123, 89123, 90123, 91023, 91123, 91203, 91213, 91223, 91230, 91231, 91232, 91233, 91234, 91235, 91236, 91237, 91238, 91239, 91243, 91253, 91263, 91273, 91283, 91293, 91323, 91423, 91523, 91623, 91723, 91823, 91923, 92123, 93123, 94123, 95123, 96123, 97123, 98123, 99123] |
|----------------------|--------------------------------------------|
```

---

## Rules

- Input is guaranteed non-empty.
- Leading and trailing zeros matter: `01234` is different from `12340`, and `1234` doesn't crack either password. Think of how real passwords work!
- [Standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) apply.
- No [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins. Non-codegolfing languages are welcome!

Comment: Are the digits always in order? Based on the test cases I assume they are, but I couldn't see it mentioned in the rules unless I read past it.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, they are in order. I'll add that to the post.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! This is a nice, well-structured, and neatly formatted first challenge. You've clearly done your homework as far as getting that all down. I'm looking forward to answering it (if someone doesn't answer it in R first!). In the future, we suggest using [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to get feedback before posting to main. Hope you enjoy your time on PPCG!

Comment: @Giuseppe thanks! I've been anonymously reading the questions on this site for years, and I've been writing and tweaking and actually solving this specific problem for a couple months: I liked it enough to skip the sandbox. I'll post there first next time!

Comment: Are leading zeros in the output mandatory?

Comment: @Arnauld Well, if your password is 01234 or 12340 you shouldn't be able to log in by typing 1234. Passwords are more a string than a number even if composed by numbers, at least in that sense. So yes, leading and trailing zeros are mandatory.

Comment: @cefel You should mention that in the challenge.

Comment: I'm confused by the example.  If we know 1st/3rd/5th digits and also know 2nd/4th/5th, don't we know all 5 digits?  I don't see where the ambiguity leading to 6 possibilities arises... (EDIT: oh ok we don't the specific digits that were asked for?  i think you should make that explicit)

Comment: Said another way, the problem is asking you to construct a full sequence of known length from multiple sub-sequences (whose indexes you do not know).

Comment: Are we allowed to take the three-digit inputs as digit lists (so like `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`?)

Comment: @Arnauld I've added your recommendation into the post. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Jonah I've made it explicit in the post, thanks for the input. You probably nailed the problem's description in the most generic way possible - it was truly inspired by a bank account system, though, so I kept the password idea into the challenge. :)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino yes, sure.

Comment: The final test case appears to be missing 22123... unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: This is a special case of finding the [Shortest common supersequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence_problem).

Comment: @Jonah you're right - for some reason my solution is skipping that particular number... there must be a bug somewhere. I'm adding it to the test case. Nice catch!

Comment: @user202729 rest assured that I didn't know the shortest common supersequence problem was a thing - still, I don't think we've had anything like it in PPCG before.

Answer (score 25):

## Python, 100 bytes

```python
lambda e,d='%05d':[d%i for i in range(10**5)if all(re.search('.*'.join(x),d%i)for x in e)]
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcuxCoMwEADQvV9xi1wiQaLgIvgl1iFtLvWKJuF0sF@f1qXrg5c/x5JiV8J4L6vbHt4BGT9iZXuPw@QrhpAEGDiCuPgi1dq67jUHcOuqhJqdnDwXhU2NzTtxVKc2v6avdl6N9HzjLSc5QKj8OagJrbVoANvO4qwHyMLxgLN8AQ)

Works in Python 2 as well as Python 3.

(**97 bytes** in Python 3.8:)

```python
lambda e:[p for i in range(10**5)if all(re.search('.*'.join(x),p:='%05d'%i)for x in e)]
import re
```

Comment: This is a lovely solution...

Comment: Your non-3.8 code can do the "poor-man's assignment expression" of aliasing the string `'%05d'`.

Answer (score 23):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
žh5ãʒæIåP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4M08OLT006vMzz8NKA//@jzU3NdEwtzGIB)

**Explanation**

```
žh          # push 0123456789
  5ã        # 5 times cartesian product
    ʒ       # filter, keep only values are true under:
     æ      # powerset of value
      Iå    # check if each of the input values are in this list
        P   # product
```

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript (ES6), 88 bytes

Prints the results with `alert()`.

```javascript
a=>{for(k=n=1e5;n--;)a.every(x=>(s=([k]+n).slice(-5)).match([...x].join`.*`))&&alert(s)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLfboIwFMbvfYpeSbtB7V@BEHwRQmLD6qYyWIAYF@Ozs1OaMDVw0V97vu98p2k4mYvpq@74M0RN@2HHQz6afHc7tB0@503Orc6aKMqIofZiu198zXe4z3FxLt8bQvv6WFkcaULotxmqL1xQSq8lPbXHZk/f9oSs16a23YB7ch@nHcpR1TZ9W1tat5/ZarC9qxmU79DtUcJmisFBiAJCMnTABtZHAxzvqykAF4EUzDljISdIFpTIfwRtNqiQoLAQwSocYJUTJCvniFi53kSJufclAqQQySR2SMAu5l7Gp/GcTeMl46/jwSBnN/e35EJ5aAchdVB6N@hKhwiglYOSeu4VMnXuVKnlW4Ku1P8kzv0ItuzmoHAY4egguAPUXFFwf@KMz4FKb6cHTtLlwNkYe6NOtstGFoME6R7w34QodfunR3rpfA5g4AgRPKyDD0ihVI5/)

#### Commented

```javascript
a => {                    // a[] = input array of 3-character strings
  for(k = n = 1e5; n--;)  // initialize k to 100000; for n = 99999 to 0:
    a.every(x =>          // for each string x = 'XYZ' in a[]:
      ( s =               //   define s as the concatenation of
          ([k] + n)       //   '100000' and n; e.g. '100000' + 1337 -> '1000001337'
          .slice(-5)      //   keep the last 5 digits; e.g. '01337'
      ).match(            //   test whether this string is matching
        [...x].join`.*`   //   the pattern /X.*Y.*Z/
      )                   //
    ) &&                  // end of every(); if all tests were successful:
      alert(s)            //   output s
}                         //
```

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, <s>81</s> <s>80</s> <s>78</s> 76 bytes

```
f x=[p|p<-mapM(:['1'..'9'])"00000",all(`elem`(concat.words<$>mapM(:" ")p))x]
```

The obvious brute force approach in Haskell: built a list of all possible passwords and keep those where all elements from the input list are in respective list of subsequences.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5dCoMwEITfe4olFDRgJX9WLdob9AQSMLRKpVGDCvWhd7dNLLovAzPf7O5Tja9K62WpYc4L8zHZqVXm5l8Kj3ph6KWexIjYQYHS2i8rXbWlf@@7u5rCdz88xux4XSsIEDYYz3JpVdNBDtYG3wxNN0FYYygOAFAgzn7LAMWMO@EEyeCfxMJaiWCbRaiDKXEwJ3RL6NqnTKwSWWE82gDGU2ulQuwdSld4vymis3sjSZGUsHwB)

Edit: -1 byte thanks to @xnor, <s>-2</s> -4 bytes thanks to @H.PWiz

Comment: Looks like you can [compute the subseqs yourself](https://tio.run/##RY5NCoMwFIT3PcUjCCpoyG9VUG/QE6SBBqtUGm1oXbjo3S3GoquBmW/em4f5PFtrl6WDuVLu68p0MO4C/T1QIQkxDotQl4GiGEudGGujW2vb4RY1r7ExUxnUKx5dm7RWCCWq0Tp2cTzrZTD9CBX4a5F79@MEuItBnQBAIc4ISgBljHvhBOnkn2RitXLBdotQD1PiYU7ontCtT5nYRK7CuNwBxovVKoQ4OpRu8PFTyLOfkRdIa1h@) a little shorter.

Comment: `concat.words<$>mapM(:" ")p` is shorter

Comment: use `p<-mapM(:['1'..'9'])"00000"` to save 2 more bytes

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 96 bytes

```python
l=input()
n=1e5
while n:
 n-=1;s='%05d'%n;t={''}
 for c in s:t|={x+c for x in t}
 if l<t:print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3bCoMwEETf8xVBkLS0hWwuXpuvsUoDEkVTarF@u01W6MssZ2aYHT/@OTixv5@2bylU7dI2SZLsvbFufPnTmTgDrSZH7ipC3c1APRuWcv1gqau9WRnbCO2GiTbUOjpX/mvW5dKgtUTLh9x2tL/7apys83Te8ZL4amVScHZluZBRJQ9rwctVoEIJJA6xATw2JAf0APsgFKoOKqTGRMgyUKnU0QPAxrGrdBa/FCVSjqSL7L@4/QA)

Takes input as a set of strings.

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 98 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,s='':any(l)or print(s)if s[4:]else[f([x[x[:1]==c:]for x in l],s+c)for c in'0123456789']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU5da4QwEHw2vyJvm7QW8nlqIL9E8mCtcoE0Jxfb3v16u7FlYZjdGWZ2e@7XW9bHsfo0fb5/TDS1xQO4KT9Z4rc73e4x76zwuNIyGheWVJZxZeMDx8ng/ezCir4HjZmm0JbXmdd9xh2EVNrYS9cPEI6fa0wLlY40yadYdrZ8T4nFvH3tjHNOmhUbSfNXCG/wYvkBWglooVO6ohZAQHcGeW8UciGrKkVVtZB4kadTKnOiRVTa4l3pAflgTPVIeao1Db@ryfggge7ktr/85/wC)

Recursively tries building every five-digit number string in `s`, tracking the subsequences in `l` still remaining to be hit. If all are empty by the end, prints the result.

Comment: Your Py3.8 submission has a couple of syntax errors related to reassigning stuff that shouldn't be reassigned. I tried fixing the problems that popped up but I [lost 25 bytes in the way](https://tio.run/##LY7NbsMgEITP8VOgXICoB5af2EbiSSwfrMRukBCxbNIkqvrs7q7by@hjZjTL/C63ezbNvGzbdZzYJJL0FZvuC8ssZrYM@XMUoE4nRz5bw3T8zl65nyO@4sSGlATnMQtRfHjJIV87hNKVzkMfwsX3tHWhrbWXxC9ivDIvMRexyu15i2lk4KtDCimuRYxfQxIxz48ipJTV4a9JX5MbN1rxD15rQ2oUr7ipLXJjNbICSkFRahSgA3sTtN3VoWrj0NemRW6tpQ7AntKadWdablrkemfXnP93fgE) xD

Comment: @RGS Weird, did I really not test that, or maybe something changed? Thanks for catching that, I deleted it.

Comment: I was able to pull the 3.8 one back down to [104 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYzLjsIgGIXX9imIG8C44OdiWxKepNMFo0VJEEmtTicTn71CY2Zz8uXc0u90uUXRpHFx5msJ9vp9sijozm3/ombqtXW3EUXkIxptPA8E2G6nqHfIhkCuNpHPZNYY@9jN2szd3GnojTnqvoyPZfx/1@8Dpf3yc/FhQKCrTTDB3ycyPG0gPqbHRCil1SaNPk7EkdxesOAM73HNRVHBcIVFLTM3kmdmUFJgJRUMsgNrE7hcVWXlQmWfizZzK2XpAKxpeZPqUJ6bNnO9smoOn583) though it's still not worth it.

Comment: @Bubbler I'm posting my 119 byter. Do you want to post your 104 or should I post it as you golfing mine down?

Comment: @RGS I'm fine if you post it. Also, [102 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYzLjsIgFIbX9inYGMC44HCxLQlP0umC0XYkQSS1aufpO4fG2fz58t/y73y9J9XkaR3d1xr97fviSbQd3QtzoftExvtEEgmJTD79DAzE4WB4GImPkd18Zp/JYikNqVusW7qls9A7d7Z9GZ9x/P/WHyPn/fq@hjgQsNUuuhgeMxtePrKQ8nNmnPNql6eQZjYybK9USUGPtJaqqBK0oqrWyI2WyAJKCqKkSgA6sDVB6k0NqlQGfala5Fbr0gHY0vKmzak8Ny1yvbFpTp@fPw) by switching the format string.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 54 bytes

```ruby
->a{(?0*5..?9*5).select{|x|a.all?{|y|x=~/#{y*'.*'}/}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LCoMwEEX3@QpJobbBpnn6KFg/RFykoriwIGpBSdJft8QIXV3OzJm54@e1bm2@3Z5KXwqCJMZFhuQVT03f1LM2i1FY9X2hzWqW/Hs/6RWFGIX2bq3dSlBCzgiMApgwvgcnsIrcOBGOU8E8E7prlOwaJ9SPqT@jTPiQLhiXfst45jgT4rAp9dpRImS8l6aZ58SzTOP/9wpUuFF1p81shqAtZ/xWQ3B@1J0ap8oCsP0A)

Takes input as an arrray of character arrays.

Comment: Well done! You beat me by 25 bytes. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: No, as long as you have a valid answer, there's no need to delete it.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, 11 bytes

```
f<QyT^s`MT5
```

Takes input as a set of strings.
[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=f%3CQyT%5Es%60MT5&input=%7B%22123%22%2C%20%22124%22%2C%20%22125%22%2C%20%22235%22%7D&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
f<QyT^s`MT5
      s`MT      Take the digits as a string.
     ^    5     Take the Cartesian product with itself 5 times.
f   T           Filter the ones...
 <Qy            ... where the input is a subset of the power set.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>80</s> 81 bytes

```r
Reduce(intersect,lapply(gsub("",".*",scan(,"")),grep,substr(1e6:199999,2,6),v=T))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclZCoQwEEXRrUh9VclDSByghd6EuAGNhTSIhAxCrz7qhfN1QymTbtkp/86kIapLOBbvjz/vMa9MBGpqQnTLySASwR7U43kxBTY6jObzBotBcH1nkWJsWxnbPfrKtn25AQ)

Here’s a base R solution using regex. Writing this nested series of functions made me realise how much I’ve learned to appreciate the magrittr package!

Initially hadn’t read rules on input, so now reads from stdin (thanks @KirillL).

Thanks to @RobinRyder for saving a byte!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctRCkBAEIDhq2hKzWiSXfaBcgm5ALtDStp2UU6/@Ot7/ENKg7jLCm7HKSGKPXmfvN8fXOM1IwBDWQBHOx3IAES8BvEcffiGBSGvjAOuuvaP@O5HoqR0nSndfEyma5Ne)

Comment: @digEmAll it says it’s 82 bytes doesn’t it? You can’t use integers because of potential for leading zeroes in the input.

Comment: Sorry, I read the title and unconsciously I picked the minimum number without noticing that it was strikedthrough... and yes, sorry again you're right about the string input ;)

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##FclBCoQwEAXRq0ivuuUjJBpBwUvIXMCJjQgiIYkDnj46BW9VsZRZ18sr72fWmNRnHEsIx81bur5MBGpqQvLLySASwRY14H0pRzbqRjP8g0Uv@E0fkWJsWxnbvVxlW1ce "R – Try It Online") by generating the list of all passwords with substr(1e5:19999,2,6). If displaying the same solution multiple times is allowable, you can gain a further 3 bytes with `substr(1e5:2e5,2,6)` (will find `00000` twice).

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
9Żṗ5ŒPiⱮẠɗƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/y6O6HO6ebHp0UkPlo47qHuxacnH6s/f///9HRxjoK5joKJrE6CtEWQFpHwSg2FgA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=all -a`, 70 bytes

```perl
map{$t=sprintf'%05d',$_;(all{$t=~/$_/}map s//.*/gr,@F)&&say$t}0..99999
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBapcS2uKAoM68kTV3VwDRFXUcl3lojMScHJFGnrxKvXwtUpVCsr6@npZ9epOPgpqmmVpxYqVJSa6CnZwkC//8bGFsqWJqY/MsvKMnMzyv@r@trqmdgaACkfTKLS6ysQksyc2yBZv7XTQQA)

#### Old Approach:  [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, <s>80</s> 77 bytes

*Credit to @NahuelFouilleul for -2 bytes*

```perl
map{s||($t=0)x(5-y///c)|e;for$b(map s//.*/gr,@F){$t+=/$b/}$t-@F||say}0..99999
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saC6uKZGQ6XE1kCzQsNUt1JfXz9ZsybVOi2/SCVJAyivUKyvr6eln16k4@CmWa1Som2rr5KkX6tSouvgVlNTnFhZa6CnZwkC//8bGVsqWJqY/MsvKMnMzyv@r@trqmdgaPBfNxEA)

Comment: `$t+=/$b/` instead of `/$b/&&$t++`

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 53 bytes

```
~(`
.$*
m`^
G`
^
K`¶5+%`$$¶0"1"2"3"4"5"6"7"8"9¶
"
$$"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/v04jgUtPRYsrNyGOyz2BK47LO@HQNlNt1QQVlUPbDJQMlYyUjJVMlEyVzJTMlSyULA9t41LiUlFR@v/f2MiAy9zImMvc2AAA) Explanation:

```
~(`
```

After executing the script, take the result as a new script, and execute that, too.

```
.$*
```

Insert `.*` everywhere. This results in `.*3.*2.*0.*` although we only need `3.*2.*0`, not that it matters.

```
m`^
G`
```

Insert a `` G` `` at the start of each line. This turns it into a Retina Grep command.

```
^
K`¶5+%`$$¶0"1"2"3"4"5"6"7"8"9¶
"
$$"
```

Prefix two more Retina commands. The resulting script will therefore look something like this:

```
K`
```

Clear the buffer (which contains the original input).

```
5+
```

Repeat 5 times...

```
%`$
```

... append to each line...

```
0$"1$"2$"3$"4$"5$"6$"7$"8$"9
```

... the digit `0`, then a copy of the line, then the digit `1`, etc. until `9`. This means that after `n` loops you will have all `n`-digit numbers.

```
G`.*3.*2.*0.*
G`.*7.*2.*3.*
G`.*7.*3.*0.*
```

Filter out the possible numbers based on the input.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>79</s> 77 bytes

```ruby
->x{(0...1e5).map{|i|'%05d'%i}.select{|i|x.all?{|c|i=~/#{c.gsub('','.*')}/}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc/LTsMwEAXQPV9hCUWToOL6/VgEPqR00aYpihSkilJRlJhfD/E1m2PP9Vgef96OP8u5fVueX@5TLTjnsrcN/zhcpnmYqRL2RNWQ@LUf@@4rZ3d@GMfXae7mof3dPk4df7/ejjXRhvgTNWmbUlou7LzbkVaCNoy80li0oP3@oRx563Jmg1sz1ras@q6FX0smoYIaGmj/DXY1rPeZQ@IFlFBBDQ20AkqooIYGlh4HPQwCSqighgZa6ASUUEENDbSwdHoYYMx65OWtmI157zBJ@VGAMRuQxGyz/AE)

Input is an array of strings.

Here's a more readable version of the same code:

```ruby
def f(codes)
  (0...10**5).map{|i| '%05d'%i}.select do |i|
    codes.all? do |code|
      i =~ Regexp.new(code.chars.join('.*'))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: BTW, your approach can also be made shorter by switching to char array input, as in my version, and -2 more bytes by formatting the upper value as `1e5`, like [this](https://tio.run/##Xc/LTsMwEAXQPV9hCQW3Fbh@jR9IgQ8pXaQhFZGCVLUgihLz6yG@ZsXm2LozmrHPn4fv@Vi/zA9P13ElhRCqo7V4b07j1E@8kvTKqz6JSzd07UfOrqIZhudxaqe@/tneju2Giw1P25TSfGLH3Y4bLfk9414bHEbyfR7I7h7bt@Z82d@UNk8u1ym4f3VW16z6Wkm/lJiCGhpoIf0ZaDEss5hD4iVUUEMDLSQJFdTQQAtLj4MeBgkV1NBACwk6CRXU0EALCZZODwOMWY@87IrZmO8OLyk/CjBmA5KYXc@/)

Comment: @KirillL. Thanks for the -2 bytes. I won't change the input format because my answer would look too much like yours. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 52 bytes

```
(>,{;^:4~i.10)([#~]*/@e."2((#~3=+/"1)#:i.32)#"_ 1[)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdhPqxzHFYbxvT5FIwXfexP7uqvqnPpzjYMh4FVW2QrFi8TGDgETQlYBfXWl69eGICcGC/S4qZkz531O99SU9bcPr58fvju@fDkejk@P83i5/n72fPzhT3/8@sPj7z/99xd/fon3PzyX8@nx7Zv37377@VffPr@uj49v3rcvf/f56/L05uWH51af3rz@5ihvn959eHr1z@9//Nff//rNt/84vnw@3r4c3/7l@x@Px3fHZy@fPH7@8v7p@O6rt0@fPD6@fn59fvH8TXn66vHhePjk06enV69ePbR6HqO2Y7Tz4fjvRz20a9Er@/UL@x3XysNVMeKYUX/27mvlaHNcnNcbrlf/759XD2c5j3J9WjvLx59wvdB@oernn1GuvKXG9TeP2vKjz7lei7xeablfj/3qL3xKbetYER9VX2t75delKOXq8PHUyrVwre7/XKzb9VrY7yuuy7Z@dd@h88jjN8fDw9N1p47vjofIfoy5flX3/00zruqc/aM057hWjoIVGwbmT5wqd323Mk4sWLFhYJ5YsGLDwPs9HQfOEwtWbBiY2E8sWLFhYOL9zoET1@awfvdam2tfd0luo4lrc1pZw6w8Sh@P7NwP1/Us4n29H/6LBe@V66uxWbDivR6Y2HHgxLUZ3pnYceDEtdl0CUzsOHDi2qwSNgxM7Dhw4vKlOU@8r7fXxYL3SjuxYMV7PTCx48CJazO8M7HjwIlrs@kSmNhx4MTtVcy/mH8x/2L@xfyL@RfzL@ZfzL@YfzH/Yv7F/Iv5F/Mv5l/Mv5h/Mf9i/sX8i/kX8y/mX8y/mH8x/2L@V7QTC94rzZe@2Rx2tov3emBix4ET12Z4Z2LHgRN3tlp0LDreG2HRsehYdCztXg9M7Dhw4u5YdCw6Fh2LjkXHoqP5V/Ov5l/Nv5p/Nf9q/tX8q/lX86/mX82/mn81/2r@1fyr@Vfzr@Z/ffyJBSve64E2@LPjwIn785uNttl0ry8Gqi1qi9qitqgtaovaqraqrWr5Nj82raqtaqvaqraqNZNmJs1Mmpk0M2lm0sykmUkzk2YmLdSG2lBrSi3U3j9ooTbUhtpQm2pTbao12/sHsOX9Y6g21abaVNvVdrVdrTvSutqutqvtarvarnaoHWqHWvdxHw821Q61Q@1QO9ROtVPtVOvut6l2qp1qp9qpdqpdapfapfZ@ZpbapXapXWqX2rVrw1MUnoe4DxHuWrhr4a5Fu9d/Oj5gx4ETfZp7FKYd5hYmEFxCqtQxdbSTXA/@iQUr3usONDqmjqlj6pg6po6pY@qYOqaOqWPXseto17q@ZCcWrHivByZ2HDhxd@w6dh27jl3HrmPXceg4dLRDXl/oEwtWvNcDEzsOnLg7Dh2HjkPHoePQceg4dZw62o2vzePEghXv9cDEjgMn7o5Tx6nj1HHqOHWcOi4dl473zr90XDouHVe71wMTOw6cuDsuHZeOS8el49Jx7Y7Nr4lf9uL4fbHgvbK7NztwswM3O3CzAzc7cLMDNztwswM3O3CzAzc7cLMDNztwswM3O3Cz7zXfkea5bZ6l5v42M2/mEHI6e1w/mCcWvFd2zpAz5Aw5Q86QM@QMOUPOkDPkDDlDzpAz5Aw5Q86QM@QMOUPOkDPkTDmdjq6f9BML3is7Z8qZcqacKWfKmXKmnClnyplyppwpZ8qZcqacKWfKmXKmnClnyplydjmd365Dx4kF75Wds8vZ5exydjm7nF3OLmeXs8vZ5exydjm7nF3OLmeXs8vZ5exydjm7nF3OIacT5nUsOrHgvbJzDjmHnEPOIeeQc8g55BxyDjmHnEPOIeeQc8g55BxyDjmHnEPOIeeQc8g55XQGvg5uJxa8V3bOKeeUc8o55ZxyTjmnnFPOKeeUc8o55ZxyTjmnnFPOKeeUc8o55ZxyTjmXnPcpfcm55Fz1Xtk5l5xLziXnknPJueRcci45l5xLziXnknPJueRcci45l5xLziXnknPJuXbO6v8dqvN5Lff1Tludz6vzeXU@r87n1fm8Op9X5/PqfF6dz6vzeXU@r87n1fm8Op9X5/PqfF6dz6vzeXU@r87n1fm8Op9X5/PqfF6dz6sTcrWLVntUtQNU36/q6a2ejWryjV1j18p9ve0au8ausWvsGrvGrrFr7Bq7xq6xa@wau8ausWvsGrvGrrFr7Bq7xq6xa@wau8ausWvsGrvGrrFr7Bq7YBfsotzX2y7YBbtgF@yCXbALdsEu2AW7YBfsgl2wC3bBLtgFu2AX7IJdsAt2wS7YBbtgF@yCXbALdsEu2CW7ZJflvt52yS7ZJbtkl@ySXbJLdsku2SW7ZJfskl2yS3bJLtklu2SX7JJdskt2yS7ZJbtkl@ySXbJLdsmus@vsermvt11n19l1dp1dZ9fZdXadXWfX2XV2nV1n19l1dp1dZ9fZdXadXWfX2XV2nV1n19l1dp1dZ9fZdXadXWc32A12o9zX/smR3WA32A12g91gN9gNdoPdYDfYDXaD3WA32A12g91gN9gNdoPdYDfYDXaD3WA32A12g91gN9gNdoPdZDfZzXJfb7vJbrKb7Ca7yW6ym@wmu8luspvsJrvJbrKb7Ca7yW6ym@wmu8luspvsJrvJbrKb7Ca7yW6ym@wmu8lusVvsVrmvt91it9gtdovdYrfYLXaL3WK32C12i91it9gtdovdYrfYLXaL3WK32C12i91it9gtdovdYrfYLXaL3drtHz78Bw)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP 128 bytes

```php
for(;$i++<1e5;$k>$argc||print$s)for($k=0;$n=$argv[++$k];)preg_match("/$n[0].*$n[1].*$n[2]/",$s=sprintf("%05d
",$i-1))||$k=$argc;
```

or

```php
for(;$i<1e5;$i+=$k<$argc||print$s)for($k=0;$n=$argv[++$k];)if(!preg_match("/$n[0].*$n[1].*$n[2]/",$s=sprintf("%05d
",$i)))break;
```

take input from command line arguments. Run with `-nr` or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b914abb3a3b0adb98b54e1727d1f03652957c66c).

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 116 bytes

```cs
x=>{for(int i=0;i<1e5;){var s=$"{i++:D5}";if(x.All(t=>t.Aggregate(-6,(a,c)=>s.IndexOf(c,a<0?a+6:a+1))>0))Print(s);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc09a8MwFIXhPb/CiA662DFXdj5KZKkYuhQK7dYhZBCqZC4EBSTRGox/u9t66pTpLA/ntWlrEy29zXQLXcqRwnC@aK@WUenJ3yKnkAtSKKkTbi9h@jKxSOqBTVSWp@f9zCR5Ptb99cqz0rnuhyG6wWTHt4eKm8qC0ql@CZ9ufPPcVqbDJ1MeTqYUABoB3n@bmSeQ87zIjefBfZ8vE2sbZFXBjk27TotsBrn5iJTdKwXH4b897v7Q4665g1CshwLXwxbFPYtrbvkB)

```cs
// x: input list of strings
x=>{
  // generate all numbers under 100k
  for(int i=0;i<1e5;){
    // convert the current number to
    // a 5 digit string padded with 0's
    var s=$"{i++:D5}";
    // test all inputs against the 5 digit
    // string using an aggregate.
    // each step of the aggregate gets
    // the index of the next occurrence
    // of the current character starting
    // at the previously found character.
    // a negative index indicates error.
    if(x.All(t=>t
             .Aggregate(-6,(a,c)=>
               s.IndexOf(c,a<0?a+6:a+1)
             )>0))
      // output to STDOUT
      Print(s);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** fixed a bug where the same character was counted more than once. For example, if `000` was logged, the function used to return all passwords containing a single `0`.

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, 21 bytes

```
1e5o ù'0 f@e_XèZË+".*
```

[Try it!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=MWU1byD5JzAgZkBlX1joWssrIi4q&input=WyI3NTYiLCAiNTg2Il0KLVE=)

```
1e5o ù'0 f@e_XèZË+".*    # full program

1e5o                     # generate numbers under 100k
     ù'0                 # left pad with 0's
         f@              # filter array
           e_            # check every element of input array
             Xè          # X is the number to be tested.
                         # test it against a regex.
               ZË+".*    # the regex is an element from the input array
                         # with wildcards injected between each character
```

-2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy!

Comment: less useless variables: `1e5o ù'0 fA{Ue@AèX®+".*` :P

Comment: also 23: `1e5o ù'0 fA{Ue@AèX¬q".*`

Comment: [21 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=MWU1byD5JzAgZkBlX1joWssrIi4q&input=WyI3NTYiLCAiNTg2Il0KLVE=)

Comment: Interesting... I didn't realize `return X,Y,Z` would pick the last term. Thanks for the tips :)

Comment: @dana; Yup, that's a feature of JavaScript: https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@1@jQqdS09auuii1pLQoTwHIq/2fnJ9XnJ@TqpeTn66RpmGgY6ip@R8A

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 113 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Data.List
$l=[s\\s<-iter 5(\p=[[c:e]\\e<-p,c<-['0'..'9']])[[]]|all(flip any(subsequences s)o(==))l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY2xCsIwFAB3vyKDkBbaIi0iSrPpIHQQHF8yPGMqgZe0Nqkg@O1GQbe7W06TQZ/ccJ3JMIfWJ@vGYYrsHK8H/yj2GLHqbIiLJQkIUoa2tNFMbJ3JUQDonVFSmrYcC92WwFe8qviWK5UDKPVCoqwnOzL0zyzMl2Dus/HaBBbyIRMiz0mlc8TvULAlA@BNveKqYMA3dfOH5ltUeuue8BZSeezS/unRWf2TE2Hsh8l9AA)

Answer (score 1):

### K 67 bytes

```
{n@&{&/y in\:x@/:&:'a@&3=+/'a:(5#2)\:'!32}[;x]'n:{"0"^-5$$x}'!_1e5}
```

K has a (very) primitive regex capability, so i tried a different approach.

{...} defines a lambda. Use example: `{...}("320";"723";"730")`

returns `("37230";"72320";"73203";"73230")`

- `n` is the list of integers in range 0..9999 as 0-padded strings

  - `_1e5` applies floor to float 1e5 (scientific notation) -> generates integer 100000
  - `!_1e5` generates integer-list 0..99999
  - `{..}'!_1e5` applies lambda to each value in 0..99999
  - `$x` transform argument x (implicit arg) to string
  - `-5$$x` right adjust string $x to a field of size 5 (ex. `-5$$12` generates `"   12"`
  - `"0"^string` replaces blanks with "0" char, so `"0"^-5$$12` generates `"00012"`
- `a` is the list of integers in the range 0..31 as 5-bit values

  - `!32` generate values 0..31
  - `(5#2)` repeat 2 five times (list 2 2 2 2 2)
  - `(5#2)\:'!32` generates 5-bit values (2-base five-times) for each value in range 0..31
- we filter the values of a with exactly 3 ones. That values are all the combinations (places) where pattern can be located: `11100 11010 11001 10110 10101 10011 01110 01101 01011 00111`. Ex. for "abc" pattern we have equivalence with regexs `abc?? ab?c? ab??c a?bc? a?b?c a??bc ?abc? ?ab?c ?a?bc ??abc?`

  - `+\'a` calculates sum of each binary representation (number of ones)
  - `3=+\'a` generates list of booleans (if each value in a has exactly 3 ones)
  - `a@&3=+\'a` reads as "a at where 3=+\'a is true"
- generate list of indexes for previous places: `(0 1 2; 0 1 3; 0 1 4; 0 2 3; 0 2 4; 0 3 4; 1 2 3; 1 2 4; 1 3 4; 2 3 4)` and the possible entered-values for a password (x)

  - `&:'` reads as "where each", applies to list of binary-coded integers, and calculates indexes of each 1-bit
  - `x@/:` applies password x to each elem of the list of indexes (generates all possible entered values)
- Determines if all patterns are located in the list of all possible entered values

  - `y` is the arg that represent list of patterns
  - `y in\:` reads as each value of y in the list at the right
  - `&/` is "and over". `&/y in\:..` returns true iff all patterns in y are locates at the list ..
- finally, return each string in n at every index that makes lambda true

  - `n@&{..}` reads as "n at where lambda {..} returns true"

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utilities, <s>54</s> <s>53</s> 51 bytes

```bash
sed 's/./&.*/g;s/ \|^/|grep /g;s//seq -w 0 99999/e'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7dCoJAEIXv9ynORRQEtj@zulpP0FUvIEHlkILYzyrd@O62ShF5YAbmO4fDnE@@HF5lVTOefCpQVw0LoLiFBfClvGHf3Lt2i8XH@tBD1454Al3juUUU/dwpjB754LnAysuNXG7W8rrzEnl/lP31yXdMt/T8QPSCQjZK8mr41kyPNDyQUXCG4EgJchapNUJpBa0IpDS@EjqEtLFhYhiKIQxlyKzFn4TWOkTUjNo4gUuzGXWBxmkybzAk3g)

*Thanks to @user41805 for 1 byte off, and now an additional 2 bytes off.*

Input: Space-separated integers on stdin.

Output: On stdout, one possible password per line.

Comment: Putting everything inside sed (and eval'ing using sed's `e`) seems to save at least a byte.

Comment: @user41805 Thanks for the idea, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @user41805  Yes, it saved a byte.

Comment: `e` can also be passed as a flag to the `s` command. Additionally, you can make use of this tip https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/167295 to save a byte

Comment: @user41805 Thanks -- that's 2 more bytes shaved off.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>119</s> 102 bytes

```python
lambda l:['%05d'%n for n in range(10**5)if all(map(lambda x:''in[x:=x[x[:1]==c:]for c in'%05d'%n],l))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzLjsIgFIbX9inYGMC44HCxLQlP0umC0XYkQSS1aufpO4fG2fz58t/y73y9J9XkaR3d1xr97fviSbQd3QtzoftExvtEEgmJTD79DAzE4WB4GImPkd18Zp/JYikNqVusW7qls9A7d7Z9GZ9x/P/WHyPn/fq@hjgQsNUuuhgeMxtePrKQ8nNmnPNql6eQZjYybK9USUGPtJaqqBK0oqrWyI2WyAJKCqKkSgA6sDVB6k0NqlQGfala5Fbr0gHY0vKmzak8Ny1yvbFpTp@fPw)

This was based off of [xnor's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180285/75323) and @Bubbler helped me golf it by 17 bytes ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <sup><s>97</s></sup> 96 bytes

```python
lambda l:[s for n in range(10**5)if(s:='%05d'%n,t:={''},[t:=t|{x+c for x in t}for c in s])!=t>l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LTsMwEEX3fIVZVLZLFh4/mgcyP1K6CG3SWjJulBgoCvn2YE8l2FzdMz4zHr7j5RpUNYxrb19X376/nVrim/1E@utIAnGBjG04dwzEdmu469nUWLoR5kQ3oYiNnSldin0q8We@PR1x7ZbX4pLrMdfpwB9tfPGH9evifEeg8cSS7rP1zIXhIzLOn8kwuhBZz/w/8HWmSgpa0FKqnErQ5SHNSp2o0hJJQDZAZEMJwBmgD1JjmpRSGXyRqk5Ua333ANC439Vml3@paqQSyVS7v4vLLw)

-1 byte thanks to @xnor.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 96 bytes

```python
lambda l,d='%05d':[d%n for n in range(10**5)if reduce(lambda t,c:t|{x+c for x in t},d%n,{''})>l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7LboMwFET3@Yq7iQwpCz/Do6I/0laIgp1YMgZZRk1F@XZqTJXNSGfuzNjTj7@Plm7KjQM0jZr97GTTgB6m0XmYnLY@uLbzerQnVX9sph2@@hZM1tfojEWPqvf@bEGNDixoC661N5kQfLmIVCtwsp87mfy3fNZV/nd5vHSx8NgLfs3CQLYgtKZv5nP7vmsjgVQG6nCeZp@kr8dHEpWY9AnptiBGMcpQTtmuDKP1FLycByo4jYTJniB4TzBMokdinlAeVQSlTMQLZWWgkvMjR0hMHLtcXPdXijJSHkkU1@fi@gc)

Alternative forms of [xnor's Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180285/78410).

Comment: This is nice, I didn't expect lambda versions get so close. Of course the `1e5` gives the program an advantage. I got a byte off the 3.8 one: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LTsMwEEX3fIVZVLZLFh4/mgcyP1K6CG3SWjJulBgoCvn2YE8l2FzdMz4zHr7j5RpUNYxrb19X376/nVrim/1E@utIAnGBjG04dwzEdmu469nUWLoR5kQ3oYiNnSldin0q8We@PR1x7ZbX4pLrMdfpwB9tfPGH9evifEeg8cSS7rP1zIXhIzLOn8kwuhBZz/w/8HWmSgpa0FKqnErQ5SHNSp2o0hJJQDZAZEMJwBmgD1JjmpRSGXyRqk5Ua333ANC439Vml3@paqQSyVS7v4vLLw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online"). Annoyingly, using `<` for `!=` makes Python 3 complain, and we can't make the tuple a set.

Comment: Here's a variant of the 96: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3LbsMgEEX3/Qq6iMBJFgyP@BHRH3G9cBO7QaLEskmbyvW3uzCR2s3VPcOZYfgOl6uXxTCuvXldXfvxdm6Jq@qJ9NeReGI9GVv/3jHg263ObF9PlaEbrs904/ehMjOlS7OrYws/8313wr172gtLqqdUp@bZhBfXrF8X6zoClSOGdJ@tY9YPt8Cy7EiG0frAeub@IVtnKgWne5oLmVJyujzFWa4iFUogcUgG8GRIDjgD9EEoTB1TSI0vQpaRSqUeHgAaj7tKH9IvRYmUI@ni8Hdx@QU "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") I feel like it should possible to stick the walrus assignments somewhere shorter, but I'm not seeing how. I hope you have some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

## C(GCC) <s>222</s> 214 bytes

-8 bytes ceilingcat

```
#define C(p)*f-p||++f;
#define I(x,y)x>9&&++y,x%=10;
a,b,c,d,e,g,**h,*f;z(int**H){for(a=0;g=a<10;){for(h=H;*h;g&=f>*h+++2){f=*h;C(a)C(b)C(c)C(d)C(e)}g&&printf("%d%d%d%d%d,",a,b,c,d,e);e++;I(e,d)I(d,c)I(c,b)I(b,a)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU3LTsMwELznK6yiRmt7IyVFCCLjXnJpvqHi4PiR5ECICoe0ab49LIYihHZnpJ2Z3bVZa@263jkf@sGzCkYuQjZer1IGldzkGiY882lfpqmUZ5y2ushVYrBBiw49tihEhyKoC/TDhxAHPoe3Exidq1abZwp/C50@KNGpNtVhLzop5Y50TUoFhlfQECzBETxf2jQdT3QvwGbrboUb/P3LlZdS1eDR8RocWmKLDXGDhi/LSsvs1fQDcDYnjH2NHVFxfHhhms0llviIWUG9qD/@7sd/wvy/L2Lg/XgfA/EYxhXMY@QC0ecqWdZP)

Calling code

```
int main() {
  int hint1[5] = {9,9,7,-1,-1};
  int hint2[5] = {8,0,7,-1,-1};
  int* hints[3] = {hint1,hint2,0};
  z(hints);
}
```

Output

```
80997,89097,89907,98097,98907,99807,
```

Comment: [211 bytes](https://tio.run/##XU3LTsMwELznK6yiRmt7KyVFCCLjXnJpvqHi4PgR50CICoe0Ub49LIYihHZnpJ2Z3bW7ztp1vXM@9INnNYw8SC2C1qPKbmoDE174RerpUOG01WWhMoMtWnTosUMhIoqgrtAPH0Ic@RzezmB0oTptnin8LUR9VCKqLtfhIKKUck@6JqUGw2toCZbgCJ4vXZ6PZ7oXYLN1t8IN/v7lykupGvDoeAMOLbHFlrhFw5dlpWX2avoBOJszxr7GSFSeHl6YZnOFFT7irqRe1B9//@M/YfHfFynwfrpPgXQM0woWKXKF5HOVLesn "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

The function takes an array of strings as input and prints each possible code on separate lines.

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 122 bytes

```php
function a($n){for(;$x++<1e5;){foreach($n as$a)if(!preg_match("/$a[0].*$a[1].*$a[2]/",$x))continue 2;printf("%05d
",$x);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDdioMwFITvfYqzIQVtZZvfqqSwD@KGJbi69aIxWAuF4rPbNKllbzKcbyYZctzJLccv58/uapupHyyYFNvs3g1jqvBttzvSVqowt6Y5eQ/MBZus79IPN7Z/P2czeYz22NREf2690ChM71GOb1nWDHbq7bUFptzY26lL0YbI3yS4ap6X9e06AagRZwTlgArGg3CCdB6NQjxJKdhKCA1RSkKUE7oaNF6mTESRXhiXL5fx6okrId55SmPwXSbkIdSX1UqKSGR5@N@iARLtVwJ@aXD3OHwR0LdFyk9hmSqZlwc)

Answer (score 0):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) -E, <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```
s/./&.*/g;s/ |^/|grep /g;s//seq -w 0 99999/e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfT19NT0s/3bpYX6EmTr8mvSi1QAHM1S9OLVTQLVcwULAEAf3U//@NjQwUzI2MFcyNDf7lF5Rk5ucV/9d1BQA)

Input: Space-separated integers on stdin.

Output: On stdout, one possible password per line.

This is from my bash answer, which had 3 bytes off thanks to @user41805.