# caN it be acrOnymised?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

The Typical Way to Make an Acronym Out of a Phrase Is to Take the First Letter of Each Word: `TTWMAOPITFLEW`. howeveR, sometimEs, you can make an acronym of random leTters In a seNtence such As like this: `RETINA`. The only condition is that the letters have to be in the correct order. For instance:

- `LORD` can be acronymised from `Hello World`: `heLlO woRlD`
- `LEOD` cannot be acronymised from `Hello World`, as no `l`s are before `e`

Your task is to take two strings as input as to determine if one can be acronymised into the other.

The first input, the phrase, will only contain letters (`A-Z` or `a-z`) and spaces, and the second input, the acronym, will only contain letters (`A-Z` or `a-z`). The acronym will always be shorter, or of equal size, to the phrase, and both the acronym and the phrase will be, at minimum, 1 letter long. You may choose which case (upper or lower) you want the inputs to be.

You may choose any two values to represent `true` and `false`, as long as those values are consistent.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Examples

```
HELLO WORLD, LORD -> true
CODE GOLF AND CODING CHALLENGES, DANGLE -> true
SANDBOX FOR PROPOSED CHALLENGES, CODE -> false
HELLO WORLD, LLLD -> true
HELLO WORLD, LLDL -> false
NEW YORK POLICE DEPARTMENT, NOODLE -> false
MASSACHUSETTS INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY, MUTTON -> true
BOB, BOB -> true
PRESIDENT OF THE UNITED STATES, I -> true
```

Comment: [Deleted Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17989/66833)

Comment: PRESIDENT OF THE UNITED STATES, I -> true , doesn't have to contain at least one letter from every word?

Comment: @AZTECCO *The only condition is that the letters have to be in the correct order.*

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5529/is-string-x-a-subsequence-of-string-y/181235) - someone else can hammer closed if I am correct.

Comment: Having read through this and the proposed duplicate I am firmly of the opinion answers are transferable in either direction.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Agreed, some of the answers are even identical.

Comment: This question can be corrected following Wikipedia definitions.. Acronyms result from a word formation process known as blending, in which parts of two or more words are combined to form a new word.   Seems more conforming than the specifications of this question to me. As I said before.

Comment: @AZTECCO with 23 answers here it would probably be better to start a new question instead of fixing this one up.

Comment: Yes for sure @Jonathan, agreed.

Comment: There is no need to downvote this challenge simply for being a duplicate. If the fact that this is a duplicate wasn't caught in the Sandbox, there's nothing I could've done to prevent this being a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 1 byte

```
⊇
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FX@///Ss7@Lq4K7v4@bgqOfi4KQJ6nn7uCs4ejj4@rn7trsNJ/JRdHP3cfVyUA)

Comment: Sometimes golfing is simply finding the right language for the job. :)

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>46</s> <s>39</s> <s>38</s> 35 bytes

```java
a->b->a.matches(b.replace("",".*"))
```

-7 bytes thanks to *@tsh*.
-1 byte thanks to *@NahuelFouilleul*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jVLNbqMwEL7nKUY@wSbxA7S7kQh2AK3jQdhRt6p6MIRsyRJAxalUrfrsqZMg7dJD1Ys99vcznzXemxcz32//nIra9D2sTdX8nQD01tiqgL1D6dFWNd0dm8JWbUNXQ/Fd2eeq@T37EmfZtnVpmsUCdvDjZOaLfL4w9GBs8VT2Xk6fy642RekRMiP0G/H90@3EpeiOee1SDGFe2moLBxfQu9o@PILxz2EBbNlbj8RcCIQ7zARzPgIzRvzb//AQGYcIxQoCycCdEhlBGAdCcBlx5TQskJHgY5Vy5CX@ghVmkGaYouJsrDr7jjUfkgjBPseZGOOS38E9Zj8hRZGEHBhPg0yvudSOLhHZx5DrQKkgjDeKa60gkUoneqM54Ao0D2OJAqN7p11vtEY51i5x6ZDzOrpOM64S5lpeTGIOG5lo93SlA315dnLlv03@/ZfLiC7y64jAzIYiHyalXntbHmh7tLRzgK0bz0wJmGYLZJpPyY3bdtR0Xf3qGX8ocn/o9HZ6Bw)

**Explanation:**

```java
a->b->         // Method with two String parameters and boolean return-type
  a.matches(   //  Check if the first input matches the regex:
   b           //   The second input,
    .replace("",".*"))
               //   where every character is surrounded with ".*"
```

*For example:*

```java
a="HELLO WORLD"
b="LORD"
```

Will do the check:

```java
"HELLO WORLD".matches("^.*L.*O.*R.*D.*$")
```

(The `^...$` will add the `String#matches` builtin implicitly, since it will always try to match the entire String.)

Comment: Will replacing "|" by ".*" work?

Comment: @tsh I don't think so. "_nothing or L or O or R or D or nothing_" isn't exactly correct if I do that replacement, whereas the current regex is "_any-character(s) L any-character(s) O any-character(s) R any-character(s) D any-character(s)_"

Comment: I meant `a->b->a.matches(b.replaceAll("|",".*"))`

Comment: @tsh Oh, yes, that indeed works. That's pretty ingenious, thanks! I was a bit confused when I misinterpret your first comment, since you definitely already knew what I was stating. ;)

Comment: why not `replaceAll("",".*")`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Ah, indeed. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 47 bytes

```c
f(a,b)char*a,*b;{a=!*b||*a&&f(a+1,b+(*a==*b));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFNU4MwEIbv/IqVmXb46th6RZyhJAXGNMuQMLWDHABFOdg6bU@2/e2Ygh7qeEmyb553N7upJ2913XWNUTqVWb@XO6t0rMo9lt6NVZ1OVjkeqzt75lS2YZWeZ1Wm6Z67j7LdGOZR6x2HvMjvCu@oHfWIMoawwpQR3dEZpkQ/O0oPkFAIkS3A5wRUFPMQgshnjPKQCsUSn4eMDrRQ0ByfYIEpJCkmKCi5pi/5BvZPRcbI/zphg87pCtaYPkKCLA4oEJr4qVxSLhXGEcnvI5a@EH4QZYJKKSDmQsYykxRwAZIGEUeG4Vp5lpmUyAfPHOdKuax9mKRUxESl7k0RhYzHUrUipC/7NmL9rJ1drdnujHZzgNabuu39vv163TbGwbz9OfVDNt3WttXEP3eKbAx9tHdGe5g8wOjleaM7h7wt8mkx7LPCUf5rRX2bpop13w)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
æIå
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8DLPw0v///dw9fHxVwj3D/Jx4fLxD3IBAA)

```
æ              # power set of the first input
 I             # second input
  å            # does a contain b?
               # implicit output
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda s,a:re.search('.*'.join(a),s)>0
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBNS8NAEIbv/RUDHtJKDeJRsLDNTpLF6U7YnVALXqKmtNIvknjw18dEUUptT8uw7/POwxw@m9V@d9cuH57bTbF9eSugHhf3VRnWZVG9roZBeB2E7/v1bliMxvVocjtYbw/7qoGqbA/VetfAchikSMQwZ0c6GENA7HQwgiu4mUBTfZSDv2DEGiFhikFZDd1kbAJRqojQJuh7WCubEJ7HfUdN@QlidpA5ztijPsH7Db/wstjUR/SpJdEFy39BTRcqLc5hwe4RMiYTIWjMlJMZWulBy6zpks1Mea@iNPco4sFYL0ZyQeAYBKPUMnGy6FtmuQjb86ZTnvaR/jn7nzn0Rnc637UpQm6NdDfzouTnXuYYbL8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes

Full program. Prompts for phrase, then acronym.

```apl
0∊⊃(⍳⍨↓⊢)/⍞,⊂⌽0,⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU@9SsRAEO73KaZUOPFeYbM7SRYnO2F3wnnlgWBzYFpbBT2CqewtrOytfZl9kbgXuHCFDgzMx/czM7t@f3X3uNs/3E/p8NpP63QY0vB8kcbvNH6ll/c0fF5ep/FjlYan9PazXuX5KJ1grl7VSMSw4UBWEQerToRhi1AxlaC9hYycr8DUmgh9hVFZ7SvCRR6zquBbKDlAG7jliPZcfoxTfy4lsv8QlhbC4wa2HG6gZXIGwWKrgzToRXlme3ZIo2PUpu4iikRwPoqTThC4BEFTeyautqrpRNgvpoKLuU@4DRidzemzrUbovJP8UBQt@Rn3Cw)

`⍞` prompt for phrase
  `"HELLO WORLD"`
  `"HELLO WORLD"`

`0,` prepend a zero
  `[0,'H','E','L','L','O',' ','W','O','R','L','D']`
  `[0,'H','E','L','L','O',' ','W','O','R','L','D']`

`⌽` reverse
  `['D','L','R','O','W',' ','O','L','L','E','H',0]`
  `['D','L','R','O','W',' ','O','L','L','E','H',0]`

`⊂` enclose (to treat as a whole)
  `[['D','L','R','O','W',' ','O','L','L','E','H',0]]`
  `[['D','L','R','O','W',' ','O','L','L','E','H',0]]`

`⍞,` prepend the prompted-for acronym:
  `['L','L','L','D',['D','L','R','O','W',' ','O','L','L','E','H',0]]`
  `['L','L','D','L',['D','L','R','O','W',' ','O','L','L','E','H',0]]`

`(`…`)/` reduce that list by the following tacit function:

`⍳⍨` the **ɩ**ndex of the first occurrence in the phrase (will return 1 + phrase length if unfound)

`↓⊢` drop that many characters from the phrase

We then use the shortened phrase to look for the next letter. If at any point a letter is unfound, we'll drop everything, including the final zero. This means that if our acronym is good, we'll still have a zero left.
  `[0]`
  `[]`

`⊃` disclose (because the reduction reduced the number of dimensions from 1 to 0)

`0∊` is zero a member thereof?

Comment: Looks like APL does not have the "lists must be homogenous in both type and length" constraint that J has.  Here the list we're reducing appears to mix characters and a list (the final element).  In J you'd need to use boxes for that kind of mixing.

Comment: @Jonah That is correct. We also have 0 and characters in the same vector here.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 21 bytes

```
<@[e.]<@#~2#:@i.@^#@]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/bRyiU/VibRyU64yUrRwy9RzilB1i/2tycaUmZ@QrGCrYKqj7@Ae5qCukKah7uPr4@CuE@wf5uKgjy/v44JI3gMi7@ODT7@TvBJYG0QhhDR0rdU91TZCEo5Ozp4urs/p/AA)

Note: Some of the longer test cases omitted because they this solution is O(2^n).  They would pass with infinite memory.

Explanation: We create all 2 ^ (length of haystack) possible substrings, and check if the needle is an element of that list.

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 5 bytes

```
$z@$Ė
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/X6XKQeXItP//PVx9fPwVwv2DfFy4fHxcfAA)

Powerset approach.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 26 bytes

Port of [Kevin's Java solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190420/58974) so please `+1` him, too.

Takes the string as a string via parameter `s` and the acronym as a character array via parameter `a`. Outputs `false` for `true` and `true` for `false`.

```
s=>a=>!s.match(a.join`.*`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHRTsJAEHzWr1j6YitYvqAkpbe0jcdt07sGSSXhgkUh2BIO/X28QlRQ7uE2m52Zneys9ac2i91qu3@om5fqsAwOJhjoYNAx/rveL95c7a@bVT337@feYdHUptlU/qZ5dctbKJ0EOSeYUM6Z03M45cyZ9W7s6/dhv/uoWkxEDCEmPoJQMLBdKmKIkpBzFDFKy2OhiDkemWc8aeFDeoIR5ZDllJFEdslrlb9ZS70x1RVLnF@x9BfD@C/mR0jgBKaUP0JGPI0QGGZhrsYolOUIIsb/Lx@HUoZRUkhUSkIqpEpVofBOAo1AYZQI4hRPrcC4UIpEK3Dma0hDO2r/k50L01mOMmV2/VErQShEquxJpArV8RzpxQVnNr@t65amp2deMDBdB7rgdLWtga2dpWs8t/R93469U8bPtc34Cw) (Footer reverses output for easier verification)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://www.python.org/), <s>89</s> 68 bytes

-21 bytes thanks to AdmBorkBork

```
def a(b,c):
    for i in b:
        if i==c[:1]:
            c=c[1:]
    return len(c)==0
```

Takes input as a(string, acronym). [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBa4NAEIXP5lcM9qKQQkNvAQsbd6JLNzuyu5KGkkNilQrBBGsO/fXWbaC0aTzNPHjfm8ecPrv3Y/PY929lBbtgPy3C@cSrji3UUDewH4RXV1BHUfE6n22d9Iphn823E68tu3PbwKFsgiKMoof@1NZNF@wCP0UpCdakJfen4EvS3A9DuIP7J@jaczn5ccbEERKSS2CKw6CESiBOmZSoEjSO5kwlEkd4M2ALeoElacg0ZWSQX/HuxA9d7Q4fv/DrolKOFf3n5PLivJGqcA0b0s@QkRQxAseMabtCZR2qiLgcbbRixrA4zQ1aa0AoY4XNLQItwWKcKpKUbFzMKreW1EjbBS2cx43bhkyjEXxo9B2cIuRK2OF1xjJ7eZv4Q/Zf)

Comment: Welcome to CodeGolf.SE! I'm not an expert in Python, but I think you can use tabs instead of spaces to save a bunch of bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBa4NAEIXP5lcM9qKQQkNvAQsbd6JLNzuyu5KGkkNilQrBBGsO/fXWbaC0aTzNPHjfm8ecPrv3Y/PY929lBbtgPy3C@cSrji3UUDewH4RXV1BHUfE6n22d9Iphn823E68tu3PbwKFsgiKMoof@1NZNF@wCP0UpCdakJfen4EvS3A9DuIP7J@jaczn5ccbEERKSS2CKw6CESiBOmZSoEjSO5kwlEkd4M2ALeoElacg0ZWSQX/HuxA9d7Q4fv/DrolKOFf3n5PLivJGqcA0b0s@QkRQxAseMabtCZR2qiLgcbbRixrA4zQ1aa0AoY4XNLQItwWKcKpKUbFzMKreW1EjbBS2cx43bhkyjEXxo9B2cIuRK2OF1xjJ7eZv4Q/Zf "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: AdmBorkBork, I didn't seem to be able to type tabs in the answer box, and I forgot copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

```
à øV
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4CD4Vg&input=IkhFTExPIFdPUkxEIgoiTE9SRCI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,t:(t[:1]in{*s}and f(s[s.find(t[0]):],t[1:]))**len(t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ldFBS8MwFAfwu5/iwQ5txxCHt4KHrHlrg1leaVLmGD1UtuJg1rHGg4ifvWYTdEZ0mEMgPPJ7/5fsXuzDU3vd983Ntn68X9XQjWwc2mU8rjbt67B7q9sVNGG37C6bTbtylasqiquRXY7jKoqGw@26DW3U7/ab1oZNGGQoJcGcCsmDUSCp4EEUwV9rAHb/vL74FBLiCCnJKTDFwZ2ESiHJmJSoUtRO5UylEr9cX9Du4oTuYEoF5AXlpJF/Fw49TnMNoKm33QnhjSHlv8fwBS7PC14IhXNYUHELOUmRIHDMWWFmqIwTFRGX6Jk/iBnTmiVZqdEYDUJpI0xpEGgKBpNMkaR04bRZaQypg@bPMaGJqx/2M/F/fYm8QC24S33smiGUShj3I9owc/wN4dMfQv8O)

Recursive function. Will check for each letter in the acronym `t`, whether it is found in the string `s`. If it is, the function is called recursively with the part of the string *after* the current test character `t[0]` as the new input string `s`.

When the test character is *not* found, the final evaluation result (which at that point is always `0`) is raised to the power of the length of the remaining test string `t`. Since `0**0 == 1` and `0**x == 0` for any `x > 0`, the function returns `1` when all test characters have been found in order and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [C#](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/), 152 bytes

```
public class P{public static void Main(string[]a){int q=0;int e=a[1].Length;foreach(char c in a[0])if(q!=e&&c==a[1][q])q++;System.Console.Write(q==e);}}
```

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AO0np4)

Comment: The "Try Online" link 404s for me. Have you tried the fairly conventional website https://tio.run? I haven't read through your code completely, but you can almost certainly declare q and e together, use `var` instead of `char`, use `&` instead of `&&`, make the submission a lambda expression (`(a,b)=>{...}` or even `a=>b=>{...}`), and use the [Visual C# Interactive compiler](https://tio.run/#cs-csi) (that allows you to implicitly use System and some other namespaces, use `Print()` and multiple similar awesome things).

Comment: Whooops fixed the link. And as to the C# interactive compiler: I simply don't want to use it because I just like my code to be full programs.

Comment: In the upcoming threads I will use tio.run for simplicity sake.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
äΦv>
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=84e8763e&i=%22LORD%22+%22HELLO+WORLD%22&a=1)

Comment: This breaks the rule that the outputs must be consistent

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Updated. Applying `!!` which will return `1` for true and `0` for false.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
eŒP}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/16KSA2v////v4uPj893D18fFXCPcP8nEBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 35 bytes

```sh
[[ $1 = *${~${(j:*:)${(s::)2}}}* ]]
```

Outputs via exit code. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzBCoJAAETv@xVzWFgVPNTRiDBdLRBX9BKEB2kXNBYXNDIS@3XTbp2GN2@Yd1/PQ91ohU5VErpp1Q7SEPWsNHr1gOuCri2xfvSar1fQDfZw6Piho3X3HM9esvc8eztNk4OynG2ibrUBPRBpWjWzWmltMJhOSwZtOklYIEKOWCQR/DTEQuc0RnDyk4SnMS8YQj@NE05YsfijuCASObJcZKLg4d9wfSJf)

```sh
[[ $1 = *${~${(j:*:)${(s::)2}}}* ]]
                    ${     2}        # second parameter
                    ${(s::) }        # split into characters
            ${(j:*:)         }       # join with *
         ${~                  }      # enable globbing
        *${~${(j:*:)${(s::)2}}}*     # *A*C*R*O*N*Y*M*
[[ $1 =                           ]] # does it match the first parameter?
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 50 bytes

```javascript
h=>n=>[...n].reduce((a,l)=>a+1?h.indexOf(l,a):a,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9Bb4JAEIXP5VdMOUGKpF5tsEF2BdJ1h7BrrGl6ILJWK0UjtKlp@tvpUqOYHnqazLz3zZt5zT6yarFf7@petVvnav@2LTfq0BSqhlpVNXhgrbJDVWeLjQOlUnmhbPCG8GVcLbZltS2UW2xfLjymY56MuhnoZnlWbeu04dqDXt82vg2jTVrqmGblDUtv@OS6bvns7lX@vlCWlTmF7Q2zm/79yl2XufrEpVU4mT3InFu7aS@0zIgyhjDDlBGdZjJMiWnfGUcxQEIhRDYGnxPQXcxDCCKfMcpDKlqA@DxktEOEdo7wEcaYQpJigoKSP0i7tQP@HsAY@UckrBM5ncEc0wdIkMUBBUITP5UTymXr5Yjk8rCJL4QfRFNBpRQQcyFjOZUUcAySBhFHhuG8BSdTKZF34AhH7bgt51mSUhETnfSLRxSmPJb6USF9eXwy1ubmBw)

take input as `f(haystack)(needle)`

```js
h=>n=>                                             // inputs
      [...n]                                       // transform n from string to array of char
            .reduce((a,l)=>                    ,0) // for each letter change the value of a, (a starting at 0)
                           a+1?h.indexOf(l,a):a    // if a === -1 keep it else replace it by the position of the letter l in the haystack h starting from position of previous letter
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 88 bytes

```
	T =INPUT
S	T LEN(1) . X REM . T	:F(M)
	M =M ARB X	:(S)
M	INPUT M	:F(END)
	OUTPUT =1
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/nzNEwdbTLyA0hCsYyPRx9dMw1FTQU4hQCHL1BdIhnFZuGr6aXJy@Cra@Co5BTgoRnFYawZpcvpxgXQq@IAWufi5AJf6hISARW0MuIP//fx//IBcuD1cfH3@FcP8gHxcA)

Prints 1 for Acronymizable, and does nothing for not.

```
	T =INPUT			;* read in the Target
S	T LEN(1) . X REM . T	:F(M)	;* extract the first letter of T
					;* and when T is empty, goto M
	M =M ARB X	:(S)		;* create a PATTERN: M, ARBitrary match, X
					;* then goto S
M	INPUT M	:F(END)			;* if M doesn't match the input, end
	OUTPUT =1			;* else print 1
END
```

Answer (score 1):

## Emacs Lisp, 52 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(a b)(string-match(mapconcat'string b".*")a))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
}Ey
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v9a18v9/JQ9XHx9/hXD/IB8XJS4lH/8gFyUA)

Comment: Somehow Pyth is still managing to beat Jelly, after all these years

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 40 bytes

```
r@(a:c)#(b:d)|a==b=c#d|1>0=r#d
x#y=x==""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFRa4MwFIWf56@4xD0o7WB7LURmTaqymCsm0pVtjGgLK2u7oh100P/uYit7KIw8nOSe7@Tmkg/Tfq42m65rHj0zqX3XqyZL/2QorWjtLk8PwT1t3KVzdH/okVJCutq0qxYovHgk4UIgzLEQjIyBCCwY8cfOjUciZBxiFDMIJQN7SmUMURIKwWXMVU@zUMaCD7yy2BSfYYYF5AXmqDi74vsrB/q6rxDsP4eJwZF8DgssniBHkUYcGM/DQmdc6h6UiOzvMVmoVBglpeJaK0il0qkuNQecgeZRIlFgvOhTWak1yiE1xWlf6@VSyAuuUmYbnIMJh1Km2o6ldKgvI6XEf3OcrVnv6Nbss3fwXj0zrny4C8Dbfx/UoYFbMDAaAbHLSnXZW5/4EAQUvPpr1x4stW/Wu14rcMH4Ppy/qfsF)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>20</s> 19 bytes

```
+`(.)(.*¶)\1?
$2
¶$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY4xbsMwDEV3nYKDWziNEKC9QCGbtC2UJg2JRhogQzpkyNKhKNCb5QC5mCt3S5cP8PPj/f91/r58fiwP9en4s63c7Vo9LttTvdvUu6fbdXN8fnXVy2ovy0DMCntNjB5YE7pWkaBX7iAIQrmi9NAOgZmkp@wBg/RMLpd3o@/QaYIp6aSZ8C63gtw9nxn/O8hOaA8HTW8wKceWAGkKyUYS8yCqWMrGkHNohzmTWYYo2aLNRqAdGLWDKGt/8DDOZiqu0cZDETclyhEL6C84EMwSrczMFmydGH8B) Takes the phrase and acronym on separate lines, but the link includes a header that formats the test suite appropriately. Explanation:

```
+`
```

Process all of the letters of the phrase.

```
(.)(.*¶)\1?
$2
```

For each letter of the phrase delete the next letter of the acronym if it is the same.

```
¶$
```

Check that all of the letters of the acronym were deleted.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 85 bytes

```python
def f(s,w):
	for c in s:
		if c==w[0]:
			w.pop(0)
			if len(w)==0:return 1
	return 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVFNi4MwED3rr5hbFWSxu7eCB2viB5tmxKR0S/EgXWWFYkUtsv3zbtIWytZc5g1v3pshr/0dfs7NxzR9lxVUVu@M9so0qnMHR6gb6FVj1BUcPW88uLnujPGtPbeWa2usqFPZWKPtee6qK4dL18DSNB7Ina7gwcEE9Q6LmDKGsMOMkYUDC4aZrrK7lLnzGAmQUIiQheBzAqpLeARB7DNGeUSFlhGfR4y@CoWaX@MXhJhBmmGKgpIXofZWNSxO/VP3ehNjs5tmI4TNbDjdwR6zT0iRJQEFQlM/kxvKpZZwRMLmuze@EH4QbwWVUkDChUzkVlLAECQNYo4Mo73Wb7ZSIn@9a41rTd7LPybNqEiIWn6ziilseSLVfwjpy/tfJE9Jbpo67UKnfV3dHNqubgarsk51P1iFit124IGXua2i1nRxeFd4@gM)