# Is it a lobster number?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, number-theory

### Introduction

A "lobster number", by my own designation, is a number that contains within itself all of its prime factors.  The "lobster" description was inspired by the recent question "[Speed of Lobsters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217690/speed-of-lobsters)".  The basic idea is that each prime factor can be made by lobsters munching away digits of the number until you are left with just the factor.

Example: `51375` is a lobster number, since its prime factors are `[3,5,137]`, which can be made by lobsters thusly: `[**3**, 5**** / ****5, *137*]`.   Another lobster number is `62379`, as the factors `[3,29,239]` can be formed as `[**3**,*2**9,*23*9]`.

### Challenge

Given a number as input, return whether it is a lobster number or not.  Preferentially this is a boolean output, such as 1 or 0, or True or False.

Astute readers may realize that prime numbers are a trivial solution to this requirement, but since they don't allow the lobsters to eat any digits, they are out. Your program must not identify prime numbers as lobster numbers.

This is similar to OEIS [A035140](https://oeis.org/A035140), but has the additional requirement that each digit of the factor must appear at least the same number of times in the number, and in the correct order. In other words, `132` is not a lobster number, since its factors are `[2,3,11]`, and the `11` cannot be made by munching away at just `132`.  `312` is also not a lobster number, because its factors are `[2,3,13]`, and `13` is out of order.

I believe the "mathematical" definition would be: "Determine if the number n is a composite number such that all prime factors of n are a subsequence of n".

### Test Cases

```
59177  -> True
62379  -> True
7      -> False
121    -> True
187    -> False
312    -> False
```

As always, Standard Loopholes are forbidden.

### Note:

It has come to my attention that the original reasoning I gave for not needing to handle 0 or 1 as input is faulty.  However, requiring the proper output at this point would invalidate a number of answers.  Therefore, let it hereby be known that neither 0 nor 1 are lobster numbers, but you also do not need to handle them as input (they are not valid test cases). If your code does handle them correctly, you may give yourself the Lobster Advocate Badge™.

Comment: The prime factors of \$51735\$ are \$3, 5, 3449\$ not \$3, 5, 173\$

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing - excellent catch, it's 51375. Edited.

Comment: Can we take input as a list of digits?

Comment: That seems reasonable and falls under the default I/O methods: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: Do we have to handle the numbers `0` and `1`? If so, are they lobster numbers?

Comment: "To be a subsequence" only imposes the digits of a prime factor to be in a given order in the digit sequence, not to be contiguous, is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: @ovs 0 and 1 are not composite, so no, you don’t need to handle them as input.

Comment: @Xi'an That is correct, subsequence means same order but not contiguous, contiguous would be substring.

Comment: This challenge doesn't have an [objective scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8130). I'd recommend [tag:code-golf]

Comment: The factors of \$62379\$ are: \$3,29,239\$ so why is it a lobster number?

Comment: @Noodle9 The factors can be formed by: `**3**, *2**9, *23*9`. These are all subsequences. Contiguity is not essential.  I will include this ans an example to make it more clear, as I now realize that the examples don't really cover that (although 121 also has that same situation).

Comment: Maybe I need to ask this on MathOverflow: are there any Lobster Numbers for which the exact number of each prime factor can be independently munched?  That is,   **if** the factorization of  X  is  2,2,53, then X would have to include "2" exactly twice and "53" exactly once.

Comment: @Carl - I think that could be another interesting code golf challenge.  It would require better keeping track of what has been used in the original number and what the factors have been.  You would just need to verify that there is such a number first with some code.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Great, I haven't been able to stop thinking about it.  Seems like it requires computing intersections for two multisets, and generating all possible subsequences in groups where all in the group are possible at the same time.  Definitely seems like a MathOverflow question before a code-golf one.  Do you want to ask the question or should I?

Comment: @IronEagle go ahead for Code Golf; I'm just a "lurker" here.  I did post over at MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382220/numbers-whose-digits-in-order-display-prime-factors

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <del>155</del>, <del>126</del>, <del>124</del>, <del>123</del>, <del>120</del> <del>116</del>, 113 bytes

Yes! First python answer!

Saved **21 bytes** due to a suggestion by Dominic van Essen to remove the `for` loop!

Saved **8 bytes** because I realized I could use `t*=True/False` instead of `t+=[True/False]`.

Saved another **2 bytes** right after I finished editing because I realized `t` could simply be set to the same value as `i` and `l`!

Saved **1 byte** based off Danis's python 2 comment.

Saved another **3 bytes** based off Tipping Octopus's comment.

Saved another **4 bytes** due to Tipping Octopus again!

Saved another **3 bytes** thanks to Dominic's suggestion to remove the `t` variable.

## New Answer

```python
x=input()
n=int(x)
i=l=2
while~-n:
 if n%i:i+=1
 else:n//=i;l+=1;j=iter(x);l*=2*all(c in j for c in str(i))
print(l>4)
```

## How it works

The `while` loop computes the prime factors of the input. If a prime factor is found, it checks if it is a subsequence of the input. `l` is multiplied by whether or not this is `True`. This takes advantage of the fact that python's `True` and `False` values act like 1s and 0s when you multiply by them. This means that instead of appending `True/False` to `t` and checking whether `all(t)` is `True` like in my old answer, I can just multiply `l` by `2*True/False` and check its value in the `print` statement. The `print` statement prints `True` if `l>4`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HczBCsIwDIDhe54iF6GdyGj11BHfRaRjGSErXYbz4qvX6e27/H9527TotbWdWMtmzoMeMrd7YBKK8JpY8ueiCZBH1BMnPlMAzLLmpH1PPMzEluuRDNJR7B4i7omsOOO4VPxzterYeyj1N5f7zbcWYvgC)

## Old Answer

```python
x=n=int(input())
l=[]
i=2
while i<=n:
 if n%i:i+=1
 else:n/=i;l+=[i]
t=[]
for p in l:i=iter(str(x));t+=[all(c in i for c in str(p))]
print(all(t)*len(l)>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY5BCsJADEX3OUU2wkQXUnXj1HiR0oXIlAZCOkwj1tOPjrsP7z34@ePzYudaNzYW8yCWXx6IQHkYQfgE71k0odzYIqBMaDuJcuAOMOmaoh1Zej3wICN4a6alYEYx1CgsnkpYvYSNqPef9VANz0YFm/ifjWeiEXJpF5ritNdkQeneUa2X6xc)

Comment: Nice work!  It seems to me that the ```for``` loop might be redundant, and that everything it does could be transferred to the ```while``` loop, something like [this](https://tio.run/##HY1BCsJADEX3c4pshIldSC1SnBovUroQmdKUkJZpxHr60XH3H@/BXz82LdrkvJMSq3nW9WUe0Rn1g2MSOrv3xBKBb6TBAY@gBw5cUe0gyhaDnog7@XE3E1tMfrPkd8TOKuofIv4JrDDDuCT4z@IZcXBrKpclMTzKvcGcL9e6bb8
) (note that I don't really know Python, so there are probably some howlers in my tinkering...)

Comment: Beat me to it, with a better answer to boot!  I'll see if I can trim mine down at all...

Comment: https://tio.run/##HclNCsIwEEDhfU4xGyGxiqQipQnjRUSISEqnDNNQR6ynjz@79/HKW8dZ2lpXFCQpT7XOKF6uhpCxNa@ROIPsfTBAA8iGAjXoDWR@5CAHpMhfxwlJ82LTmlzUBm/M9g4kMMEwL/DPRMntTFlI1P6@ui2fj67WU@@77gM

Comment: @Dominic Yeah you're right. Don't need the `for` loop. I'll add an edit to my answer.

Comment: [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##FY1BCoMwEEX3c4psiomllERqqjK9SiMS60gYRVNqN716qrv3eR/e/I3DxCatmGVZ2pCReH5HqSAiYUADn4GC/124BkG94BPVdEYNwofV13xFasK@mxEp@kW6zakm5tiGIDtBLEbRT4s40JFTMC/EUcY8PEqV9iTAoZ/Hc2n55WWp9pDffCfWdKu0tVCawlZgQRsN@m6h0OYP)

Comment: The `iter` trick to check subsequences is really cool! I've been golfing in Python for years and had never seen it or had it occur to me.

Comment: @xnor Tbh, I saw it on a stack overflow post.

Comment: -3 bytes: https://tio.run/##HY1BCsIwEADv@4q9CElFSip4SFn/IpLSLcs2pFusF78eo7dhYJj8tnnVa60HsebdnAdtZO7wYMQkNMBrZkmfi0ZAnlBPHPlMATDJlqL2PfEoTYwLsaXSytE6eoi4J7LigtNa8I@bFcfeQy6/g3Vyv/lawxC@

Comment: I think we can remove the `t` variable and get 116 bytes: https://tio.run/##HYzBCsIwDEDv@YpchEaRobu1xH8R6VhGyEoXcV789Vq9PR68V94@rza2trNYeXogsE4edgJh5Su8ZtH8OVsElAntIFFOfAHMuuVow8CStIu0sHiuvUt65LtqeKAYLjitFf@4eQ1CBKX@/nobqbUv

Comment: I *think* ```l+=1``` may also be superfluous: [113 bytes](https://tio.run/##HczBCsIwDIDhe54iF6GdyGj11BHfRaRjGSErXYbz4qvX6e27/H9527TotbWdWMtmzoMeMrd7YBKK8JpY8ueiCZBH1BMnPlMAzLLmpH1PPMzEluuRDNJR7B4i7omsOOO4VPxzterYeyj1N5f7zbcWYvgC)...?

Comment: `l*=2*` can be `l<<=`

Comment: @pxeger `l<<=` almost works. It works correctly for all the lobster numbers, but it I think if a number has at least 2 factors (or a double factor) that are subsequences, it will incorrectly identify them as lobster numbers. It might work if I changed the truthy check in the `print` function, but I can't think of an obvious way to do it that would still save bytes.

Answer (score 13):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

That's basically this: "Determine if the number n is a composite number such that all prime factors of n are a subsequence of n".

```
ḋṀ⊆ᵛ?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFSuVv2obcOjpuZHHcuVSopKU/WUakDMtMScYiC79uGuztqHWyf8f7ij@@HOhkddbQ@3zrb//z/a1NLQ3FxHwczI2NxSRwHIMjQyBBIWQJaxoRFcwtTQ2Nw0FgA)

```
ḋṀ⊆ᵛ? (with implicit input n)
ḋ     get the prime factors of n
 Ṁ    they must be Ṁany (at least 2 to filter out primes)
  ⊆ᵛ  all of them must be an (ordered) subset of
    ? the input
```

Comment: 13 bytes unless a special codepoint table is given https://onlineunicodetools.com/convert-unicode-to-bytes

Comment: @AnnoyinC https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/wiki/Code-page

Answer (score 10):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `-e -o glob_subst -o extended_glob`, <sup><s>40</s></sup> 38 bytes

```sh
>$1:
for i (`factor $1`)>${i///*}*~$i:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@K9RnFqioJuqoJuvkJ6TnxRfXJpUXALipVaUpOalpKbEg4T/26kYWnGl5RcpZCpoJKQlJpcAmSqGCZp2KtWZ@vr6WrVadSqZVv811ez0U1LL9PNKc3K4bGxsVOz//zc0MgQA)

Outputs via exit code: `0` is a lobster number, `1` is not a lobster number

Explanation:

- `>` - do nothing, and send the output to:

  - `$1:` - the input with a `:` appended (e.g. `51375:`). This is because `factor` outputs the input number itself, then a colon, then its factors, and we need to match based on that later.
- `factor $1` - factorise the input (in the format `51375: 3 5 137`)
- `for i` - for each element in the factorisation:

  - `${i}` - take that element
  - `///*` - prefix each character with a `*` (e.g. `*1*3*7`)
  - append `*~` + the input + `:`
  - `>`, `-o glob_subst` - do nothing, and try to output to a file matching that pattern (there is only one file in the directory, the one we created earlier):

    - at this point the pattern is something like `*1*3*7*~51375:`
    - `*` - match zero or more characters; so `*1*3*7*` tests for a subsequence.
    - `~`, `-o extended_glob` - the file must match `*1*3*7*` but *not* `51375:` itself - this is to prevent prime numbers from being matched.
  - `-e` - exit immediately if there is an error (no files match that pattern) and set the exit code to `1`. If all factors matched a file, there is no error and the exit code is `0`.

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 6 bytes

```
æ¨IfåP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LJDKzzTDi8N@P/f1NLQ3BwA) or [Try all cases!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BN09B/fCyQys80w4vDVBXsFNIzk9J1UtMSuXiKs/IzElVKEpNTFHIzONKyedSUNDPLyjRzy9OTMpMhVJw9Qo2NjYKKmCFean//5taGpqbc5kZGZtbcplzGRoZchlamHMZGxpBxQA)

**Commented:**

```python
æ          # get the powerset / all subsequences of the input
 ¨         # remove the last one (the input itself)
  If       # get all prime factors of the input
    å      # is each prime factor in the powerset?
     P     # take the product
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>13</s> <s>10</s> 9 bytes

*(`Πm` -> `Λ` simultaneously golfed-down by [Razetime](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80214/razetime)!)*

```
Λo€hṖd¹dp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@52fmPmtZkPNw5LeXQzpSC////R5saGpub6phaGpqb65gZGZtb6pjrGBoZ6hhamOsYGxpBxGIB)

Returns `0` (falsy) for non-lobster numbers, and a positive nonzero integer (truthy) for lobster numbers.

**How?**

```
Λo       p    # is this true for each prime factor of input:
   €          # index (or zero if absent) of
        d     # its digits among
    hṖ        # all subsets (in order, without full set) of
      d¹      # digits of input
```

Comment: You can use `all` here for -1: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f@52fmPmtZkPNw5LeXQzpSC////R5saGpub6phaGpqb65gZGZtb6pjrGBoZ6hhamOsYGxpBxGIB "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: I was already typing-in that improvement while your comment arrived!  Thanks (and credit for the simultaneous improvement)!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 93 bytes

Outputs via exit code: `0` if it is a Lobster number, `1` otherwise.

```python
n=m=input()
i=1
while~-m:
 i+=1
 while m%i<1:m/=reduce(lambda s,c:s[c==s[:1]:],`n`,`i`)or i%n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3LasMwEEX38xWDwcSmLu3YdRSLatf@QVcNAaeyIAPRA1lp601/3RXuupuBOdx7T1jSxbt2/brw1SBJwBSXfNF8G42xKIrVKavYhVuqamBFsEV/7m1O8V3@8a9rS34maR9UNNNNm@p6th/TGedGy/molZqPkk7y1IxubEYeax@RS7ciZkf2hcgu4a7sJ5ndnFD7yeDjDkt0kIk2IWH1tgTzGqOPDb6b6F/4k2f2bkO1/HeGtpm1H0gI2LedGEAAtQR0ENBRCy108AQ97DM/wPAL)

The algorithm for determining subsequences was borrowed from [@xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180287/88546) to [Is string X a subsequence of string Y?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5529/88546). A `TypeError` is raised when the subsequence check fails, and the `i%n` causes a `ZeroDivisionError` to occur on prime inputs.

#### [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 92 bytes

One byte can be saved using `exec`, at the cost of segfaulting on large inputs.

```python
n=m=input()
i=1
exec"i+=1\nwhile m%i<1:m/=reduce(lambda s,c:s[c==s[:1]:],`n`,`i`)or i%n\n"*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY3BbsIwEETv@xUrSxEJjdRuKIRa9a39g54KSKGOJVYia8sx0Hx96tJzL3N4o5kXpnTy0sy3E58dkgZMccqJ7ttZjEqpWcxgWMIllRWwIfhtFD8Y2svfaij4lfTwaKLrL9aV5@Pw1R9xrK0ed9aYcafpoA91J13dcVf5iFzIXtRSZsSsyLoQWRIuinWvs5oTWt87fFpggQKZWBcSlh9TcO8x@ljjp4v@ja88spc7qvS/N3S/mVughoC2LayogQZW8Axr2EALW3j5AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
DŒPḌḟiⱮÆfẠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l6KSAhzt6Hu6Yn/lo47rDbWkPdy34b324XeVR0xr3//9NLQ3NzXUUzIyMzS11FIAsQyNDIGEBZBkbGsElTA2NzU0B)

### How it works

```
DŒPḌḟiⱮÆfẠ - Main link. Takes an integer n on the left
D          - Digits of n
 ŒP        - Powerset of the digits
   Ḍ       - Convert back to integers
    ḟ      - Remove n from this list
       Æf  - Yield the prime factors of n
      Ɱ    - Over each prime factor:
     i     -   Index of the factor in the powerset, or 0
         Ạ - All are true?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

*<sup>I got ninja'd..</sup>*

```
§&tΛo€Ṗd¹dp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9odXNr///CpyZ0zptv4oKs4bmWZMK5ZHD///81)

Outputs truthy for a lobster number and falsy otherwise. This would be shorter if `all` returned 0 for empty lists.

### Explanation

```
§&tΛo€Ṗd¹dp
          p prime factorization of the input
§           fork:
  t          is the list not composed of a single element?
 &          and,
   Λo    d   are all the prime factors' digits
     €       present in
      Ṗd¹    the powerset of the input's digits?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>135</s> 128 bytes

Saved 7 bytes thanks to @ovs!

```hs
f n=all(\x->x/=n&&(show n%show x))$foldl(\f x->[x|all((>0).mod x)f&&mod n x<1]++f)[][2..n]
(a:b)%(c:d)=b%([c|a/=c]++d)
_%x=x==[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYxBDoIwEEX3nGIWQtqAaCGKEOtFamMqpYFYCgGMNfHuWIhLN39@5r38WoyPSut5VmCo0Bpd7fZid9QEARrr7gXGX4/FeKM6LZ2gwCnMfhYbXfY4bjvpuAqCpRiwZ8LDUGHGWRLHhntIFHfso7KQmN59xMqP2NHSORJ7N99SSynjcysaAxRk5wHoaoJpeE71230YSUgEh5xkWQTHJM1y/lOU0ONqOEBOLlKSLKwfGjPBBlrRA1L4N/UHrAPzFw)

Comment: [128 bytes](https://tio.run/##bYxBDoIwEEX3nGIWQtqAaCGKEOtFamMqpYFYCgGMNfHuWIhLN39@5r38WoyPSut5VmCo0Bpd7fZid9QEARrr7gXGX4/FeKM6LZ2gwCnMfhYbXfY4bjvpuAqCpRiwZ8LDUGHGWRLHhntIFHfso7KQmN59xMqP2NHSORJ7N99SSynjcysaAxRk5wHoaoJpeE71230YSUgEh5xkWQTHJM1y/lOU0ONqOEBOLlKSLKwfGjPBBlrRA1L4N/UHrAPzFw) by combining two lines from the definition of `(%)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>12</s> 15 bytes

```
&!P_Q.A}Ry`Q`MP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X00xID5Qz7E2qDIhMME34P9/MyNjc0sA)

*-2 bytes by using `` ` `` instead of `+k`, +5 to account for primes needing to return false.*

Comment: This returns 'True' for prime numbers, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 95 bytes

```
.+
$*_¶$&
%O^$`.

+`^(__+?)(\1)*¶
$#2$*__¶$.1¶
_¶((.)+¶(?=(.+¶)*((?<-2>\2)|.)+$(?(2).))){2,}.+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYoxDsIwDEV3XwMX2QlYsisIlYCMjFygasrQgYUBsQHX6gF6sWCm97/ee06v@@NWG7qMVSJgKMuMa2iuA44CEMeBSomZqVcOywy4Mm/@kahfH0TC0ZFPJE4ORPm4tXNv/HGDlMlYmPltm69ErHXXaUqwtzZ1kEBNQQ8JWrUf) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$*_¶$&
```

Duplicate the input, converting one copy to unary.

```
%O^$`.
```

Reverse both copies. (Reversing the unary copy has no effect, of course, other than being golfier.) Reversing the input allows it to be used for nondestructive subsequence matching (a simple subsequence matching Retina program works by destroying both strings on success).

```
+`^(__+?)(\1)*¶
$#2$*__¶$.1¶
```

Repeatedly extract the smallest proper (and therefore necessarily prime) factor of the unary input, until it is reduced to 1.

```
_¶((.)+¶(?=(.+¶)*((?<-2>\2)|.)+$(?(2).))){2,}.+$
```

Attempt to match the unary 1, followed by at least 2 factors, each of which can be matched against the reversed input by popping its previously captured characters as they are seen, followed by the reversed input.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 27 bytes

```
1<[:*/](]#.@E.[-.-.)&":"+q:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DW2irbT0YzVilfUcXPWidfV09TTVlKyUtAut/mtypSZn5CuohxSVpqpD2GkKppaG5uYwjpmRsbkljGNoZMgF1eGWmFOM0AJXbmgBZxobGv0HAA)

Takes list of prime factors `q:` and original input, and for each pair, formats each as a string `&":"+` and then applies the following verb in parens: `]#.@E.[-.-.`

This verb set subtracts the factor digits from the input digits `-.` (leaving digits *not* in the factor) and then subtracts those from the input digits `[-.`, leaving only input digits that *are* in factor, with order preserved.

We then check if the factor is a substring match of that `E.`, which returns a boolean list of length input, with a 1 at any index where a match begins.  Finally we interpret that as a base 2 number and convert to an integer `#.@`.  This means that for a true result we need *all* factors to be greater than or equal to 1, and at least 1 factor to be greater than 1.

So we multiply all the results together `[:*/` and check if that is greater than 1 `1<`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/language/), 118 bytes

```
i|->Catch@AllTrue[MemberQ[a=FactorInteger@i,{i,_}]&&Throw@False;a,LongestCommonSequence@##==#&@@ToString/@{#[[1]],i}&]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU/RSsQwEHz3K8IV@hSQtGg9SyFyUBAUlOtbCNcY99pAk5zpFoXSb6@9E@9un3aY2Z0Zq7AFq9BoNc/7ohycRuOdMJRsFOqWP3VdFQYQr2A/ILwLVZRKow/PDqGBwA0dDd1NMo6rNvhvXqquh1zRF@8a6HHjrfVuC18DOA08iooiijmv/BaDcc0tHyMhmJTUTLGU@YzLTU8KMo53a5ZllBzNJ0rG@yTN1he4MCen484SdiHYwzWVsuQfTfnNud3oKIGfA2iEz0X2tkRB8ZeoAnvoFIJY1ax@PKtIndSUNB5JndYrKa4eULIXTi5DOOfkVCCf518)

Pure function; uses the `|->` syntax, which is new in version 12.2. TIO is running version 12.0, so I've used Function FullForm there.

Test cases:

```
59177: expected True, got True
62379: expected True, got True
7: expected False, got False
121: expected True, got True
187: expected False, got False
312: expected False, got False
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! This is a nice first answer! [Here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12900/95792) are tips for golfing in Mathematica (I'm not sure if it's the same as Wolfram Language).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 137 bytes

```python
lambda n:(p(n)<1)*all(re.search('.*'.join(`d`),`n`)for d in range(2,n)if n%d<1and p(d))
p=lambda n:all(n%i for i in range(2,n))
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU7LasMwELzrKxZDiDYIgxxaNyG@5txDb23BqrWO1TprIanQ9uddK31Au4fZHZiZHf@ehomruW8e5tGcn6wB3ksvGQ8aN2YcZaAykgndINflZl0@T45la1tULbfYTwEsOIZg@ESyUoyuB17ZgzZswUuLKHzzm5wDeeUg@9xfHwp39lNIEGhOFFOEBuTVTte1gutqW@8ULJeu9AI3y7XVFQp689Qlsll7F15JwRcezRj/k8tC0Q3UvVDIjuJo3FgoKG5NjAWK3Copyr0@nJeXFgp@fuBewDK5Vy8TXogPjtPigUX3HXwfm4Ye508)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>80</s>  79 bytes

Expects a string.

```javascript
f=(n,m=n,k=2)=>n%k?k>n||f(n,m,k+1):m-k&&m.match([...k+''].join`.*`)&&f(n/k,m,k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcxPC4IwGMfxe69CBumWOtmklsHs1ivoFoHDtHRuC7VOvvelRIf@0HN8vh9@tbiLLm@rax9qcyqsLTnUgeI6kJwinuq53MpUD0M5vQPpE7RRoXRdhZXo8ws8YIyl73lHXJtKZ3iRIdcdcSQnjmxudGeaAjfmDEsIlglhDCDkRJGzb2/F7KOvaMySP50BZ7xn34mm@wKEEvACvwbImoG/AzGh78A@AA)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (              // f is a recursive function taking:
  n,               //   n = initially the input as a string,
                   //       then an integer
  m = n,           //   m = copy of the input
  k = 2            //   k = current divisor candidate
) =>               //
  n % k ?          // if k is not a divisor of n:
    k > n ||       //   stop the recursion if k > n
    f(n, m, k + 1) //   otherwise: do a recursive call with k + 1
  :                // else:
    m - k &&       //   if k is not equal to m
    m.match(       //   and we can find in m:
      [...k + '']  //     the digits of k in the correct order
      .join`.*`    //     possibly with other digits in between
    ) &&           //   then:
    f(n / k, m, k) //     do a recursive call with n / k
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>264</s> <s>236</s> 219 bytes

-45 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!

```c
i,j,k,b,n,r,z;char p[9],c[6];l(int*s){b=1;for(j=k=!strcpy(c,s);p[j]*b;j++)for(b=0;c[k]&&(c[k]==p[j]?c[k]=5,b=1,0:1);k++);b=b;}f(int*s){r=1;n=z=atoi(s);for(i=2;n>1;i++)for(;sprintf(p,"%d",i),n%i<1;n/=i)r&=i-z&&l(s);b=r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFbb4IwFH73V3QskqLVCcbbSt0PQR6kwCywQtr6MA2/nR2YF8iSNYRz6HfOdwl89sl58yokL85xgnxtYlHOT/tGkIzkJCKSKHKh/HRUqAp2IeHBOqQFFtJMtHONmEvTUuGM5exFG8Wrb8yJdmgVZOEkotl06rR4xBaUB3lo27gtjLX4R9euCJCQxbvr0BymacQiWqd3AQUCkl3Y0ZQCA29LJphH5d6l4kZOdaVgPMUVscaxRYRD5Fj4sPjGhKNsJmYX2y7a9YgpWjcwjL6OQmIHXUcjBKfLZxJtIB08iAGAbsda7dzNxiLPi7W33Oz6FwPU9dzB53aALl3PQjXtLrpXlwgMGRBdUCg@WkOBbD0Pj@aW1Bpri/waNqFD/87dWePS6F/irvPRdga/qUgkfix3yFBuQNWXnVs9sfofe/FBHiRYTB86t8X6mVwl5qwkeBvVzQ8)

But it's a shame that C needs all those bytes. I believe that a better approach could be found, so here is an ungolfed and highly commented version that you can use to get yourself into the problem and hopefully develop something better.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// indexes
int i,j,k;

// int copy of the input s, used to find prime factors
int n;

// array to store char* copy of the prime factors of n
char p[20];

// bool telling whether a particular digit of p
// has been successfully "lobsted" in s
int b;

// checks whether a given factor p "lobsters" s
int l(char*s)
{
    // just copy of s, so that we can preserve the input
    // to check whether the next factors "lobster" it or not
    char c[6];
    
    strcpy(c,s);
    
    // we don't do it at the start of the k-loop
    // because we want to continue the loop from
    // where we left it. 31 do not "lobster" 12345.
    // After checking for 3, we don't check for 1 from the beginning
    k = 0;
    
    // until p has digits to check for lobsterness
    for(j=0;p[j];j++) {
        
        // assume the digit can't be lobsted in c
        b = 0;
        
        // untill c has digit that could potentially
        // "lobster" the digit of p
        for(;c[k];k++) {
            
            // if the digit of p double equals one of the digits of c
            if(p[j]==c[k]) {
                
                c[k] = '*'; // delete the digit of c
                b = 1; // set "lobsted" to true
                break;
            }
        }
        
        // if a digit couldn't be lobsted
        if(!b) break;
    }
    
    // return 0 if at least one digit couldn't be lobsted,
    // return 1 if all of them were sucessfully lobsted
    return b;
}

// find factors of s and launch l() for each factor found
int f(char*s)
{
    // n is, initially, the int copy of the input
    n = atoi(s);
    
    // until a factor can be found in n
    for(i=2;n>1;i++) {
    
        // if i is a factor of n
        if( !(n%i) ) {
            
            // if the first factor found is the original number
            if(i==atoi(s)) return 0;
        
            // until i divides n, divide n by i
            for(;!(n%i);n/=i);
            
            // make a char[] copy of the factor i, named p
            sprintf(p,"%d",i);
            
            // if p doesn't "lobster" s
            if(!l(s)) return 0;
        }
    }
    
    // reachable only if each factor p "lobsted" the original number s
    return 1;
}


int main() {

    char test[6][6] = {
        "59177",
        "62379",
        "7",
        "121",
        "187",
        "312" };
    
    for(int t = 0; t < 6; t++) {
        
        printf("%s", test[t]);
        
        for(int dots = 0; dots < 8-strlen(test[t]); dots++) {
            
            printf(".");
        }
        
        printf("%d\n\n", f(test[t]));
        
        memset(p,0,20);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

And in case you want to golf from here, rather than start a new approach, here is [the same code without comments](https://tio.run/##hVPbjoIwEH3nKyobI1V0AbNeUvFH0AcpqBWsBurDZsO3u1NAoAraGNueuZ2eGej4QOn9i3Ea34IQrVIRsMvkuG6BNAWKmf@MJYwfJKYxLhAzT2ZEijOHnR53Cbp6jrUtQb/cY0OahinW/jQEK3ek3gz85DX/g9z0@mtQM8UNNEIushr3/SUxTq5Frt5pS06jEUZFxspBLr8OUnAZTKgXbUmkRipecrG9ISu4rvR@9nzxzp8EjlB2MByQF5vkY7fASbiLVDjTXk9ag1TPx82wrBYmCcUt4VLxrNB8/6Q5BxI7cWGGoq@UhLkO4WubsFqUZk3UM3ifYfRJMOa6ZX78YNPWhKoRRVrCv12GSXfm9AozJ6Afpt4PdPOtr1Qo7iCQdShmV4qdd4wb8pX1jIowFTCm8AP16ufrP0t7PtfNGpg50/myCShW27GV60KxTm1HR9lzU4CQyOcYthWawdYx7aU@ej/VzYKw2OKO6ZdZg4tIi8T5aYUWY/j24pAbVXBu@fCJPMpOdEzeTW1FL9jwDQeK@6pOG8tzeE5DAd22TMfCXWMOfc3u938)

Comment: @ceilingcat thank you!

Comment: @ceilingcat thank you again! You should change your name in golfingcat :D

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 126 bytes

```powershell
param($n)(($u=2..($n-1)|?{!($n%($a=$_)-or(2..($a-1)|?{!($a%$_)}))})|?{$n-match(("$_"|% t*y)-join'.*')}).Count-eq$u.count-and$u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBda8IwFIbv@yuyEmcitpAW13lRJoi73Zi7G0OyGOmkbVw@2Ib2t3enLauKHnpx@rzPeSndqW@pTSbzPBBKyxpv0n2945oXBJeUEOzSKAxhDxg9POxvYBsQzFO8ooHSpM14n/EB8IrCA@9wU3ArMkJ8vPIPA2RHvzTYqs9yGI6G4IRz5UobyC/sQtGuvFxjV1eeNyMeghmjGZmwOJmMEbbaSXqkU5YkF/QuipPpBW28Dc/NCWIRu9DY/RUxZtGV6/gEUnRAj0ovuMiCp4@tFBbtWxNbaSx48mcHUK5RivCqS7Q0LrcAbvGm81r@9rycO2NV0fW8z7qiZpZOCGlMu6d9Afy7Y3/v@q9QiAQ30m/cvr6Zl@7wvKdPF/@f2qVnzZVX1X8)

Takes an integer and returns a boolean

```powershell
($u=2..($n-1)|?{!($n%($a=$_)        # finds the factors of the input
-or(2..($a-1)|?{!($a%$_)}))})       # keep them only if they are prime
|?{$n-match(("$_"|% t*y)-join'.*')} # add a .* between each digits of each prime factors and check if they match the input
.Count-eq$u.count-and$u             # Check that the input has factors and that they all match the input
```