# Tips for golfing in D2

Tags: code-golf, tips

What general tips do you have for golfing in [D](https://dlang.org)? I'm looking for ideas that can be applied to code golf problems in general that are at least somewhat specific to D (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer). Please post one tip per answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look, no parens!

D's functions and template functions can be called as values, methods (won't help), and properties.

I can't believe no one has said this yet. I'll list the ones that save bytes:

- `fun()` and `fun!()()` shorten to `fun` (assuming there is no variable `fun`).
- `fun(par)` shortens to `par.fun` (assuming `par` has no property/method `fun`, as well as `par` not being an expression like `5+2`).
- `fun!(T)()` shortens to `fun!T`
- `fun!(T)(par)` shortens to `par.fun!T` (assuming `par` has no property/method `fun`)

And with objects:

- `new cls()` shortens to `new cls` (More JavaScript anyone?)
- `obj.fun()` and `obj.fun!()()` shorten to `obj.fun`
- `obj.fun!(T)()` shortens to `obj.fun!T`

One final thing, **use old versions**. It allows you to use deprecated features that shorten your code. That said, best advice: D isn't good for code-golf. It is a great language, just not for code-golf.

Comment: Accepting for now :)

Comment: Yeah, good to know there's still fans of D here.

Answer (score 2):

D is JavaScript.

---

Obviously not. But, when dealing  with `float`, `double` and `real`, `nan` is a value which must be handled, and, as specified by IEEE 754, NaN does not compare equal with itself.

```
writeln(double.nan == double.nan); // false
```

Meaning,

```
writeln(value!=value); // only true for nan
```

is way shorter than

```
import std.math;
writeln(isNaN(value));
```

Obviously, always use `math.isNaN` for *real* code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

D has type inference and an `auto` keyword. If the object is not `int`, then `auto` is probably shorter.

Comment: Does `auto` work when building an associative array with the `KeyType[ValueType]` syntax?

Comment: @AlexA. `auto asd = ["a":1, "b": 2];` works, but since `KeyType[ValueType]` would go in the place of the `auto` keyword, I don't know if that will always work with types for which literals can't be constructed

Comment: @AlexA. `auto arr = ["a": true, "b": 6];` works, the keys and values must be of *compatible* types

Answer (score 1):

If the question requires a full program, the `module` declaration is surprisingly unnecessary.

**cough** Java, anyone? **clears throat** *Actually*, D's `module` system is older than Java's.

Answer (score 1):

D is great at method chaining, but:

```
str.toLower.strip().split("").sort();
```

is the same as

```
sort(split(strip(str.toLower),""));
```

and usually the non-chained one is shorter, which I just realised, which lets me shorten my answer to [Manage Trash So](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/74344/46231) :D

Comment: It's those dots

Answer (score 1):

D, as a multiparadigm (Object Functional) systems programming language, seems to embrace TIMTOWTDI, or There Is More Than One Way To Do It.

Case in point, writing the program's argv:

```
import std.stdio, std.array, std.algorithm;

void main(string[] args) {
    for(int i=0;i<args.length;writeln(args[i++])){};

    foreach(a;args)writeln(a);

    each!writeln(args);
}
```

Note the C-style for-loop requires `{}` as the empty block and will not accept a semicolon or nothing as a blank statement, *in this case*. Usually,  or `;` are no-ops.

Comment: Can you use `char*` in place of `string` to save a byte?

Comment: @AlexA. `function D main parameters must be main() or main(string[] args)` moreover, `char` is literally one character, `char*` is a pointer to literally one character and `char[]` is an array of character literals (strings are different). D != C || C++

Comment: OIC. Never used D, just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

D has a few types of C#-style lambda expressions, which can be assigned and stand alone:

```
(int a,int b)=>a*b;

auto a=(int a,int b)=>a*b;
```

However, unlike C#, the signature's types are still needed because D doesn't have Haskell-level type inferencing.

https://dlang.org/spec/expression.html#Lambda

Comment: Function templates for golfing the types? `T f(T)(T a,T b){return a + b}` should infer _T_ as _int_ in `f(5);`

Comment: @fedes. Hello, friend! Yes, you are exactly correct (but I think/hope "untyped" lambdas will be shorter than typed function expressions).

Comment: Ah, ofc! When I decide to take yet another look on D, who do I find? :D I objectively declare you have good taste on languages

Comment: @fedes. Aw, why thank you! :P that implies you do too (but I haven't spent enough time in front of Smalltalk, yet anyways :) )

Answer (score 0):

Like C/C++, `main` can be `int` or `void`, but `void main(){}` will always be shorter than `int main(){return my_func_returning_int;}`.

Comment: If the question ask to output an integer wouldn't `int main(){return output}` be shorter?

Comment: @dev-null if the question asks for a full program writing an integer to stdout then `import std.stdio;void main(){write(7);}` is what's needed. I doubt a question would mandate the *program* return a number because many languages can't set return codes

Comment: @dev-null however, yes, in that case that it should *not* be written to stdout but returned, it would be shorter

Comment: Usually you are allowed to return / output the most convenient way for your language. But I guess D only support exit codes from 0-255?

Comment: @dev-null actually, *POSIX* only supports exit codes up to 255. I don't know about Windows, but on Unix / Linux an exit code over 255 wraps around, because of overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function on an object with no other arguments

```
reverse(x);
```

can nearly always be shortened to

```
x.reverse;
```

to shave a byte or more.

This is because the `.` makes the LHS an implicit first argument, and templating lets us choose the right function for the args.

Comment: Dots are good? This is confusing...

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy when there are no args. When there's another argument, the `x.reverse(y, z)` is longer because of the dot

Comment: `x.reverse(y,z)` and `reverse(x,y,z)` have the same byte count.

Comment: @ZacharyT Uh, yeah...

Comment: Were you comparing `x.reverse(y, z)` to `x.reverse`?

Comment: @ZacharyT I believe I was comparing counting sheep to a lack of coffee -- that is, it was probably me not thinking properly ;)